# Creemos un sitio con explicaciones sobre el porqué de las votaciones negativas

Tags: discusión, votos, votos-negativos

Hace poco he descubierto [idownvotedbecause](http://idownvotedbecau.se/). Es un sitio con explicaciones claras sobre los motivos por los que una pregunta (o respuesta) puede ser votada negativamente, con varias páginas que pueden ser enlazadas en los comentarios.

Personalmente me parece una muy buena idea para que los usuarios nuevos puedan entender el porqué de una recepción negativa a su publicación, y puede ayudar a mejorar la calidad del sitio.

Por ello, me gustaría proponer crear un equivalente en español.

Veo dos opciones:

1. crear un equivalente a las páginas del sitio como posts aquí en meta para poder enlazar a ellos, o
2. crear una página similar a la que os enlazo.

Yo me inclino por la segunda, ya que deja más posibilidades en cuanto a formato.

¿Qué os parece esta iniciativa?

---

Actualización: Se ha creado una pregunta aquí: 
[¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/15301)

---

Actualización 2: Se ha solicitado permiso al dueño de [idownvotedbecause](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) para poder traducir las páginas. Cree un issue en el [GitHub del proyecto](https://github.com/WillSullivan/idownvotedbecause/issues/32) y amablemente ha contestado por un lado que tenemos su permiso, y por el otro ha ofrecido crear una nueva categoría en su sitio y poner ahí las traducciones. Creo que por el momento, estamos bien con el post creado en meta, pero tampoco es mala idea contribuir al proyecto ya que las traducciones ya están hechas.

Comment: Me parece buena idea aunque yo lo veo mejor en una publicación de Meta, cuyas respuestas sean los diferentes motivos por los que das downvote.

Comment: Es una buena idea, así se pueden evitar "conflictos" como los que se han visto ya en Meta. Y creo que sería bueno ponerlo también en Meta

Comment: ¿Alguien tiene una captura de pantalla o una muestra de cómo funciona?

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave no entiendo. Pulsa en el enlace que está puesto en el post. Tienes problemas para verlo?

Comment: @Pikoh me refiero a cómo se usa, la verdad había visto la página, pero no entiendo si se debe agregar un complemento o cómo es que funciona. = curiosidad :)

Comment: @MauricioAriasOlave ah ok, no te había entendido. Se usa en un comentario. Imaginemos que yo he votado esta pregunta negativamente porque contiene una imagen de código en lugar de el código en si como un texto. Yo podría comentar algo asi como [He votado negativo por tener una imagen de código](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: @Pikoh ahora comprendo. Gracias +1 :)

Comment: Interesante propuesta, cualquiera de las dos opciones es de gran ayuda, independientemente cual sea la elegida. Otra opción es tener ambas opciones, mi propuesta es que iniciemos por la opción 1 y una vez que ya se encuentre consolidada la información echemos a andar una página con toda la información completa ;)

Answer (score 9):

## Voto por la opción 1:

Crear un equivalente a las páginas del sitio como posts aquí en meta para poder enlazar a ellos.

Comment: Me gusta más esta (aunque la opción 2 también). Creo que esto nos permitiría editar las publicaciones a antojo y entre todos.

Comment: El problema de la opción dos es la disponibilidad y mantenimiento del nuevo sitio. Si por alguna razón el otro sitio deja de existir los enlaces publicados no serán nada útiles,

Comment: Esta me parece una buena opción por varias cosas: Todos los usuarios del sitio tenemos acceso para poder colaborar, editar añadir, etc. No es un sitio externo que haya que mantener aparte. Acercaría a usuarios nuevos a *meta* que muchas veces no saben ni que existe. Habría una política mas o menos "oficial" de en que casos se vota negativo (aunque siempre quedará a criterio de cada uno como votar).

Answer (score 5):

## Voto por la opción 2:

Crear una [página similar](http://idownvotedbecau.se/) a la que os enlazo.

Comment: Es mas.. yo preguntaria si podemos usar la misma, traduciendo casi textual lo que escribieron al español.. no se si es necesario generar mas ruido con otra pagina.. Total, como se vea el link o donde esta hosteada no cambia nada.

Comment: En la "actualización 2" se menciona que ya se recibió el permiso y que hay una categoría para las publicación en español

Answer (score 3):

## Voto por la opción 4:

Utilizar los comentarios para explicar por qué se vota negativo y sugerir cómo mejorar la pregunta/respuesta.

Comment: No encuentro una razón de peso para que el usuario tenga que explicar el porque de los downvotes. Si la pregunta/respuesta tiene problemas de formato, se comenta la explicación correpondiente con el enlace a la ayuda de SO. Si no le sirve la pregunta/respuesta despues de haberla intentado, está en todo su derecho de dar downvote. Las demas opciones están de mas, ademas no creo que esto llegue a algo.

Comment: @Arie Completamente de acuerdo. Nadie tiene obligación de explicar sus votos. Pero si alguien lo quiere hacer el mejor sitio es en los comentarios de la misma pregunta o respuesta en Stack Overflow. ¿Para qué alejarlos?

Comment: Por eso voté por esta opción, no creo que meta u otro sitio externo sea la mejor opción. En los comentarios se mantiene la consistencia en la discusión sobre la pregunta/respuesta

Comment: @Arie No estoy de acuerdo con vosotros. Por un lado,esta opción ya está disponible. Por otro,por supuesto no es obligatorio explicar los votos,pero algunos preferimos hacerlo.Y por último,esta es sólo otra opción mas para casos comunes (como poner una imagen en lugar de pegar el código) que permite dar una explicación mucho mas extensa y detallada de porqué eso ha podido llevar a un OP a recibir votaciones negativas. Tampoco entiendo estar en contra de algo que es una herramienta mas para poder mejorar la calidad de las preguntas. Si se quiere,se usa,si no,pues no :)

Comment: @Pikoh Para crear ese sitio no te hace falta permiso de nadie. Ni tampoco estoy en contra de que lo hagas, adelante. A mi me parece un esfuerzo inútil y por tanto manifiesto que no lo apoyo.

Comment: No pedía permiso,sino opinion. Y tu has dado la tuya,la cual valoro como todas. Gracias por ella.

Answer (score 0):

## Voto por la opción 3:

Iniciar por la opción 1 y una vez que ya se encuentre consolidada la información echemos a andar una página con toda la información completa.