# ¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?

Tags: discusión, faq, votos, votos-negativos

He recibido un voto negativo en mi pregunta/respuesta y la persona que lo hizo me ha dirigido aquí.

¿Cuál es la razón? ¿Cómo puedo evitarlo?

---

### En mi pregunta

Te he votado negativamente porque...

- [No responder a los usuarios que piden aclaraciones no es de ayuda.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870/)
- [Una captura/imagen del código no es de ayuda.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)
- [Solo pusiste una imagen de tu excepción.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873)
- [Solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871)
- [No intentaste nada.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874)
- [Sin código es difícil ayudarte.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875)
- [No se aprecia ningún esfuerzo en depurar el código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872)
- [Tu pregunta no incluye los detalles de la excepción.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2877)
- [No has proporcionado un Ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2876)
- [Hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)
- [Un exceso de código no es de ayuda.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2879)
- [No sabemos lo suficiente sobre tu base de datos.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880)
- [Sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794)
- [Un enlace hacia tu código no garantiza ayudar a la comunidad.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3883)
- [Solicitar ayuda URGENTE es descortés y hasta grosero.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152)
- [Solicitas directamente que alguien haga tu trabajo/tarea escolar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320)

---

Sugerencias de Respuestas:

### En mi respuesta

Te he votado negativamente porque...

- [Es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882)
- [Solamente pusiste un enlace.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2883)
- [Es una pregunta flagrantemente fuera de tópico.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2884)
- [Tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912)
- [No esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217)
- [Respondiste en un idioma que no es el español.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3222)
- [Tu respuesta resuelve un problema pero agrega otro](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5671/342)

Comment: ¡¡Botón para enlazar aquí automáticamente, ya!!

Comment: Por si alguien no sabe de que va esta pregunta/respuesta, esta basada en este post [Creemos un sitio con explicaciones sobre el porqué de las votaciones negativas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2859/15301). Ya que al parecer ganó la opción de un post en meta, me he decidido a crearlo y a traducir un par de respuestas. Si alguien quiere ayudar con la traducción o con la edición de las que ya haya, es totalmente bienvenido.

Comment: @Pikoh ¡Eres todo un genio! Gracias por esta excelente aportación.

Comment: Es de las mejores preguntas que he visto en meta. ¡¡Es una genial idea!!

Comment: He votado negativamente esta pregunta porque solo contiene enlaces :P

Comment: @fedorqui XD lo de los enlaces es en la respuesta ;)

Comment: Cada vez que veo esta pregunta, caigo en la trampa y vuelvo a entrar pensando "*¿qué hace Pikoh preguntando por un -1?*"

Comment: @Mariano XD ponla como favorita para que no se te vuelva a olvidar :)

Comment: @Mariano En ese caso, igual hay que cambiar el título de la pregunta para que no te vuelvas a asustar :) De hecho...algunos piensan que se debería cambiar el planteamiento y eliminar la parte de "Te he votado negativamente porque..." y dejar solamente las razones...y a lo mejor tienen razón.

Comment: @Pikoh opino igual... me pareció un poco violento cuando vi los comentarios de `te he votado negativamente` a usuarios nuevos.

Comment: @Mariano pues es cuestión de plantearlo en Meta y si la gente está de acuerdo, modificarlo

Comment: Pikoy y @Mariano yo estoy usando muchas veces el enlace, es muy útil. Lo divertido es que en muchos casos me sabe mal votar negativamente a un novatillo, por lo que no lo hago y aún así añado el enlace. Sí, podría ser mejor simplemente apuntar el problema y no que hemos votado negativamente.

Comment: @Mariano todos lo hemos entendido,tranquilo. Yo creo que efectivamente los enlaces son útiles pero el planteamiento parece obligar a votar negativo, lo que no es siempre necesario. Yo diría que esto es un sentimiento mayoritario, pero como digo creo que es mejor preguntarlo en meta y ver si es asi y que opciones de modificación existen. Yo soy el primero que creo que debe modificarse

Comment: Pikoh y @Mariano absolutamente de acuerdo con los dos. Se te entendió bien Mariano, no temas :) El currazo de Pikoy en este tema es impresionante, por lo que sería una pena que tuviera una connotación negativa cuando su finalidad máxima es la pedagógica para tener mejores publicaciones. Entonces, ¿hacemos una pregunta en Meta para decidir si esta otra pregunta de Meta debe ser cambiada? :)

Comment: @fedorqui opino que si. Y yo preferiría que la hiciera otro,no quiero "apropiarme" de este tema. Por ejemplo tu,master de meta ;)

Comment: @mariano no estoy de acuerdo. El contenido que hay aqui es de todos,hayas o no participado, y tienes el mismo derecho a opinar sobre el que cualquiera. Exactamente el mismo.

Comment: Hecho: [¿Deberíamos poner un texto más “constructivo” a la hora de enlazar las publicaciones de “¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2938/83)

Comment: @Pikoh es un buen punto. A mí me parecía un detalle nomás, que no hace a la cuestión de fondo, por eso es que no me modifica mucho... (O sea, si quisiera poner el enlace, le cambió el texto en el comentario y listo, y Las publicaciones están para que cualquiera las edite, nadie lo impide)... A lo que iba, pensé que quizás era algo más sencillo de discutir entre los que se tomaron el trabajo, evitando una meta-meta-meta publicación, pero por sobre todo confío en tu criterio para saber qué conviene en este caso

Comment: Y ya está publicada, @fedorqui no se anda con vueltas ;-)

Comment: Hoy me he topado con una ["pregunta"](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/142950/ingresar-datos-por-teclado-y-que-calcule-los-primos-e-imprima-en-pantalla-los-n) en la que solo plantaron un bloque de código. Creo que valdría la pena incluir estos casos en esta lista, algo como "*Te he votado negativamente porque no indicas cuál es el problema*".

Comment: @KroneauxSchneider bueno,podría encajar dentro de "un exceso de código", pero adelante,si crees que es interesante, te animo totalmente a añadirlo a la lista ;)

Comment: Hola! Quise compartir esta entrada a una publicación con votos negativos, pero **ninguno de esos votos fue mío**. Entonces, ¿no deberíamos cambiar el `"... te he votado"` por `"... te votaron"`, o algo por el estilo?

Comment: En ocasiones el que pregunta no lo entiende, de hecho ni sabe el porqué, Esta pregunta realmente ayuda. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 30):

### Te he votado negativamente porque una captura/imagen del código no es de ayuda

**Una captura de tu código no nos ayuda**

Cuando realizamos una pregunta sobre un problema con nuestro código, no solo debemos dejar que los usuarios que nos ayudan puedan verlo de manera óptima, sino que algunos querrán copiarlo y pegarlo en un IDE o Editor para jugar un poco con él. Con una captura del código esto no es posible, además que personas con dispositivos poco comunes, resoluciones especiales o problemas visuales van a tener dificultades para leer nuestro código y lo más seguro, dejar de lado la pregunta.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Una de las primeras cosas que hacemos cuando examinamos un código para encontrar un error es intentar compilarlo (si es necesario) y ejecutarlo para ver qué es lo que sucede. Podemos también copiar parte del código para pegarlo en motores de búsqueda, de tal manera que encontremos información sobre los tipos o algoritmos que estamos usando, y para encontrar otras preguntas similares. Cuando lo que nos das es una captura del código, este proceso se hace mucho mas difícil.

También debemos tener en cuenta que las imágenes pesan más, por lo que para los usuarios que acceden con su dispositivo móvil y tienen conexiones lentas puede ser un problema. Otro problema es que algunos usuarios que tratan de ayudarnos pueden no ser capaces de ver las imágenes al tener su red restringida en el trabajo o escuela.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Cuando los usuarios nos ofrecen su ayuda, gratis y utilizando su tiempo, es importante darles todo lo necesario para poder resolver nuestro problema. Cuando les estamos forzando a transcribir el código de una imagen, estamos malgastando su tiempo. Además, los errores en la transcripción pueden hacer mas difícil que se pueda encontrar una solución a nuestro problema. Los contenidos de una imagen no pueden ser buscados, así que otros desarrolladores con el mismo problema tendrán mas complicado encontrar nuestra pregunta. Esto es aún mas problemático en el caso de desarrolladores que utilizan lectores de pantalla, ya que no serán capaces ni de ayudarnos ni de ayudarse a sí mismos encontrando una respuesta a nuestra pregunta en el futuro.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Edita tu pregunta. Quita las imágenes que contienen código. Copia y pega tu código en la pregunta. Es muy importante que el código sea el mínimo imprescindible para reproducir nuestro problema, y que esté bien formateado. Si nuestro código consiste en HTML, CSS y JavaScript, ¡podemos aprovecharnos de los snippets para hacer que nuestro problema sea reproducible directamente en nuestra pregunta! Esto hace mucho más sencillo ver nuestro problema y proporcionar una solución rápidamente. También puedes consultar [Fiddles: Lista de páginas que podemos usar para probar código y sus características](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2446/83) para ofrecer fragmentos de código con los que los usuarios puedan emular tu entorno de trabajo.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar `@usuario` para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Tradución/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)`.</sub>

Comment: @fedorqui muy buena aportación añadir el enlace :)

Comment: El uso de esta respuesta como comentario en un post donde NO se pregunte *por que me votaron negativamente?* puede tener un sentido antipático; lo puedes aplicar en casi todo los post del sitio... y puedes votarle negativo a todos los post del sitio... el 90% del sitio esta basado en preguntas de personas que no leyeron la documentación, que no la entendieron o no investigaron en google un tutorial... me parece que aunque sea valido, las preguntas deben ser cerradas y al OP se le debe dirigir a: `[ask]` y 
`[mre]` y 
`[help/on-topic]` y 
`[help/dont-ask]` del sitio en cuestión claro

Answer (score 18):

### Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.

**"No me funciona" no nos ayuda**

Cuando alguien hace una pregunta por un problema en su código, necesitamos saber qué hay de malo con el código. Decir que "no me funciona" no ayuda.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Para poder proporcionar una solución, necesitamos una descripción completa del problema. Eso incluye:

- Qué tratas de conseguir
- Qué has probado (incluyendo [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
- Una descripción de lo que hace el código.
- Una descripción de por qué no se está consiguiendo lo esperado del programa.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Cuando solo proporcionas uno de estos puntos, las respuestas tendrán que adivinar las piezas que faltan en tu pregunta. Eso aumenta las posibilidades de que las respuestas sean incorrectas, lo que es una pérdida de tiempo para todos. Sin la suficiente información para responder una pregunta, los usuarios son más reacios a intentar responderla y están más dispuestos a votar negativamente.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Revisa tu pregunta. ¿Has añadido una explicación completa de lo que hace tu código? ¿Explicaste por qué el resultado actual difiere de lo que quieres lograr? Usa el botón de `editar` bajo la pregunta (**no** añadas un comentario) para mejorar la pregunta. Si algún usuario ha hecho preguntas en los comentarios, trata de añadir la respuestas a estas preguntas en la edición de tu pregunta.

Si no sabes por qué tu código no funciona, deberías usar el modo debug para analizar dónde puede estar el problema. Debugging es uno de los primeros pasos que se han de realizar para saber qué puede estar fallando. No *debuguear* tu código también es motivo para votar negativo. Para aprender por qué y pistas para debuguear tu código, [pulsa aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872/)

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar `@usuario` para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83)

---

*Tradución/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)`.</sub>

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te podrían votar negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855) usando este código: `[Te podrían votadr negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)`.</sub>

Answer (score 15):

### Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada

**Parece que no intentaste nada.**

Todos tenemos trabajo que hacer. Puede ser tarea escolar, un ejercicio para la universidad o trabajo-trabajo. No importa el porqué, es nuestra responsabilidad hacer el trabajo. Y cuando parece que nuestra tarea es demasiado difícil o ni siquiera sabemos dónde empezar, siempre vale la pena hacer el esfuerzo por intentarlo.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

No podemos depender de que otros hagan el trabajo por nosotros. Pedirle a otros que hagan el trabajo por nosotros también suena rudo. Si probamos, puede ser que nos salga. Pero si no probamos, siempre fallaremos. Y si probamos, y no mostramos nuestros esfuerzos, puede ser que se duplique nuestro trabajo en lugar de brindar una solución que funcione.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Puede verse como demasiado rudo pedirle a otros que hagan el trabajo por nosotros. La gente va a mirar si hicimos por lo menos algún esfuerzo, y si ven que no hicimos nada, vernos como unos vagos, y actuar negativamente, votando negativamente la pregunta y cerrándola. Sin hacer por lo menos un intento, puede que ni sepamos donde esta nuestro problema. La gente puede gastar tiempo contestando nuestra pregunta, sugiriendo cosas que ya probamos, y no las cosas que realmente necesitaríamos para solucionar el problema. Esto hace perder el tiempo a los que voluntariamente nos ayudan, y no soluciona el problema.
Si hicimos un esfuerzo, pero fallamos en detallar exactamente que hicimos en nuestra pregunta, esto puede resultar en duplicar esfuerzos por parte de los que tratan de ayudarnos. Eso es una pérdida de tiempo, y hace más difícil obtener una respuesta correcta.

Y en algunos casos, nuestra pregunta en si puede ser una pérdida de tiempo. El esfuerzo por arreglar nuestro problema puede ser menor que el esfuerzo por hacer la pregunta. Una simple búsqueda, un poco de debug, y se podría haber solucionado. Y, si preguntando fue una pérdida de nuestro tiempo, definitivamente fue una pérdida de tiempo para aquellos que trataron de ayudarnos.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Si hiciste un esfuerzo, edita inmediatamente tu pregunta para detallar exactamente qué hiciste. Agregar “busque en google y no encontré nada”, no ayuda. Debes detallar que buscaste, y apuntar a los links que te ayudaron pero no contestaron tu pregunta. Si probaste una solución, debes agregarla en la pregunta. Nuestros intentos deben transformase en un Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable para que sea fácil de leer y entender.
Si no hiciste ningún esfuerzo, y nadie contesto la pregunta, bórrala inmediatamente.  Guarda el link a la pregunta, puede que la necesites otra vez. Haz un esfuerzo por solucionar el problema.  Investiga mas, guarda registros de lo que buscaste y no sirvió. Deberías crear un pequeño prototipo que reproduzca el problema. Trata una vez mas de solucionar el problema. Si no puedes encontrar la solución, regresa a la pregunta. Edítala y agrega todos estos detalles. Una vez que terminaste, recupera la pregunta, ahora si tiene la información suficiente para contestarla correctamente.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque no intentaste nada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2874/)`.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

### Las consultas que se te hicieron son para buscar la mejor solución a tu problema. Deberías responderlas para obtener respuestas de calidad.

**No responder a los comentarios no es de ayuda**

Los usuarios me están haciendo preguntas en los comentarios para tener más claro mi problema, pero yo no les estoy respondiendo.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Hay usuarios intentando ayudarme con mi pregunta, pero después de hacerla, no he respondido a sus peticiones de aclaración. La gente está intentando responder mi pregunta, pero no pueden porque yo no fui lo suficientemente claro al hacerla. Como no estoy respondiendo, los que están intentando ayudarme o no pueden hacerlo, o están tratando de adivinar. Si estos intentos de adivinar son incorrectos, han perdido el tiempo.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Si mi pregunta es lo suficientemente importante para crear una publicación aquí, debería ser lo suficientemente importante para comprobarla regularmente y responder a todo el que comente en ella. Si ignoro mi pregunta, también estoy ignorando a los que están intentando ayudarme. El tiempo que han empleado en analizar mi pregunta, solicitar una aclaración y esperar una respuesta, es tiempo que se ha perdido. Si se arriesgan con una respuesta que resulta ser incorrecta, el tiempo que han empleado en ella también se ha malgastado. Hacer perder el tiempo de gente que está intentando ayudarme no parece muy adecuado.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Si estoy leyendo esto porque alguien dejó un enlace en mi pregunta abandonada, debería inmediatamente volver a mi pregunta y responder a todos los que me han pedido alguna aclaración en ella. Debería editar mi pregunta para incluir cualquier información adicional que se me haya pedido, y después @responder en los comentarios para que las personas que solicitaron alguna ampliación de información sean notificadas de que he respondido sus preguntas. Y, en el futuro, cuando haga una pregunta, debería mantener una pestaña abierta al menos durante unas horas después de haberla realizado, para comprobar si se ha añadido algún comentario y responderlo lo antes posible. Debo tener en cuenta que la mayoría de comentarios o respuestas se producen en un corto período de tiempo tras la realización de la pregunta.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar `@usuario` para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/beingunresponsive)*

<sub>Compartible con los textos:

[Te he votado negativamente porque no responder a los usuarios que piden clarificaciones no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870/).

Las consultas que se te hicieron son para buscar la mejor solución a tu problema. [Deberías responderlas para obtener respuestas de calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870/).</sub>

<sub>Cuyo código es:

`[Te he votado negativamente porque no responder a los usuarios que piden clarificaciones no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870/)`.

`Las consultas que se te hicieron son para buscar la mejor solución a tu problema. [Deberías responderlas para obtener respuestas de calidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870/).`</sub>

Comment: Dado que es la respuesta más votada, he modificado el título y añadido un posible enlace de acuerdo con lo comentado por Mariano en [¿Deberíamos poner un texto más “constructivo” a la hora de enlazar las publicaciones de “¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2940/83). Si parece bien, seguimos con el resto.

Comment: Por mi,visto bueno total @fedorqui.

Answer (score 14):

### Te he votado negativo porque no has proporcionado un Ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable

**Sin un Ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable es difícil saber cuál es el problema**

Una pregunta sin nigún código, o donde el código provisto no es:

- Mínimo – el menor código posible que aun así esté produciendo el mismo problema.
- Completo - contiene todas las partes necesarias para reproducir el problema
- Verificable – compilará si es ejecutado, y exhibe el problema descrito.

Cuando un ejemplo de código cumple estas tres cualidades, se suele conocer como [MCVE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Sin código, los usuarios tienen que tratar de adivinar cuál podría ser el error en el código de otra persona. Con demasiado código, encontrar el problema podría ser como encontrar una aguja en un pajar. Si se añade un código que no muestra el problema sobre el que se pregunta, entonces ese código no sirve prácticamente para nada. Y si el código está lleno de errores de compilación o errores tipográficos al pegarlo en la pregunta, estos puede ocultar cuál es exactamente tu problema.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Una pregunta sin un MCVE es mucho más difícil de responder. Esto además significa que es menos probable de ser respondida. Los usuarios expermentados es posible que puedan determinar el problema, pero les tomará más tiempo del necesario hacerlo. O se verán forzados a adivinar las posibles razones hasta dar con la correcta, o se darán por vencidos. Esto se considera poco adecuado ya que hace perder el tiempo a los que están tratando de ayudarte con tu problema.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Crea un [MCVE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! Existen varios [tutoriales (en inglés)](http://www.sscce.org/) disponibles, algunos de los cuales son parte de mas extensas guías sobre "Cómo hacer una buena pregunta", como [ésta misma (en inglés)](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)(ver la sección “Sample code and data”). ¡Léelas! Están ahí para ayudarte.

Una vez entiendas correctamente el concepto, vuelve y edita tu pregunta. Si tienes demasiado código, ¡límpialo! Elimina todo lo que no tenga nada que ver con tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, elimina las líneas vacías y los comentarios, si estos nos son relevantes para la pregunta. Si el código contiene HTML markup, elimina los detalles sobre el CSS y el *layout* que no sean parte de la pregunta.

Si no tienes código, crea un ejemplo que reproduzca exactamente lo que tu lógica intenta hacer. Hazlo lo más limpio y claro posible, asegurándote de que reproduce tu error. ¡Puedes llegar a sorprenderte descubriendo tú mismo cuál era tu problema simplemente haciendo esto! Pero si no es el caso, puedes usar ese ejemplo para añadirlo a tu pregunta.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83)

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativo porque no has proporcionado un Ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2876) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativo porque no has proporcionado un Ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2876/)`.</sub>

Answer (score 13):

### Te he votado negativamente porque hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta

**La investigación es un primer paso muy importante a la hora de resolver problemas**

Resolver problemas puede ser un trabajo duro. Cuando nos encontramos con alguno para el que no tenemos suficientes conocimientos, es a menudo muy tentador simplemente preguntar a otro para que éste resuelva nuestro problema. Es muy común encontrar que la duda que tenemos es una que muchas otras personas han tenido antes, y muchas de esas personas ya hicieron la misma pregunta recibiendo respuestas correctas. Considerando la gran cantidad de información existente en internet y en Stack Overflow en Español, normalmente con una o dos simples búsquedas encontraremos la solución.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Hemos realizado una pregunta, pero no hemos añadido que investigación previa hemos realizado. Esto no significa que no la hayamos hecho, solo que la evidencia de dicha investigación no está en la pregunta. La gente que lea nuestra pregunta puede que no entienda, si saben que con una pequeña investigación habríamos encontrado la solución, porqué aparentemente no lo hemos intentado. Pueden sugerir cosas que nosotros ya hemos intentado, o simplemente pueden considerar que somos unos vagos e ignorar la pregunta. Nos arriesgamos a recibir votos negativos y perdemos la oportunidad de recibir respuestas correctas a nuestra pregunta.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

La primera parte del texto que aparece cuando pasamos el ratón por encima del botón de votación negativa es *"Esta pregunta no parece tener un trabajo de investigación"*. La primera sección de la página [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) comienza con una cabecera que dice ***Busca, e investiga*** .Esto indica lo importante que es la investigación previa, no solo para Stack Overflow en Español, sino para resolver problemas en general. Nos debemos a nosotros mismos, y a todos los que voluntariamente tratan de ayudarnos, intentar resolver nuestros propios problemas antes de pedir ayuda.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Si todavía no hemos investigado sobre nuestro problema, y nadie ha respondido nuestra pregunta, deberíamos eliminarla. Podemos mantener el enlace a la misma para posteriormente poder mejorarla. Entonces, debemos comenzar a investigar nuestro problema, manteniendo un registro de lo que hemos buscado, que hemos encontrado, que hemos probado y porqué no ha funcionado. No es necesario enlazar absolutamenete todo lo que hemos buscado, pero al menos debemos referenciar preguntas similares y explicar porqué razón no han funcionado en nuestro caso.
Como dice en la página  [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask):

> Incluso si no encuentras una respuesta útil en cualquier parte del
>   sitio, incluyendo en los enlaces sobre preguntas relacionadas o que no
>   hayan ayudado pueden ayudar a otros a entender cómo tu pregunta es
>   diferente del resto.

Si nuestra investigación es fructuosa y hemos encontrado nuestra respuesta, genial! Podemos dejar que la pregunta permanezca cerrada. Si la respuesta la hemos encontrado en el mismo Stack Overflow en Español, y queremos que otros con nuestro mismo problema puedan encontrar la solución, podemos recuperar nuestra pregunta y votar para cerrarla como duplicado de la respuesta que encontramos. Si tras la investigación no hemos encontrado ninguna respuesta, podemos volver a nuestra pregunta, editarla para añadir todos los resultados de nuestra investigación y porqué no nos han servido. Una vez editada con todos estos datos, podemos recuperarla para que los usuarios puedan tratar de responderla.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)`.</sub>

Comment: Mejor conocida como ¿Por qué no somos un remplazo de un motor de búsquedas?

Answer (score 13):

### Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código

**El código es lo que sirve, pero se necesita algo más.**

Puede que hayas escrito una línea, o 50, pero solamente se ve código. El código es lo que sirve, pero sin saber cómo funciona, solamente se puede copiar y pegar y no servirá a futuro.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Los futuros lectores, necesitaran leer la pregunta, el código y tratar de interpretar si para un escenario similar tu código se ajusta. Puede que sea demasiado código, y tratar de entender si todo es la solución a un problema similar lleve mucho tiempo.Puede que sea solo una línea, pero haga algo tan complejo que haya que buscar función por función que es lo que hace.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Te tomaste el trabajo de copiar un código, propio o sacado de otro lado, y eso es muy bueno. Sin embargo, para alcanzar a más gente y que se pueda comprender que hiciste, estaría bueno explicar que hace, o si tiene funciones raras o hace cosas fuera de contexto que resuelven el problema, explicarlo.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Explica tu código. Explica esencialmente que hace, como lo hace, y si puedes explica secciones de tu código que no estarían del todo claras a simple vista.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)`.</sub>

Answer (score 12):

### Te he votado negativamente porque tu pregunta no incluye los detalles de la excepción.

**Necesitamos TODO el detalle de la excepción para ayudarte.**

En tu pregunta, indicaste que tu código lanzaba una excepción. Esa es información que nos sirve para encontrar una solución. Sin embargo, para encontrar esa solución necesitamos TODOS los detalles que se pueden encontrar en la excepción. Si una pregunta no tiene estos detalles, se hace difícil poder ayudarte.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

La pregunta solo contiene una parte o nada de esta información, por lo que es difícil o incluso imposible ayudar. Las excepciones contienen un montón de información, que sirve para determinar qué pasa con tu código.

**¿Qué detalles necesitamos?**

Las excepciones contienen muchos detalles sobre lo que pasó en el momento de ser lanzadas. Toda esta información nos da pistas sobre por qué la excepción fue lanzada. Detalles de la excepción que necesitamos son:

- El tipo de excepción
- El mensaje
- La pila de llamadas
- Todas las excepciones internas, con sus tipos, mensajes y pila de
  llamadas.

Alguno (o más) de esos pueden ser necesarios para diagnosticar el problema. Si no provees esta información, estamos forzados a adivinar qué puede estar pasando. Usualmente es simple recopilar esta información, sigue leyendo para obtener consejos de cómo obtenerla.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Las excepciones contienen casi toda la información que nosotros, la gente que trata de ayudarte, necesitamos para obtener una rápida respuesta. Cuando no nos das esta información, debemos examinar la pregunta buscando pistas sobre la información que deberías haber puesto en principio. Esto gasta el tiempo de gente que (**¡gratuitamente!**) trata de ayudarte.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Consigue un reporte en texto de todo el contenido de la excepción. Recuerda que el error debe ser capturado como texto, ¡no como una imagen! Esto usualmente se hace fácil, pero acá va un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo en distintas IDE.

**Visual Studio and .NET**

Si estás usando Visual Studio, el diálogo de la excepción contiene un enlace que te permite copiarlo al portapapeles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si estás experimentando la excepción en tiempo de ejecución, puedes intentar atrapar la excepción y llamar al metodo `ToString()` para loguear los resultados de ella de la forma que más te convenga.
Debes capturar todos los detalles de la excepción y editar la pregunta agregando dicha información. Es importante que lo agregues en la pregunta y no en un comentario, porque en los comentarios es difícil formatearlo y además no hay suficiente espacio. Hay un botón "editar" debajo de tu pregunta, presiónalo y pega los detalles en la pregunta. Asegúrate que el texto esté bien formateado y se lea fácilmente.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque tu pregunta no incluye los detalles de la excepción.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2877) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque tu pregunta no incluye los detalles de la excepción.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2877/)`.</sub>

Answer (score 12):

### Te he votado negativamente porque solamente pusiste un enlace.

**Los enlaces no son malos, pero son volátiles.**

Agregaste un enlace a tu respuesta, lo cual es genial, pero solamente pusiste eso, sin decir nada más.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Los enlaces son volátiles: si son a páginas externas puede que la página deje de existir. Además, puede que hayas enlazado toda una biblioteca, donde el problema de la pregunta está explicado, pero hay que navegar para encontrar la solución. Puede que el enlace solo sea un pedazo de código, pero entonces habría que tratar de comprenderlo.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Te tomaste el trabajo de poner un enlace, que buscaste o tenías, y eso es genial, pero no hiciste nada más para enriquecer la respuesta. Para las respuestas se espera un poco de elaboración para que futuros usuarios sepan de qué se está hablando.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Deja el enlace en su lugar. Pero copia las partes esenciales del mismo, explica cómo solucionar el problema, y deja el enlace solo como referencia futura.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó a este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque solamente pusiste un enlace.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2883) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque solamente pusiste un enlace.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2883/)`.</sub>

Answer (score 11):

### Te he votado negativamente porque no se aprecia ningún esfuerzo en depurar el código

**No parece que hayas realizado ningún esfuerzo para depurar tu código**

Depurar código es una de las cosas más importantes que un desarrollador puede hacer. Cuando el resultado de un programa es inesperado, o cuando un programa se detiene con un error en tiempo de ejecución, la depuración es una forma rápida para que el desarrollador aísle e identifique el problema. En la gran mayoría de casos, una vez el problema es identificado, la solución es evidente. Pero cuando el desarrollador no depura su código, el problema es mucho mas difícil de arreglar.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Sin hacer el esfuerzo de depurar el código que está fallando, cuanto menos obvio sea el problema, más difícil sera encontrar una solución. A veces si tienes suerte el problema puede hacerse evidente simplemente viendo el código. Pero ese no es siempre el caso. Una solución que podría tardar diez minutos en encontrarse usando la depuración, podría llevar horas y ocupar el esfuerzo de varias personas sin hacerlo.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Sin depurar, estás arriesgándote a hacer perder el tiempo a los que están intentando ayudarte. Si el problema es fácil de solucionar, y habría sido evidente simplemente depurando el código, no había necesidad de hacer tu pregunta para empezar. El tiempo que has empleado en hacer tu pregunta podrías haberlo usado para solucionar tu problema. El tiempo que otros perdieron leyendo tu pregunta podría haber sido utilizado para ayudar a otras personas con problemas mas complicados de diagnosticar. Y cuando tu problema es complicado, sin haberlo aislado exactamente mediante la depuración del código, hace que otros deban intentar adivinar las posibles causas. Necesitará de mucho *tira y afloja* sobre las posibles causas y soluciones. La depuración ayuda a evitar todo esto.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

¡Depura tu código!

- Ejecuta tu código con el depurado de tu IDE favorito enlazado.
- Pon puntos de depuración cerca del lugar donde está fallando tu código.
- Examina las variables y su contenido en tiempo de ejecución.
- Observa como tu lógica evalúa estas variables y examina los resultados para ver si son correctos.

Puede que encuentres que lo que creías que era el resultado, en realidad no lo era, permitiéndose así arreglar tu algoritmo. O tal vez no entiendas porqué tu algoritmo está fallando. En ese caso, recopila todas esa información (el algoritmo, el valor de tus variables, y cuál es el resultado no esperado que recibes). Con todo ello, te será fácil hacer una buena pregunta!

Una vez que hayas depurado tu código, recopila todo lo que has aprendido y edita tu pregunta. *Nota: ¡No añadas esta información como uno o varios comentarios en tu pregunta! En lugar de eso, edita tu pregunta para añadir toda esta información con un formato adecuado*. Añade el código que te falte, si lo hay, que sea relevante para tu pregunta.

Si has encontrado la solución a tu problema después de haber depurado el código, y piensas que esa solución puede ser útil para otros, puedes añadir una respuesta a tu propia pregunta con detalles sobre que hiciste y que encontraste al depurar. Si otros has respondido a tu pregunta, y éstas eran parcial o totalmente correctas, selecciona la mejor de ellas como respuesta aceptada. Si tu propia respuesta es la única, después del tiempo requerido, puedes aceptar tu respuesta como la correcta y cerrar así tu pregunta. Puede parecer raro, pero aquí aceptar tu propia respuesta es perfectamente aceptable y es de hecho como manejamos estas situaciones. Si tu respuesta no será de utilidad para nadie más, y nadie la ha respondido, puedes simplemente borrarla.

**¿Cómo puedo depurar mi código?**

Es bastante común que los nuevos desarrolladores no sepan como depurar su código. A continuación se añaden enlaces a diferentes artículos sobre como depurar código usando diferente herramientas.

Si no estás seguro para empezar de que trata todo esto de depurar, [aquí hay un artículo introductorio sobre el tema en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depuraci%C3%B3n_de_programas)

- ***Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code***

Para aprender a usar las herramientas de depuración disponibles en las últimas versiones de Visual Studio, [pulsa en este enlace](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour). Para Visual Studio Code, mira [aqui](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging).

- ***Javascript (en el navegador)***

Puedes depurar tu código javascript directamente en la mayoría de navegadores, incluyendo a [Chrome](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging), [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger), [Edge](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/f12-devtools-guide/debugger), y [Safari](https://developer.apple.com/safari/tools/).

- ***Xcode***

Puedes aprender como depurar en el IDE de Xcode [aqui](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/debugging_tools.html).

- ***Android Studio***

Para aprender a depurar tu aplicación Android, [visita este enlace](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html).

- ***Tu IDE favorito***

Si tienes algún IDE favorito que quieras añadir a esta lista, hazlo simplemente editando esta respuesta.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque no se aprecia ningún esfuerzo en depurar el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872/) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque no se aprecia ningún esfuerzo en depurar el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872/)`.</sub>

Answer (score 11):

### Te he votado negativamente porque solo pusiste una imagen de tu excepción

**Imágenes de la excepción no son de ayuda**

En tu pregunta, indicaste que se lanzaba una excepción en tiempo de ejecución. Esa es buena información que necesitamos para solucionar el problema. Sin embargo, para poder ayudar, necesitamos los detalles de la excepción. Si tu pregunta no tiene un detalle de esta información, es complicado tratar de ayudarte.

**¿Por que es un problema?**

Pegar una imagen de la excepcion no es de gran ayuda. No es necesario que pegues una imagen para demostrar que tu codigo lanza una excepcion, te creemos cuando lo dijiste en la pregunta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imágenes de la excepción con un poco mas de información tampoco son de gran ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Una de las primeras cosas que las personas hacen cuando tratan de ayudar a otro es pegar la excepción en su buscador favorito. Cuando pegas una imagen en tu pregunta, estas obligando a la gente que esta tratando de ayudarte (gratis!) a transcribir la excepción desde la imagen. No solamente esto genera una perdida de tiempo, si no también puede resultar en un error en la transcripción y reducir la posibilidad que la búsqueda sea exitosa.

Ninguna imagen puede contener todos los detalles de tu excepción. Las excepciones contienen una pila de errores que en general son muy largas y no entran en una imagen. También pueden contener excepciones internas con sus propias pilas de errores, que pueden contener a su vez mas excepciones internas. Tu imagen no nos esta dando toda la información necesaria!

Se puede agregar también que las imágenes no son indexadas. Por lo tanto es muy difícil, si no imposible, encontrar tu pregunta usando un motor de búsqueda. Reduce la visibilidad de la pregunta y evita que futuros lectores la encuentren. También genera problemas a la gente con discapacidad visual, ya que los lectores de pantalla no leerán eso.
Adicionalmente, cabe agregar que no todas las personas tienen la capacidad visual, es decir, una persona con debilidad visual o sin la facultad de la visión le será imposible conocer la traza de la excepción y por lo tanto, no podrá ni ayudarte ni recibir ayuda.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Debes capturar todos los detalles de la excepción y editar la pregunta agregando dicha información. Es importante que lo agregues en la pregunta y no en un comentario, porque en los comentarios es difícil formatearlo y ademas no hay suficiente espacio. Hay un botón "editar" debajo de tu pregunta, presiónalo y pega los detalles en la pregunta. Asegúrate que el texto este bien formateado y se lea fácilmente.

**Capturando los detalles de tu excepcion**

Capturar todos los detalles de tu excepción suele ser fácil, dependiendo del lenguaje y herramientas que estés usando.

**Ejemplo usando Visual Studio**

Si estas usando Visual estudio, el dialogo de ayuda sobre excepciones tiene un link que te permite copiar la informacion al portapapeles.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si la excepción te ocurre en tiempo de ejecución y no ves el dialogo, puedes llamar a la función `ToString()` en la clase de errores. Guarda el resultado, con el método que te parezca mas conveniente.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque solo pusiste una imagen de tu excepción](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque solo pusiste una imagen de tu excepción](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2873/)`.</sub>

Comment: Relacionado: [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/)

Answer (score 11):

### Te he votado negativamente porque sin código es difícil ayudarte

**Es difícil contestar una pregunta sobre programación sin ver el código**

Es realmente difícil contestar una pregunta sobre un bug en tu código, cuando tu pregunta ***no incluye el código que esta bugueado***. Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver lo que está pasando.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Hiciste una pregunta sobre un problema con tu código. Tal vez no esté dando lo que esperas que dé, o no está compilando, o cuando se ejecuta tira una excepción. Sin embargo, no incluiste el código relevante. Código que la gente que trata de ayudarte puede examinar para ayudarte a encontrar el problema o que puede ser usado para reproducirlo.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Así como está, la pregunta difícilmente pueda ser contestada. Cualquier solución se va a basar en adivinar. Y aunque alguien adivine correctamente y obtengas una respuesta, no proveer el código significa que va a ser difícil para futuros lectores saber si la solución se aplica a su problema. Preguntas que no son valiosas para otros usuarios no están bien vistas en Stack Overflow.
También demuestra que no pusiste mucho esfuerzo en escribir la pregunta. Recuerda, estás pidiendo a la gente que te *ayude*, **gratis**. Dar la suficiente información para contestar tu pregunta es lo menos que puedes hacer. Fallar en eso es **hacer perder el tiempo a otras personas**, y hacerles perder el tiempo, cuando tratan de ayudar, es muy rudo.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Edita la pregunta agregando un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). ¡El código no debe ser copiado completo desde tu editor o IDE! En lugar de eso, debe ser resumido a las partes esenciales para identificar y reproducir el problema.
De esa forma, tu problema puede ser rápidamente identificado por usuarios experimentados y resuelto en sus respuestas. Estas respuestas serán de mejor calidad y reflejaran mejor el problema propuesto, llamando más la atención sobre la pregunta (y provocando votos positivos). Futuros lectores podrán rápidamente descubrir si su problema está relacionado con el de ellos.
¡No pegues tu código en comentarios! Los comentarios no se pueden formatear, y no se considera un lugar valido para poner código. Hay un botón "editar" debajo de tu pregunta. Presiónalo y agrega tu código a la pregunta.
¡Tómate el tiempo formateando tu código apropiadamente! Si tu código es un lío, se hace más difícil para otros entenderlo. [Puedes encontrar información de cómo formatear tu pregunta acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque sin código es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque sin código es difícil ayudarte](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2875/)`.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

### Te he votado negativamente porque un exceso de código no es de ayuda

**Por favor, incluye la mínima cantidad de código necesaria para ilustrar tu problema**

Como en el dicho popular *una aguja en un pajar*, has hecho que sea difícil encontrar el error en tu código.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Hay un enorme bloque de código en tu pregunta. El problema real que tienes debe estar en solo unas pocas instrucciones, y la mayoría del código que has añadido es completamente irrelevante para la resolución de tu problema. Es solo ruido que hace mas complicado para los que tratan de responder tu pregunta ayudarte.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

El ruido generado por todo el código que rodea al error hace que futuros usuarios no puedan hacer relacionar tu pregunta y posibles respuestas con su propio problema. También hace mucho más difícil para cualquiera determinar cual es el problema. Esto hace menos probable que tu pregunta reciba una respuesta, y hace perder el tiempo a quien trata de ayudarte. En resumen, la pregunta solo es útil para ti, es menos probable que obtenga respuestas, y es de poca o ninguna utilidad a la comunidad como un todo.

Además muestra que no se ha empleado mucho esfuerzo en la confección de la pregunta. Los usuarios aquí ofrecen su tiempo voluntariamente, gratis, para intentar ayudarte. Debes ser considerado con su esfuerzo. Una de las formas mas sencillas y útiles de hacer esto es reducir tu código al mínimo indispensable para ilustrar tu problema.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Aísla el problema y crea un [Ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Ver también [Te he votado negativo porque no has proporcionado un Ejemplo Mínimo, Completo y Verificable](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2876/)). Un ejemplo así normalmente consiste en unas pocas líneas de código, como una función o una solicitud a una base de datos.

[Debes depurar el código](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2872/) para indentificar el punto exacto donde ocurre el problema. Una vez identificado, deberías reescribirlo suprimiendo las partes no relevantes y comprobando que el error sigue sucediendo.

Para markup (html, xml, etc), elimina atributos, espacios de nombres, estilos y elementos que no tengan nada que ver con el problema.

Si te preocupa que algo de lo que has suprimido pueda jugar algun papel en el problema, explícalo en tu pregunta. Los usuarios con suficientes conocimientos sobre la cuestión te harán saber si necesitan alguna información adicional. [Mantente disponible tras realizar tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2870/) y responde rápidamente a estas solicitudes! Si no puedes, es mejor que esperes a realizar tu pregunta a un momento en el que puedas estarlo.

Una vez tengas un código reducido a lo esencial, puedes sustituir el anterior en tu pregunta editándola. Puedes encontrar el enlace para editar en la parte inferior de tu pregunta.

Ahora tu código puede ser leído rápidamente, entendido, y solucionado por los usuarios que te respondan. Los futuros lectores podrán ver de un solo vistazo si tu problema está o no relacionado con el tuyo.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/toomuchcode/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque un exceso de código no es de ayuda.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2879) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque un exceso de código no es de ayuda.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2879)`.</sub>

Comment: una cantidad de codigo excesivo?

Answer (score 10):

### Te he votado negativamente porque es una pregunta flagrantemente fuera de tópico.

**Las preguntas fuera de tópico deben ser eliminadas.**

Pusiste una respuesta a una pregunta que esta explícitamente fuera del alcance de las preguntas válidas para el sitio, y esta clase de preguntas se cierran y eliminan del sistema.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Cuando se contesta esta clase de preguntas, no se está educando a OP sobre qué tipo de preguntas son válidas o no. Tampoco aportan a la calidad del sitio, y en algunos casos generan controversia o discusiones acaloradas que no llevan a ningún lado y hacen solamente ruido. Muchas veces estas preguntas no ayudan a futuros usuarios si se mantienen en el sistema, confundiendo sobre los alcances de la página.

**¿Que tópicos no se deberían contestar nunca?**

La página de ayuda sobre [que se puede preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) aclara específicamente cuales son las preguntas validas. Las preguntas con motivos de cierres claros y que no se deberían contestar incluyen:

- Preguntas en otro idioma que no sea español
- Preguntas que piden explícitamente recomendaciones sobre como actuar
- Preguntas que son claramente errores tipográficos
- Preguntas duplicadas
- Preguntas donde se pide que se haga un trabajo y no se demuestra que se ha hecho hasta el momento.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Te tomaste el trabajo de contestar, y eso es genial, pero estas contestando una pregunta que no aporta calidad al sitio, o genera ruido.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Elimina la respuesta, has una copia si quieres. Monitorea la pregunta a ver si en algún momento se corrige y cuando ello ocurra, vuelve a poner tu respuesta.

---

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque es una pregunta flagrantemente fuera de tópico.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2884) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque es una pregunta flagrantemente fuera de tópico.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2884/)`.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

### Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar

**Si entiendes la pregunta contesta. Si no, no trates de adivinar.**

Este es un sitio para resolver las dudas concretas de otros. Malas preguntas normalmente reciben malas respuestas. Asimismo preguntas muy generales llevan a respuestas muy generales y muy frecuentemente de baja calidad que no ayudan a alguien que busque un problema en específico. Lo más probable es que hayas tratado de contestar una pregunta que no tenía todos los detalles necesarios.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Si la pregunta no está bien planteada o es confusa, es de esperar que tu respuesta sea también confusa y que no demuestre realmente que eres un experto en el tema, y que sabes de lo que estás hablando.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Se aprecia tu intención de ayudar, pero si no entiendes que preguntan o que problema enfrentan, podrías perjudicar en vez de ayudar, deberías de esperar a tener la mínima cantidad necesaria de información acerca del problema para asegurarte que tu respuesta va a ser 100% correcta.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Revisa tu solución, y si piensas que solamente adivinaste, puedes eliminarla o reportarla para pedir a un moderador que la elimine; esto seguamente te evitará muchos votos negativos si resulta ser incorrecta.
Si tu respuesta ya fue aceptada y estás seguro que no es correcta, hazle saber a los demás cuál es la solución correcta. Si no sabes cuál es la solución correcta, pon el estilo tachado en el texto (<s>así</s>, es decir, `<s>así</s>`) y en un comentario explica por qué tu solución no es correcta.

**busca mejorar la pregunta**

Puedes solicitar a quien preguntó que mejore su pregunta, en los comentarios de la misma, aclarando que partes generan dudas. Tambien podrías sugerir ediciones a su pregunta para que sea más clara.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342) usando este código: `[Te podrían votar negativamente porque no esperaste a entender la pregunta antes de contestar.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3217/342)`.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

### Te he votado negativamente porque no sabemos lo suficiente sobre tu base de datos.

**Necesitamos toda la información relevante sobre tu base de datos.**

Estás haciendo una pregunta sobre un problema con tu base de datos. Puede ser un problema de una consulta que no funciona, una consulta que no devuelve lo que corresponde, o una consulta, que según tus parámetros, anda lenta. Para poder ayudarte, es necesario que nos adjuntes la información relevante sobre tu base de datos.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

La pregunta contiene información incompleta sobre tu base de datos. Puede ser que se deba a no tener datos de prueba, el esquema no contempla toda la información necesaria, dices que obtienes un resultado erróneo pero no dices cual es el correcto, dices que anda lenta pero no dices basado en que datos. Todo esto provoca que no podamos hacer una respuesta correcta.

**¿Qué datos necesitamos?**

Las preguntas sobre base de datos requieren mucha información para poder replicar el problema y actuar sobre él. Preguntar sobre porque una consulta es lenta, sin aclarar si la tabla tiene 10 registros o 100 millones, no nos da nada de información. Para que podamos resolver tu consulta necesitamos
Sobre qué base de datos estas trabajando

- El esquema necesario para resolver la consulta (no solamente una imagen, también el esquema en formato SQL)
- Todas las consultas que probaste y no anduvieron
- La salida que conseguiste, y la salida real que quieres obtener
- Un explain plan (o query execution plan, si no sabes lo que es, búscalo en tu buscador favorito).
- Si es posible, un [fiddle](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2446/fiddles-lista-de-p%c3%a1ginas-que-podemos-usar-para-probar-c%c3%b3digo-y-sus-caracter%c3%adsti) de ejemplo para hacer las pruebas

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Las preguntas sobre base de datos suelen ser complejas, y requerir una importante cantidad de tiempo para ser resueltas. Si no te tomaste el tiempo en agregar toda esta información para recibir ayuda, la gente que quiere ayudarte (*¡GRATIS!*) no tiene porque tomarse el tiempo en agregar toda esta información, o pedírtela porque no la incluiste. Puede que la gente imite consultas que ya probaste, porque no aclaraste cuales probaste hasta ahora que no funcionaron, lo cual haría que perdieran el tiempo duplicando el trabajo.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Verifica que la información necesaria para saber los datos está en tu pregunta. Agrega el explain plan, el esquema de la base de datos  en formato sql, un fiddle de ser posible, datos de prueba, la salida esperada y la salida obtenida, y todos los querys que probaste.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque no sabemos nada sobre tu base de datos.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque no sabemos lo suficiente sobre tu base de datos.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2880/)`.</sub>

Answer (score 9):

### Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta

**Todos nos equivocamos pero no hagamos que otros se equivoquen.**

Este es un sitio para compartir conocimiento, no se pide que todos sean expertos, pero sí que al menos intenten probar las soluciones por su cuenta.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Los futuros lectores encontrarán una respuesta que no es correcta y podría confundirlos.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Se aprecia tu intención de ayudar, pero si no sabes, podrías perjudicar en vez de ayudar.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Revisa tu solución, y si estás seguro que no es para nada correcta, puedes eliminarla o reportarla para pedir a un moderador que la elimine. 
Si tu respuesta ya fue aceptada y estás seguro que no es correcta, hazles saber a los demás cuál es la solución correcta. Si no sabes cuál es la solución correcta, pon el estilo tachado en el texto (<s>así</s>, es decir, `<s>así</s>`) y en un comentario explica por qué tu solución no es correcta.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque tu respuesta es totalmente incorrecta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2912)`.</sub>

Comment: Excelente Ruslan!, la mayoría de las propuestas realizadas aquí solo se enfocan únicamente en las preguntas, muchas gracias por esta contribución!

Answer (score 9):

## Te podrían votar negativamente porque solicitar ayuda URGENTE es descortés y hasta grosero.

En el mejor de los casos, esto solo añade ruido a tu pregunta y se interpone en la presentación de la pregunta real. Además, **esto hace que sea más difícil para otras personas ayudarte, lo que hace que sea menos probable que obtengas una respuesta.**

Nadie, al ver que necesitas una respuesta lo antes posible va a abandonar todo lo que está haciendo para ayudarte. Tus emergencias son tuyas. Alternativamente: la falta de planificación de tu parte no constituye una emergencia para otras personas.

En el peor de los casos, esto puede ser visto como muy grosero. **Específicamente, decir que tus necesidades son urgentes o que necesitas una respuesta lo antes posible implica que tu tiempo es más valioso que el de otras personas que hacen preguntas, o de las personas que, generosamente, responden a estas preguntas.

**Otras personas que hacen preguntas desean una respuesta, tanto como tu lo haces.**

Las personas que responden preguntas **lo hacen gratis**, en su tiempo libre. ¿Por qué tu tiempo es más valioso que el de ellos?

Esto desalentará activamente a las personas que podrían responder tu pregunta y, probablemente, incluso puede traerte algunos votos negativos, lo que hace que sea aún menos probable que obtenga una respuesta.

Además, en mi experiencia, las publicaciones que contienen *necesito ayuda lo antes posible* y *ayuda urgente*, por lo general, suelen contener otros problemas.

**Hacer una investigación adecuada toma tiempo, por lo que, si tienes prisa, probablemente no estés haciendo la investigación adecuada (antes de preguntar).

- ¿Te has tomado el tiempo para hacer tu propia depuración?
- ¿Te has tomado el tiempo para agregar declaraciones de impresión, o para reducir el problema a un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), o para leer la documentación?

Si tienes prisa, entonces la respuesta es probablemente no. Y si no has hecho estas cosas, entonces es más difícil para nosotros ayudarte.

La mejor manera de mejorar tus posibilidades de obtener una respuesta es haciéndonos más fácil responderte. No incluir una investigación adecuada hace que sea más difícil ayudarte, lo que nuevamente disminuye tus posibilidades de obtener una respuesta. Puede parecer paradójico, pero si tienes prisa, lo mejor que puedes hacer es disminuir la velocidad.

Así que, realmente, no hay razón para incluir su urgencia, y un montón de razones **para no incluirla**.

---

- <sub>Compatible con el texto [Te podrían votar negativamente por pedir ayuda urgente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152): `[Te podrían votar negativamente por pedir ayuda urgente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152)`</sub>
- <sub>Compatible con el texto [Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152): `[Te podrían votar negativamente porque pedir ayuda urgente es descortés y hasta grosero](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4152)`</sub>

Inspirado en [esta respuesta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326590/255257) (en meta en inglés)

Answer (score 7):

### Te he votado negativamente porque solicitas directamente que alguien haga tu trabajo/tarea escolar (sin demostrar ningún esfuerzo por resolverla por ti mismo).

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

StackOverflow es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas para programadores y entusiastas del desarrollo y uso de software, no es un sitio donde programadores <del>sin nada que hacer</del> están dispuestos a hacer las tareas escolares o el trabajo de otras personas de manera gratuita y tampoco es un sitio de publicación de trabajos para contratación de programadores.

Una de las ideas principales de la existencia del sitio es ayudarnos entre todos, no solo a resolver los problemas que enfrentamos día a día, sino a mejorar entre todos nuestro conocimiento mutuo.

La idea más elevada que perseguimos es construir una inmensa base de datos donde prácticamente se encuentre la respuesta a cualquier pregunta de programación.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Todos los que respondemos acá hemos adquirido el conocimiento invirtiendo muchas horas de esfuerzo y dedicación, muchas veces a lo largo de toda una vida de estudio y trabajo.

Si inicias en la programación, comprendemos que es normal que tengas dudas y, creeme, seguirán surgiendo dudas aunque tengas muchos años de experiencia.

Sabemos también que hacerte la tarea no te beneficiará en lo más mínimo. Si te interesa aprender a programar, pon esfuerzo de tu parte, lee tus libros, pregunta a tus maestros. Pregunta en StackOverflow, creeme, se notará cuando hayas intentado resolver las cosas por ti mismo. Entonces, encontrarás aquí una apasionada comunidad dispuesta a ayudarte.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Inicia leyendo [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Si ya has invertido tiempo en resolver tu tarea por ti mismo, utiliza el botón de `editar` bajo la pregunta para mejorarla. No coloques solamente la descripción que el profesor o tu jefe te ha dado para el problema. Muchas veces esta ni siquiera hace falta, pues tu duda se puede resumir de otra forma más concisa y sin tanto contexto (entre más tenga que leer, pero sobre todo comprender quién lee tu pregunta, menos probable es que tenga el tiempo y motivación para hacerlo).

Si tu duda lo permite, intenta siempre producir primero un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Asegurate que la pregunta incluye las etiquetas adecuadas y, si estás limitado al uso de alguna sentencia/tecnología, no olvides incluir la información en la misma.

Coloca el código que has escrito (solo lo relevante a la pregunta). Si no hay código para publicar, seguro podrás escribir algunos párrafos describiendo lo que has intentado y cómo esto ha fallado. Incluye siempre los mensajes de error exactos que obtienes en cada caso.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo (si lo hizo). [Recuerda usar `@usuario` para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/21), y con suerte, quizás también esté en capacidad y buena disposición para escribir una respuesta.

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te podrían votar negativamente porque pides directamente que hagan tu trabajo/tarea escolar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794) usando este código: `[Te podrían votar negativamente porque pides directamente que hagan tu trabajo/tarea escolar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320)`.</sub>

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque pides directamente que hagan tu trabajo/tarea escolar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque pides directamente que hagan tu trabajo/tarea escolar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320)`.</sub>

Answer (score 6):

### Te podrían votar negativamente debido a que respondiste en un idioma que no es el español.

**El idioma de este sitio es el español**

Este es un sitio para compartir conocimiento orientado a la comunidad hispanohablante usando el idioma español, también llamado castellano, sin importar su ubicación geográfica.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Si la respuesta está en otro idioma los hispanohablantes no se benefician, las comunidades específicas de ese idioma en Stackoverflow no se benefician y las búsquedas en español de este sitio podrían regresar resultados erróneos.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Se aprecia tu intención de ayudar, pero el sitio es en español, por lo que las respuestas deben ser en dicho idioma, requiere esfuerzo adicional por parte de las personas que contribuimos a este sitio el traducirlo y si es un problema común, la gente hallaría el resultado sin estar éste en el idioma que más domina y que le permite una mejor comprensión.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Lo ideal es que lo traduzcas, si no te es posible contacta con los moderadores. Una vez traducido, **comenta** que ya esta traducido, y posiblemente quienes te hayan votado negativamente quieran gustosamente cambiar su voto.

---

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te podrían votar negativamente debido a que respondiste en un idioma que no es el español.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3222/342) usando este código: `[Te podrían votar negativamente debido a que respondiste en un idioma que no es el español](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3222/342)`.</sub>

Comment: "¿Si entiendes que..." me parece que es contrario a [Compórtate bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) específicamente en lo que se refiere a ser acogedor y paciente, lo cual procederé a editarlo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Rubén

Comment: Aunque he editado esta respuesta aún siento que tiene margen para mejoras importantes por ejemplo en lo que se refiere a la explicación del porqué es un problema que las respuestas no sean en español y del porqué merece un voto negativo, siento que no concuerdan.

Comment: Otra cosa con la que no me siento cómodo es con el texto "Te he votado negativamente". Encontré que otros se sienten igual por lo que se publicó [¿Deberíamos poner un texto más “constructivo” a la hora de enlazar las publicaciones de “¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?”?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2938/65). En su [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2940/65) Mariano propone varias redacciones alternativas.

Comment: Yo no se si estoy de acuerdo con usar esta. El resto se supone que se usan para que quien escribe sepa que hay margen para mejorar. Esto es una violacion de las normas flagrante.

Comment: @Rubén yo también le pondría algo como "Te podrían votar negativamente debido a", pero tendremos que esperar hasta que haya consenso en el estándard del lenguaje a usar

Comment: @gbianchi yo lo entiendo, es saltarse las normas del sitio por ayudar a alguien en el menor tiempo posible, en cierta manera preferiría una opción de reportarlo tal y como se hace con las preguntas como esta respuesta está en inglés el idioma oficial es español y quitarse de problemas al avisarles que si no está en español corre peligro de ser eliminado.

Comment: @gbianchi No me parece mal tener una explicación de porque se debe responder en español pues en algunos foros si se permite responder en un idioma diferente al de la pregunta, en particular aquellos que incluyen una función de traducción automática. En el caso de soes no me ha tocado ver que se responda en inglés a una pregunta escrita en español, pero antes de enlazar a esta publicación yo esperaría que tuviera mejoras importantes.

Comment: @RuslanLópezCarro Me parece que aún no hay una guía sobre cómo contribuir así que siendo tu el autor original de esta respuesta, sí así lo quisieras, estás en "tu derecho" de hacer el cambio del texto según te parezca mejor.

Answer (score 3):

### Te he votado negativamente porque poner solamente código en tu pregunta dificulta mucho ayudarte

**El código es lo que sirve, pero se necesita algo más.**

Puede que hayas escrito una línea, o 50, pero solamente se ve código. El código es muy útil, pero sin saber que problema tienes con él es muy probable que malgastes el tiempo de los demás.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Los futuros lectores, necesitaran leer el código y tratar de interpretar si para un escenario similar tu código se ajusta a su problema. Tratar de entender su significado y los problemas que tenga puede que lleve mucho tiempo. Puede que sea solo una línea, pero haga algo tan complejo que haya que buscar función por función que es lo que hace y que a pesar de ello funcione en otros ambientes y en el tuyo no.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Te tomaste el trabajo de copiar un código, propio o sacado de otro lado, y eso es muy bueno. Sin embargo, para alcanzar a más gente y que se pueda comprender que hiciste, estaría bueno explicar que hace o no hace, o si se requiere alguna configuración, y que deberia de hacer.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Explica el problema en tu código. Explica esencialmente que no hace, como lo debería hacer, y si puedes explica secciones de tu código que no estarían del todo claras a simple vista.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

---

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque poner solamente código en tu pregunta dificulta mucho ayudarte.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3402/342) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativamente porque poner solamente código en tu pregunta dificulta mucho ayudarte.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3402/342)`.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

### Te podrían votar negativamente porque sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta

**Recuerda incluir datos de ejemplo de entrada y salida en preguntas sobre sentencias `select` de *SQL***

Entendemos que tu consulta no funciona como esperas. Pero simplemente decir que no funciona de acuerdo a lo que TÚ tienes en mente no hace que automáticamente todos entendamos qué es lo que quieres conseguir.

Si la consulta devuelve un millón de registros, mientras tú esperas 10, o no devuelve ninguno mientras esperas cientos, lo más probable es que haya un error lógico. La sintaxis es correcta, pues el motor la logra interpretar y devolver un resultado. Esto significa que un conocedor experimentado de SQL no le basta con leer el código de tu consulta pues entenderá lo mismo que el servidor. Se necesita una explicación y también datos de ejemplo. Para evitar mandar datos de 20 tablas, intenta producir primero un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable][https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example].

También ocurre que a veces las explicaciones con palabras, si bien son necesarias y de mucha ayuda, pueden tener ambigüedades o imprecisiones que se aclararían de manera automática al ver los datos.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

A veces resulta difícil entender explicaciones en lenguaje coloquial –aunque son mejor que ninguna explicación– pues requieren de gran habilidad para escribirse sin ambigüedad y un mayor conocimiento sobre el dominio del problema de quien lee la pregunta para comprenderla correctamente.

Si tu consulta produce un resultado incompleto, inesperado o ningún resultado, es porque estás cometiendo un error de lógica al escribirla. Te podemos asegurar que al leerla, otra persona que sepa SQL muy probablemente la interpretará de la misma manera que el motor de base de datos.

Lo ideal es incluir, como ejemplo, un pequeño conjunto de datos de entrada y la salida que se desea obtener, junto a una explicación sobre la manera de procesarlos (basta con decir que se quiere el promedio anual de las notas por alumno, por ejemplo).

Una pregunta de buena calidad debiera incluir:

- La menor cantidad de tablas necesarias para producir el resultado, con la cantidad mínima de campos en cada una ([un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
- Un pequeño conjunto de los datos de cada tabla (dos, tres registros por tabla suelen ser suficientes, aunque si son promedios o totales quizás haya que incluir algunos más para que se logre apreciar sin lugar a dudas como deben procesarse los datos)
- Una descripción de lo que quieres lograr.
- Un ejemplo de la salida que desea producirse con los datos de entrada publicados en la pregunta.
- La sentencia que tienes actualmente y que NO produce los resultados.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Cuando solo proporcionas sentencias *SQL*, sin datos de ejemplo, las personas que quieren responder tendrán que adivinar las piezas que faltan en tu pregunta. Eso aumenta las posibilidades de que las respuestas sean incorrectas, lo que es una pérdida de tiempo para todos. Sin la suficiente información para responder una pregunta, los usuarios son más reacios a intentar responderla y están más dispuestos a votar negativamente.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Revisa tu pregunta. ¿Has añadido una explicación completa de lo que quieres lograr? ¿Incluiste datos de ejemplo de las entradas y salidas? ¿Los datos de salida incluidos en el ejemplo se pueden conseguir con los datos de entrada publicados?

Usa el botón de `editar` bajo la pregunta (**no** añadas un comentario) para mejorar la pregunta. Si algún usuario ha hecho preguntas en los comentarios, trata de añadir la respuestas a estas preguntas en la edición de tu pregunta.

**Ejemplo de datos de ejemplo**

Los datos de ejemplo serán unas pocas filas y el resultado que se produce con estas, por ejemplo:

Entrada

```
Codigo  Cantidad
======= ========
1234          10
1234          30
3456          20
1324           5
3456          10
```

Salida esperada

```
Codigo  Pedidos Cantidad
======= ======= ========
1234          3       45
3456          2       30
```

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo (si lo hizo). [Recuerda usar `@usuario` para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83), y con suerte, quizás también esté en capacidad y buena disposición para escribir una respuesta.

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te podrían votar negativamente porque sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794) usando este código: `[Te podrían votar negativamente porque sin datos de ejemplo no se logra comprender bien tu pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3794)`.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

### Te pueden votar negativamente porque estás haciendo varias preguntas en vez de una buscando varias alternativas

**Trata de ser específico y objetivo**

Está bien buscar alternativas a algo que ya tengamos, pero preguntas del tipo "Como hacer X en el lenguaje Y o en el lenguaje Z" o "Como hago X con el framework X o el framework Y" implican falta de investigación.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

No somos un servicio de soporte técnico. Somos una comunidad y como tal buscamos ayudar a la mayor cantidad de personas con problemas específicos.Tanto las personas que buscan ayuda como aquellas que la proveen muchas veces llegan al sitio gracias a los motores de búsqueda, para buscar o dar ayuda con un lenguaje o framework en particular.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Causa pérdida de tiempo tanto a los que están buscando como a los que tienen que responder la pregunta, haciendo más difícil que obtengas una respuesta totalmente satisfactoria.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Convierte tu pregunta en dos preguntas. Pon un [Ejemplo Mínimo Completo y Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) de código en la pregunta. Es muy importante que el código sea el mínimo imprescindible para reproducir nuestro problema, y que esté bien formateado. Esto hace mucho más sencillo responder el problema y proporcionar una solución rápidamente.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar `@usuario` para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te pueden votar negativamente porque estás haciendo varias preguntas en vez de una buscando varias alternativas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4307/342) usando este código: `[Te pueden votar negativamente porque estás haciendo varias preguntas en vez de una buscando varias alternativas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4307/342)`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

### Te he votado negativo porque el Ejemplo que proporcionaste no es fácil de reproducir

Muy bien pusiste un ejemplo, sin embargo no es:

- Verificable (o reproducible) – compilará si es ejecutado, y exhibe el problema descrito, es imprescindible que hasta el más novato pueda reproducir tu problema en cualquier IDE o editor con el código que provees.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Seguramente quieres una respuesta que puedas simplemente copiar y pegar, nosotros que vamos a invertir tiempo también queremos algo que podamos copiar y pegar para reproducir tu problema en menos de 5 minutos. Nuestro tiempo es por lo menos tan importante como el tuyo, muchos miembros de la comunidad no invertirán tiempo en ayudarte si tú mismo no inviertes tiempo en reducir el tiempo que ellos invertirán.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Te recuerdo que no necesitamos ayudarte, quien necesita ayuda eres tú. Tú eres quien tiene un problema y no nos estás pagando por ayudarte, así que no tenemos ningún compromiso ni obligación contigo. Seremos más solidarios si vemos tu esfuerzo en vez de una actitud arrogante tipo: ay tienes un poco de mi código, resuélveme mi problema porque que me urge, deberías de ser capaz de reproducir las otras 100 clases de mi aplicación con esas 4 líneas de código.

Los usuarios expermentados es posible que puedan determinar el problema, pero les tomará más tiempo del necesario hacerlo. O se verán forzados a adivinar las posibles razones hasta dar con la correcta, o se darán por vencidos.

No nos importa que tan urgente o importante sea para tí, sino ayudar a la mayor cantidad de personas a que no pasen por lo mismo.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Crea un [MCVE](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)! Existen varios [tutoriales (en inglés)](http://www.sscce.org/) disponibles, algunos de los cuales son parte de mas extensas guías sobre "Cómo hacer una buena pregunta", como [ésta misma (en inglés)](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)(ver la sección “Sample code and data”). ¡Léelas! Están ahí para ayudarte.

Una vez entiendas correctamente el concepto, vuelve y edita tu pregunta. Si tienes demasiado código, ¡límpialo! Elimina todo lo que no tenga nada que ver con tu pregunta. Por ejemplo, elimina las líneas vacías y los comentarios, si estos nos son relevantes para la pregunta. Si el código contiene HTML markup, elimina los detalles sobre el CSS y el *layout* que no sean parte de la pregunta.

Si no tienes código, crea un ejemplo que reproduzca exactamente lo que tu lógica intenta hacer. Hazlo lo más limpio y claro posible, asegurándote de que reproduce tu error. ¡Puedes llegar a sorprenderte descubriendo tú mismo cuál era tu problema simplemente haciendo esto! Pero si no es el caso, puedes usar ese ejemplo para añadirlo a tu pregunta.

En algunos casos extremos podrías necesitar hacer un código en que se vea el problema que no tenga nada que ver con tu código original, no te aflijas por ello, se trata de la estrategia dividir y conquistar.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar @usuario para que reciba una notificación.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83)

---

*Traducción/adaptación de [I Downvoted Because](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/)*

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativo porque el Ejemplo que proporcionaste no es fácil de reproducir](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4747/342) usando este código: `[Te he votado negativo porque el Ejemplo que proporcionaste no es fácil de reproducir](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4747/342)`.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

### Te pueden votar negativamente porque estás publicando spam

**Trata de ser conciso**

Cuando publiques coloca la información necesaria y solamente eso, un [Ejemplo Mínimo Completo y Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Así que algunos de los siguientes comportamientos no se deben fomentar:

- imagen para llamar la atención
- imagen para no morir ignorado
- poner un Lorem Ipsum
- poner cualquier otro tipo de texto no relacionado con la pregunta
- poner una liga a un sitio aleatorio no relacionado con la pregunta

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Somos una comunidad y como tal buscamos ayudar a la mayor cantidad de personas con problemas específicos. Tanto las personas que buscan ayuda como aquellas que la proveen muchas veces llegan al sitio gracias a los motores de búsqueda, para buscar o dar ayuda con un lenguaje o framework en particular. Por tanto, buscamos ser útiles con el contenido de este sitio.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Primero porque no estamos para satisfacer tus necesidades de atención, segundo porque eso hace que sea más difícil hallar contenido relevante, tercero porque hace más difícil responder.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Quita todas las cosas no relacionadas con tu problema, esto mejorará rápidamente la calidad de tu pregunta.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar `@usuario` para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te pueden votar negativamente porque estás publicando spam](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5253/342) usando este código: `[Te pueden votar negativamente porque estás publicando spam](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5253/342)`.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

### Te pueden votar negativamente porque un enlace hacia tu código no garantiza ayudar a la comunidad

**Una enlace a tu código no nos ayuda**

Cuando realizamos una pregunta sobre un problema con nuestro código, debemos dejar que los usuarios que nos ayudan y que tengan el mismo problema puedan verlo. Con un enlace  del código esto no es garantizable.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

Como alguien que busca ayuda te estás perdiendo parte importante de la funcionalidad que el sitio ofrece para ayudarte, por ejemplo será casi imposible tener buenas preguntas relacionadas o que otros usuarios expertos en la librería o clase con la que neesitas ayuda puedan hallarla aún buscando dentro de este sitio. 
Tanto las personas que buscan ayuda como aquellas que la proveen muchas veces llegan al sitio gracias a los motores de búsqueda, y muchas llegan gracias a una declaración de librería o import, o a un fragmento en concreto de tu código.

También debemos tener en cuenta que los enlaces a sitios de hosting pueden estar bloqueados apra algunas personas por su proxy y/o firewall, ya sea personal o corporativo, o incluso en la escuela donde estudian. Otro problema es que no se puede garantizar que tu enlace viva por siempre.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Cuando los usuarios nos ofrecen su ayuda, gratis y utilizando su tiempo, es importante darles todo lo necesario para poder resolver nuestro problema, pero generalmente basta con un Ejemplo Mínimo completo y verificable. Cuando les ponemos un link al código, estamos malgastando su tiempo y a la larga perjudicamos a la comunidad. Los contenidos de un link hará que otros desarrolladores con el mismo problema tengan mas complicado encontrar nuestra pregunta.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

Edita tu pregunta. Pon un [Ejemplo Mínimo Completo y Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) de código en la pregunta. Es muy importante que el código sea el mínimo imprescindible para reproducir nuestro problema, y que esté bien formateado. Si nuestro código consiste en HTML, CSS y JavaScript, ¡Podemos aprovecharnos de los snippets para hacer que nuestro problema sea reproducible directamente en nuestra pregunta! Esto hace mucho más sencillo ver nuestro problema y proporcionar una solución rápidamente. También puedes consultar [Fiddles: Lista de páginas que podemos usar para probar código y sus características](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2446/83) para ofrecer fragmentos de código con los que los usuarios puedan emular tu entorno de trabajo.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja una comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar `@usuario` para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te he votado negativamente porque un enlace hacia tu código no garantiza ayudar a la comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3883/342) usando este código: `[Te pueden votar negativamente porque un enlace hacia tu código no garantiza ayudar a la comunidad](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3883/342)`.</sub>

Comment: Pregunta: Te refieres a algo como esto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/612681/301324 ??

Comment: Efectivamente, cosas que a la larga crean vulnerabilidades o necesitan retrabajo

Answer (score 1):

### Te pueden votar negativamente porque tu respuesta resuelve un problema pero agrega otro

**Una respuesta que introduce problemas para el yo del mañana no nos ayuda a futuro**

Se agradece tu genuina voluntad de ayudar, pero tu solución podría causar más problemas que ventajas.

**¿Por qué es esto un problema?**

La industria de TI se mueve a velocidades vertiginosas por lo que las soluciones que en algún momento fueron aceptables se pueden volver inviables pronto por muchos motivos como por ejemplo:

- las buenas prácticas pueden cambiar
- estás usando un código que hace 20 años hubiera estado bien pero ahora es muy fácil de atacar
- la tecnología ha avanzado tanto que tu solución creativa ahora es no solo obsoleta, sino impensable.

**¿Por qué esto merece un voto negativo?**

Las personas que buscan ayuda llegan al sitio gracias a los motores de búsqueda, y dar una solución rápida sacada de la manga puede causar que algunos con poco criterio simplemente copien y peguen tu código, si bien es responsabilidad de cada programador cuidar la calidad del código que integran, la manera más efectiva que tenemos de indicar que respuesta es la más adecuada es mediante los votos a favor y en contra.

**¿Qué puedo hacer ahora?**

No te lo tomes personal, el sitio se encarga de poner las respuestas con más votos en la parte superior.

- Edita tu pregunta.

  Especifica en tu criterio experto en que versiones o en qué casos
  podría ser una buena opción usar el código que agregaste.
- Si te dejaron comentarios certeros agrega esa información

  Asume que los comentarios no son para molestarte, si quisieran reputación habrían puesto otra respuesta, que te hayan comentado en tu respuesta significa que te dan una oportunidad de mejorar tu respuesta y con ello obtener reputación en el sitio
- Si te dejaron comentarios con algo que cambiarle

  A veces las personas más expertas no tienen tiempo de darte una explicación elaborada, eso no significa que no intenten ayudarte. Edita y mejora la respuesta usando y ampliando la información con la que intentan contribuirte, podrías aprender muchas cosas nuevas en el proceso
- Si te dijeron que tu código introduce una vulnerabilidad, corrígelo, al final tendrás una mejor respuesta en la que podrás indicar que hacer y que no hacer

Yo entiendo que es muy fácil dejarse llevar y reaccionar con enojo diciendo si eres tan bueno por qué no te haces tú tu propia respuesta, pero la finalidad del sitio no es una lucha de egos, y la finalidad de tener puntos de reputación y votos en las respuestas no es meternos en una competencia individualista, sino de manera natural mostrar indicadores de valor social en la comunidad, es decir, alguien que te indica que tu solución tiene problemas te está dando la oportunidad de mejorar y ser más apreciado en la comunidad. No está tolerado insultarse en la comunidad, así que siempre asume que todos tienen las mejores intenciones y si no lo notas así, reporta los comentarios para que podamos mejorar la convivencia y no echemos a la basura el esfuerzo que tantas personas hemos invertido de manera altruista.

**Deja un comentario**

Una vez hayas hecho esto, deja un comentario a la persona que te mandó este enlace. Probablemente estará encantado de retractarse de su voto negativo. [Recuerda usar `@usuario` para que reciba una notificación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1358/83).

<sub>Compartible con el texto [Te pueden votar negativamente porque tu respuesta resuelve un problema pero agrega otro](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5671/342) usando este código: `[Te pueden votar negativamente porque tu respuesta resuelve un problema pero agrega otro](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5671/342)`.</sub>

Answer (score -3):

## Te he votado negativamente por que no se usar la herramienta de votos de Manera Efectiva.

Muchos nuevos usuarios y otros no tan nuevos tienen una ideología negativa sobre el uso de Votos Negativos y Es correcto a veces cometemos errores en la votaciones... somos humanos y nos equivocamos.

El primer planteamiento del sitio es el [siguiente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) :

> ¿Cuándo debo votar negativo?
> Utiliza tu voto negativo cada vez que encuentres una pregunta o respuesta atrozmente descuidada, poco rigurosa, sin ningún esfuerzo empleado, o que es clara, pero quizás peligrosamente incorrecta.

> ¿Cuáles son las alternativas al voto negativo?
> El privilegio de voto positivo viene primero porque es en lo primero que debes concentrarte: mover el contenido de calidad a la parte superior. El voto negativo debe reservarse para casos extremos. No es un sustituto de la comunicación y la edición.

***Antes de emitir un voto negativo, plantee dejar un comentario sustancial. que ayude al OP y a la comunidad, en caso de que la pregunta pueda ser mejorada o que el usuario requiera orientación***

---

## Situación comúnmente vistas:

***Publicaciones Cerradas Tag de [Duplicada] que reciben votos negativos:***

Esto no tiene sentido, la publicación con 0 votos no sube en la estadística; si alguien la encuentra ira a la publicación con la respuesta ya establecida por la comunidad.
votar negativamente no contribuye en lo mas mínimo, pierde reputación el OP y el que Vota.

**Respuesta:** ignore la publicación cerrada duplicada, y otorgue votos positivos a la original para que suba en las búsquedas.

***Publicaciones Cerradas Tag de [Necesita Mejoras] que reciben votos negativos, sin comentarios:***

Esto no tiene sentido, la publicación que Necesita Mejoras requieren de orientación y comunicación, un comentario aclarando por que una publicación es cerrada es mucho mejor que emitir un voto negativo.
votar negativamente no contribuye en lo mas mínimo, pierde reputación el OP y el que Vota, y crea un ambiente de incertidumbre; si el usuario no encuentra este [post](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo)  o [este otro en ingles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357436/why-isnt-providing-feedback-mandatory-on-downvotes-and-why-are-ideas-suggestin) es probable que el usuario se abstenga de participar en el sitio en un futuro.

**Respuesta:** ignore la publicación cerrada, Oriente al usuario si es posible.

***Publicaciones No Cerradas que requieren Mejoras de redacción que reciben votos negativos, sin comentarios:***

Esto no tiene sentido, la publicación que Necesita Mejoras requieren de orientación y comunicación, un comentario aclarando como mejorar la publicación es mucho mejor que emitir un voto negativo.
votar negativamente no contribuye en lo mas mínimo, pierde reputación el OP y el que Vota, y crea un ambiente de incertidumbre y el OP no sabe que esta haciendo mal.

**Respuesta:** ignore la publicación, Oriente al usuario si es posible ayúdelo con la edición o solicítele datos faltantes.

---

## Notas finales:

Esto aplica para preguntas y respuestas en la mayoría de escenarios. como bien sabemos dar un voto negativo es mucho mas fácil que hacer un comentario y por es nos mal, acostumbramos a emitir votos donde no son necesario o donde no tienen ningún sentido, sea por que la pregunta fue cerrada o que una pregunta con 0 votos no sube en las estadísticas.

Aquellos que desean contribuir efectivamente y positivamente a la comunidad debemos plantearnos que es importante en una sociedad; la comunicación o votos, que dicen no me gusta anónimamente.

Es preferible participar en la Orientación de los usuario, Comentarios, en las colas de Publicaciones y Votos de Cierre o Apertura o en los Votos Positivos a buenas Preguntas y Respuestas.

Comment: Entiendo la situación. Pero no creo que plantearlo aquí sea lo adecuado, y más si la comunidad no está de acuerdo con esas afirmaciones. Podrías hacer una pregunta aparte expresando tu inquietud, pero dudo que reciba apoyo.