# ¿Es justificado el cierre de la pregunta "¿Qué diferencias hay entre library y require?"?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, pregunta-específica

Acabo de hacer y responder la pregunta [¿Que diferencias hay entre library y require?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/119971/que-diferencias-hay-entre-library-y-require/). En cuestión de segundos recibió 3 votos negativos y un negativo en la respuesta, lo cual no me preocupa mucho. El tema es que ya tiene dos reportes de cierre.

La pregunta y respuesta es una elaboración de [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595512/what-is-the-difference-between-require-and-library) del sitio en inglés que me parecía muy interesante traer a SOes. Entiendo que la pregunta podría ser detectada como de baja calidad por su extensión, pero más allá de eso, ¿es justificable su cierre? No veo que entre en ninguno de los motivos.

Comment: Bueno, toma en cuenta que esa pregunta es de 2011. Al día de hoy teniendo tanta documentación en diferentes páginas se podría considerar como un "hazlo por mí" y creo que caería en "*[Te he votado negativamente porque hacer una investigación previa es necesario para realizar una buena pregunta.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2878)*". Si fuera una tecnología que recién salió hace unos días, la documentación es muy escasa y de plano no le encuentras por donde, entonces creo que sí sería algo un tanto más válido. Creo que es una de las lecciones aprendidas durante todos estos años de SE.

Comment: No puedo juzgar esta pregunta en particular, porque no sé nada sobre `R`. Pero en general las preguntas de tipo *¿Cuales son las diferencias entre X y Y* se consideran muy amplias. Aun en el sitio en inglés, actualmente este tipo de preguntas tienden a no ser bien recibidas y son cerradas por esa misma razón.  Pero el sitio en inglés tiene historia y ha cambiado su enfoque con los años. Preguntas que hoy se considerarían muy amplias tal vez tenían el visto bueno en 2011. Si vas al meta en inglés, verás que lo que ellos consideran una pregunta muy amplia es algo que debaten a menudo.

Comment: Solo para terminar, si tu intención era realizar la misma pregunta, poner la respuesta y tener la información en español, igual sería bueno que le pongas una nota al pie que diga algo así como "*Traducción libre de la pregunta en inglés bla bla bla*", con su link a la pregunta original, creo que con eso evitarías los votos negativos y los votos de cierre.

Comment: Lo que no entiendo aquí en SOes.. es que algunas preguntas similares sean bien recibidas y el tuyo por ejemplo no... será ignorancia? favoritismo? np idea... eso me preocupa más porque no hay una linea concreta aquí... y eso lo dije ya hace tiempo...

Comment: @Flxtr, entiendo tu criterio, ahora cuando la pregunta y respuesta es del mismo autor y la investigación esta puesta en la respuesta? Te aclaro que no fue una traducción literal, fue una elaboración sobre la pregunta del sitio en inglés sus múltiples respuestas y la documentación de `R`. Es posible que como dices, si aclaro en la pregunta que se trata de un tema trasladado del sitio en inglés predisponga mejor al que la lee  las juzga.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho estoy de acuerdo contigo, revisé la pregunta en inglés y veo que tu respuesta es un tanto más resumida tomando lo mejor de algunas respuestas, es por eso que en mi comentario anterior te decía que pusieras una nota al pie o al inicio indicando que es una traducción *libre*, donde la pregunta original se mantiene pero la respuesta es más un compilado de las mejores respuestas ;)

Comment: @sstan, no me parece que debiera considerarse amplia, es como si en `C` tuvieras un `fread()` y un `fread2()` que hacen exactamente lo mismo (leen un archivo) y lo que preguntas es que diferencias hay entre usar una rutina u otra. Entiendo que un poco de investigación podría subsanar esta duda, por lo que puedo entender el voto negativo, pero no me cierra el motivo del cierre como el de pregunta amplia, pero bueno, es bueno leer otros puntos de vista.

Comment: @Flxtr, si voy a hacer eso, ya hice algunas traducciones, de preguntas que me parecen interesantes, me idea es seguir haciéndolo, así que aclararé ya desde la pregunta este punto en particular, gracias..

Comment: @aldanux, pienso igual, es preocupante, pero lamentablemente inevitable, es muy difícil pretender que exista una "línea editorial" constante para juzgar todas las preguntas, todo el tiempo. Esta pregunta en meta, no fue para pedir explicaciones, por que no tiene sentido por lo que dije antes, sino más bien para entender que puedo mejorar para evitar casos como éste.

Comment: @Patricio: Lo que dices es cierto. Lo que pasa es que las preguntas que piden diferencias entre 2 cosas a menudo son demasiado amplias. Ejemplo: `¿Cuales son las diferencias entre Java y C#, o MySQL y SQL Server, o Windows y Linux?`  Tal vez por esto algunos se precipitan a concluir que **todas** las preguntas de este tipo deban cerrarse por ser demasiada amplia sin realmente examinar los méritos individuales de la pregunta, o tal vez sin siquiera entenderla.  Por eso mismo, generalmente me abstengo de votar en preguntas de temas que no entiendo. O en las colas de revisión, uso `Omitir`.

Comment: @sstan, gracias, compartimos el mismo criterio de revisión! saludos.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho si piensas realizar traducciones de preguntas ¿no consideras que **sería buena idea definirlas como wiki de comunidad**?

Comment: @Jorgesys, ya he hecho alguna traducción literal y la marque como wiki, en este caso se trato más de una re-elaboración, por eso no la marque cómo tal, pero en realidad tampoco tengo muy claro cuando correspondería hacerlo y cuando no. Me imagino que ya se discutió el tema en meta, así que  buscaré criterios.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## NO

Ni siquiera está justificado en su redacción original donde no habías puesto un enlace a una pregunta en inglés de la que te inspiraste. La frase *"What is the difference between require() and library()?"* no es subsceptible de ser protegida por derechos de autor dado que carece de la mínima creatividad necesaria. Por lo que es posible reproducirla sin citar al autor original.

Tu pregunta no "demuestra trabajo de investigación". Esto no es motivo de cierre. Y siempre es motivo para votar negativo salvo si es una pregunta autorrespondida, como es el caso. Véase como ejemplo [la cuarta pregunta más votada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/36/cu%C3%A1l-es-la-diferencia-entre-un-inner-y-un-outer-join).

Sin duda no es demasiado amplia. Las diferencias entre esas dos funciones se pueden explicar en unos pocos párrafos.

Al menos uno de los votos de cierre es "demasiado amplia", ¿por qué? Tendría que explicarlo quien así ha votado. A mi me da la impresión de que se usa el cierre por demasiado amplio de forma incorrecta contra preguntas que carecen de trabajo de investigación. A esas preguntas hay que votar negativo, salvo las autorrespondidas, pero no cerrarlas.

[Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes):

> Cuándo se podría cerrar mi pregunta?
>
> Las preguntas que no están lo suficientemente relacionadas a la
> temática del sitio, como se explica en la ayuda, deberían ser cerradas
> por votos de usuarios de la comunidad. Los motivos más habituales son:
>
> - Hiciste una pregunta que ya se había realizado previamente
> - Tu pregunta no está relacionada a la temática del sitio

Solo en esos casos se pude cerrar. La mala calidad(1) o la falta de investigación no son motivos de cierre sino de voto negativo.

[Centro de ayuda:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

> ¿Cuándo debería votar para cerrar una pregunta?
>
> Las preguntas deben ser cerradas emitiendo votos de cierre si:
>
> - Son suficientemente similares a preguntas ya existentes y se les respondería de manera idéntica.
> - Son poco claras, demasiado amplias o de algún modo hacen difícil identificar el problema de manera que pueda ser abordada por los
>   contestatarios.
> - No están relacionadas a la temática del sitio, como se describe en el Centro de Ayuda.

Nuevamente la mala calidad no es motivo de cierre. La mala calidad se gestiona con los votos. Los motivos de cierre son: duplicado, fuera de la temática y que se haga difícil responderla(1). Y en tu caso, como en el de jasila, en mi humilde opinión no te mereces ni siquiera los votos negativos.

(1) Si la calidad es tan mala que se hace difícil responderla entonces sí se justifica el cierre. Pero una mala pregunta que no es duplicada, que se puede responder sin más dificultad que la intrínseca al problema y que está dentro de la temática no debe ser cerrada.

Comment: Gracias Jose, muy clara tu respuesta. Coincido plenamente con tu criterio.

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo, podemos debatir si es o no demasiado amplia, siendo este el único motivo posible para el cierre, el cual no comparto. La pregunta es concreta en mi opinión, la respuesta no es ni mucho menos extensa y no creo que se pueda añadir mucho a ella.  Decir que el motivo para cierre o voto negativo  es "no demuestra trabajo de investigación" me parece algo contradictorio en una pregunta autorrespondida... Hay mucha documentación en ingles,pero ¿cuál es el sentido de SOes?.Si la pregunta es adecuada para la temática del sitio y añade documentación en ESP debería ser bienvenida