# Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes... ¿cómo sensibilizar a los usuarios de ese principio?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, respuesta

Considero que aún es alta la cantidad de usuarios (sobre todo al principio), que en vez de incluir el texto del código en sus preguntas, incluyen una imagen.

¿Cómo se les puede sensibilizar para que entiendan que *un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes*?

Yo suelo indicarlo en un comentario... pero no me parece suficiente porque en muchos casos, el OP cambia la imagen por el código al cabo de dos o tres comentarios de varios de nosotros. Y a veces, aunque se lo repitas, no hay forma de que lo cambie.

¿Qué otras medidas creen que se pueden tomar para sensibilizar a los usuarios sobre lo que debería ser, a mi juicio, un principio básico?

¿Algún enlace al cual redireccionarlos, en la ayuda por ejemplo?

¿Poner alguna advertencia en la opción de subir imágenes?

¿Dar alguna medalla por haber cambiado la imagen por el código? (Bueno, esto sería menos razonable).

Comment: Creo de recordar (cuando empecé en SOen) que no se podía subir imágenes hasta una cierta cantidad de reputación... esta sería una buena opción

Comment: Tenemos esta: [Te he votado negativamente porque una captura del código no es de ayuda](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2869/) que es justamente para estos casos...

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo con @aldanux, y de esto se habla en esta discusión en SO: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500/4955425). ¿Hay manera de averiguar si se puede activar esta funcionalidad en SOes? O tal vez ya lo tenemos, y no nos hemos dado cuenta...

Comment: @gbianchi considero que votar negativamente por este motivo es exagerado y contraproducente sobre todo tomando en cuenta que por lo general es gente que acaba de aterrizar en el sitio.

Comment: @A.Cedano no necesariamente tenes que votar negativo. pero ahi esta bien explicado el motivo que puede causar un voto negativo.

Comment: Ojo chicos, que muchas veces, por mas que alguien no tenga suficiente reputacion, las imagenes son necesarias y vienen bien (mi pantalla se ve asi, quiero que se vea asi, y se incluye el codigo)...

Comment: Aún así, @gbianchi, no me parece coherente enlazar a una pregunta que se titula *Te he votado negativamente porque...* en los casos en que no haya votado en contra.

Comment: @A.Cedano eso esta en discusion en otra pregunta en meta. y mas alla de eso, podes cambiarle el titulo a lo que te guste. Pero es la mejor explicacion que tenemos hasta ahora, y lo que viene funcionando ultimamente...

Comment: En el sitio en ingles no puedes mostrar imagenes hasta cierta reputacion minima, eso nos ayuda a evitar esos problemas, pienso que se podria hacer lo mismo, quizas hasta que consiga 10 o 20 puntos, ademas que deberia ser parte del tour.

Comment: Acabo de ver una pregunta de mysql donde la definición de tablas Y la pregunta misma eran una imagen. Esto es relevante y necesita empujar a los usuarios a hacerlo bien. La reputación mínima para incluir imágenes es una necesidad.

Comment: En el chat, hablando con [@terdon](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22222/terdon), él tenia una publicación ideal para este problema en uno de los sitios que modera. Me tome el atrevimiento (con su permiso) de traducirla casi textual. La original es [está](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086)

Comment: No hay usuarios; sólo chicos que pasan, preguntan y nunca más vuelven.

Comment: Deberían de poner esto en el centro de ayuda. Si no, es una opinión y no tendrá impacto en el sitio.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cuando haces preguntas o cuando las contestas, por favor no uses capturas de pantalla del texto. Esto es una mala idea porque:

1. No se puede copiar tu código en las respuestas, o en las búsquedas de Google, o en una solución para comprobarlo o donde sea.
2. No salen en las búsquedas.
3. La publicación es mas pesada (en términos de cantidad de datos) y va a tardar más en cargarse. Esto puede ser problemático cuando uno tiene conexiones lentas.
4. La publicación es inservible para usuarios con navegadores basados en texto o para quienes tienen deshabilitadas las imágenes.
5. La publicación es inservible para personas con problemas visuales y que acceden al sitio con un software de reconocimiento `text-to-speech`.
6. La imagen seguro que se ve bien en tu monitor, pero en cualquier otro monitor diferente (diferentes *DPI*, mayor resolución, viéndolo en una *tablet*, etc.) no se podrá leer letras tan chiquitas (o fuera de foco).
7. Las preguntas con imágenes suelen ser ignoradas.
8. Muchas personas que están detrás de proxys corporativos, no pueden acceder a los sitios de imágenes y no van a poder ayudarte en sus ratos libres.

Aunque a veces hay razones mas que válidas para usar imágenes (discutir un *layout*, mostrar una vista) en la mayoría de los casos no es `útil` y puede causar los problemas descritos.

Además, muchas veces es mas fácil *copiar y pegar* (no implica hacer un archivo de imagen, no implica subir un archivo de imagen). También se puede *copiar y pegar* el texto que ves (que en muchos casos se puede seleccionar y tiene la opción copiar), y se puede aprovechar para dar formato al código como corresponde.

Comment: Yo agregaría el tema del proxy, imgur está bloqueado por muchísimo proxies corporativos. En dicho caso no hay forma de ver siquiera la imágen.

Comment: Buen punto @Emeeus.. lo agrego!

Answer (score 0):

Según mi punto de vista el tema no queda suficientemente esclarecido si se tienen en cuenta los comentarios y la única respuesta que se ha dado a la pregunta.

Primero que todo, por que no se trata de limitar las imágenes en la publicación de preguntas o respuestas, de lo que se trata, es de definir con claridad cuando una imagen puede ser necesaria y cuando puede ser indeseable en la publicación.
No creo que para desarrolladores de software, estos conceptos sean difíciles de interpretar:

- Una imagen es necesaria solo cuando en la publicación se está haciendo referencia a aspectos relacionados con temas visuales, es decir, cómo se dice en la respuesta anterior "(discutir un layout, mostrar una vista)" yo diría mejor en español (discutir un diseño, mostrar una vista).
- Una imagen es inaceptable cuando intentas publicar texto de cualquier tipo (ya sea código, o cualquier otro texto) a partir de una captura de pantalla.

No existe tal controversia, no existe tal contradicción, es simple: Para publicar aspectos visuales, son validas las imágenes. Para publicar texto son inaceptables.

Recomendaría que los desarrolladores del sitio, se esforzaran un poco y rediseñaran un tour, que incluyera una parte interactiva, creo que es necesario explicar a que me refiero ahora.

Me refiero a que como parte del tour, el usuario deba seleccionar checkbox que indiquen que leyó e interpretó lo que ese punto expone.

Por ejemplo, en el punto donde se expone por que no se deben colocar capturas de  imágenes con texto, debe haber un checkbox con el texto "Entendido", que hasta que no sea activado, el usuario nunca, independientemente de su reputación, podrá publicar imágenes.

Seria útil además que cuando un usuario que no ha completado este requisito, intentara publicar una imagen, se le diera solo dos opciones, primero la opción de ir a este formulario para completar el requisito después de haber leído y segundo la de cancelar la publicación; nunca la opción de publicar sin haber cumplido el requisito.

También puede implementarse un grupo de requisitos o condiciones "Sine Qua Non" visibles en el perfil de usuario, que hasta que no se completen, no se tendrá privilegios, como por ejemplo publicar imágenes, si no se ha completado el requisito de leer el texto asociado.

Comment: @gbianchi Me gustaría que vieras y analizaras mi repuesta, no por que crea que soy muy inteligente, solo por que creo que tengo algo que decir sobre este tema.

Comment: es interesante lo que planteas. Dado que planteas soluciones, ideas, creo que iría mejor formular una pregunta nueva con todas ellas. Dicho lo cual, lo de "obligar" a pasar el recorrido, etc, se ha comentado en otras ocasiones y no ha cogido suficiente consenso.

Comment: Me gusta que propongas ideas nuevas y todos estamos de acuerdo a cuándo no va una imagen... pero estoy completamente en desacuerdo con *obligar* a completar un recorrido antes de poder usar el sitio, y sobre todo a un límite en cantidad de imágenes. Hay excelentes publicaciones que tienen más imágenes que código. No me gustaría que exista un impedimento para que sigan apareciendo. La solución que siempre me pareció mejor es poner en pausa a toda pregunta que tenga imágenes en lugar de código.

Comment: @Pollo No, yo no propongo _obligar a completar un recorrido antes de poder usar el sitio_, ni tampoco _un límite en cantidad de imágenes_. Solo propongo, que para publicar la primera imagen, haya que leer y chekar el `checkbox` del punto referente al uso de las imágenes en el recorrido. El nuevo usuario, podría publicar, con texto incluyendo código sin limitaciones, solo al intentar publicar su primera imagen, se le mostraría una advertencia, para continuar, tendría que chekar el `checkbox` con el texto **Entendido**, no me parece que sea poner demasiados requisitos.

Comment: @EduardoReyes puede ser que te haya entendido mal... Pero si para publicar la primera imagen tiene que hacer el [tour], no estaría obligado a algo antes de usarlo (por más que sea exclusivo para imágenes)? Me parece que hay buenas respuestas con muchas imágenes de usuarios que jamás hicieron el recorrido.

Comment: No habia visto esta publicacion antes. Se me paso, tene en cuenta que arrobarme en un comentario no es suficiente para que me llegue una notificacion. Lo que propones es valido, pero tene en cuenta que cualquier cambio de este estilo, es para toda la red, no solo para este sitio. Debe ser propuesto es una pregunta (no en una respuesta) en Meta.se... y alli debe ser valido para todos los sitios.

Comment: Aclaro que arrobarme si no participo de la respuesta, si la respuesta es mia, o si no comento, no sirve de nada arrobar.

Comment: Los usuarios podrían presionar ese checkbox sin haber leido esa seccion. Es lo que algunas personas hacen en los terminos y condiciones (incluyendome)

Comment: Además, yo creo que la respuesta de gbianchi es clara y da muy buenos motivos por los que no publicar imagenes.