# ¿Es adecuado sugerir el cierre de preguntas que poseen imágenes para compartir código?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, imágenes

Recién obtuve el privilegio de votar para el cierre de preguntas que no siguieran con los lineamientos del sitio, encontré una pregunta que utiliza imágenes para compartir el código del OP. Hice lo  usual y le sugerí al usuario (que era nuevo, pero ya había hecho el recorrido) que por favor editara la pregunta cambiando las imágenes por el código por medio de un comentario.

Luego pensé en votar por el cierre de la pregunta por no seguir el formato correcto, sin embargo, no encontré ninguna justificación explicita que justificara el cierre de la misma dentro del menú de *"¿Por qué debería de cerrarse esta pregunta?"*. Entonces me surgió la duda...

**¿Compartir código como imagen es motivo de cierre para una pregunta?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Sí es válido

Entre los motivos de cierre, encontramos lo siguiente

> Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable

**Entonces, cerrar una pregunta por contener código fuente en imágenes es válido**

Porque una imagen no es reproducible ni verificable, algunos usuarios simplemente tienen complicaciones al leer una imagen, por lo que siempre es mejor dejar el código como texto con las herramientas de edición de la parte superior

Comment: Esta me parece la mejor respuesta ya que hace referencia al mismo menú para el voto del cierre de la pregunta y me parece una interpretación muy clara que justifica el cierre de una pregunta. Me parece la más adecuada también porque el link al que hace referencia el *véase* en la página en inglés ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) dice explícitamente que no se incluyan imágenes en las respuestas (creo que sería importante actualizar la traducción).

Comment: Claro que es válido cerrar una pregunta por contener código fuente en imágenes. Lo que se debate aquí es si es condición suficiente para cerrar o no.

Comment: Como ya se dijo mas abajo, la respuesta deberia ser depende, una pregunta simple que se entiende con solo leer y da una imagen del codigo como referencia, no deberia ser cerrado

Comment: @JuanRivera Discrepo. No tomarse ni la molestia en hacer una pregunta correcta y esperar que otra gente se tome la molestia de responderte lo considero de mala educación. Si vienes a pedir ayuda, cíñete a las reglas. Muchas veces en el portátil me resulta ***muy complicado*** leer el texto de las imágenes, y estoy seguro de que no soy el único con ese problema. Además... cuesta menos pegar el código como texto que como imagen :/ Por mi parte, una pregunta con imágenes de código **no** es una pregunta válida.

Comment: @JuanRivera "*una pregunta simple que se entiende con solo leer y da una imagen del codigo como referencia*", da igual lo simple que sea la pregunta si la imagen es ilegible ya sea por resolución o ya sea por padecer acromatopsia o algún grado de daltonismo.

Comment: Por eso puse "imagen del codigo como referencia" asumiendo que no es tan necesario ni obligatorio poner el codigo en una pregunta simple y entendible

Answer (score 7):

Si es motivo de cierre.

Como bien aclara esta [publicación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2990/324), la imagen no sirve como código.

Si tenes dudas sobre el motivo, podría cerrarse como no esta claro lo que se pregunta, ya que la imagen no es algo claro, no se puede copiar, hay que transcribirla y no ayuda para nada a la publicación (en la mayoría de los casos).

Así que si, aclarárselo al usuario es correcto. y reportar el cierre, también.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la pronta respuesta! Creo que sería útil ponerlo explícitamente en los motivos para generar el cierre, yo entiendo que este tipo de preguntas son perjudiciales para el sitio, sin embargo, son comunes y al no encontrar una opción para justificar el cierre me genera dudas de si es un motivo para votar por el cierre de la pregunta.

Comment: Nos encantaria.. pero los motivos de cierre son fijos, no podemos agregar ningun otro sin sacar alguno... y el motivo por imagenes no seria prioritario... @FranAcuna

Comment: Oh, ya entiendo, suponía que iba por ahí el porqué no está la opción. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @gbianchi se podria sugirir implemenar la regla "Todo codigo va como texto"? Igual como lo hay en ingles

Comment: @JuanRivera no se que es esa regla...

Comment: @gbianchi en el sitio de [ingles](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) dice "*DO NOT use images of code*", entonces eso tambien sugeriria implementarlo aca, si esque se considera invalido subir codigo en imagenes

Comment: se podria.. tengo que averiguar como editar esos archivos ahora que perdimos el link directo... tendriamos que ponerlo en una pregunta de meta...

Answer (score 5):

No estoy de acuerdo con [la respuesta de gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5048/83). Por sí solo, que una pregunta contenga el código en una imagen no es condición suficiente para cerrarla.

Si la pregunta está bien formulada, no hay porqué cerrarla.

Lo que sí que hay que hacer es cerrarla si carece de detalles, es demasiado genérica, etc.

Comment: Aceptando que colocar una imagen del código es equivalente a no colocar código, ¿ no considerarías una pregunta **con solo una imagen** como una pregunta **carente de detalles** ?

Comment: @Trauma tu hipótesis abarca más de lo que indica el autor de esta pregunta :P Aquí se pregunta qué hacer si el código está en una imagen. Pero es demasiado genérico, hay [preguntas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/276636/83) [perfectamente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/294628/83) [válidas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/383363/83) sin código. O puede ser que la imagen sea de apenas una línea, en cuyo caso sí que es molesto, pero no es horrible. Mi respuesta va en la línea, pues, de indicar que por sí solo este hecho no debería ser motivo de cierre.

Comment: Ok. Entendí lo que quise entender, *sorry*. Estoy de acuerdo contigo en que mostrar algo de código como imagen, por si solo, no es motivo de cierre. **Siempre y cuando** se cumplan los demás *requisitos*. Tienes razón en que esta pregunta no está demasiado bien planteada. +1

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo, la respuesta debiera ser "depende".  Incluso hay casos extremos dónde hasta sería recomendable colgar una imagen y no un texto, imagino una pregunta acerca de la "iluminación" de sintaxis, por ejemplo.

Comment: Hay personas que no podemos leer lo que pone en algunas imágenes por padecer acromatopsia o algún grado de daltonismo, las personas con ese problema se configuran la pantalla para tener los colores y el contraste necesario para evitar ese problema PERO si se comparte una captura todo eso se pierde. Además, por corto que sea el código es una molestia innecesaria el copiar el código de una imagen para testarlo: quien pregunta tiene que poner las cosas fáciles para ser ayudado, no difíciles.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster como dije en otros comentarios: no discuto que el AP deba poner las cosas fáciles ni que poner código en imágenes sea una cosa no deseable. Lo que digo es que poner código en imágenes no es, para mí, una condición suficiente para cerrar una pregunta. Seguramente en muchos casos deba cerrarse, porque hay una correlación con otros temas: poca explicación, poca claridad, etc. Pero crear el marco mental "código en imagen -> cierre al canto" no creo que sea deseable.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' has dicho en otros comentarios que para ti no es una condición suficiente para cerrar una pregunta, y yo remarco en comentarios que para mi no sólo es condición suficiente para cerrar una pregunta si no que además denota pocas ganas de ayudar a quien estás pidiendo ayuda.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster me parece perfecto, pero no lo comparto.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' me alegro que estemos de acuerdo en cuán en desacuerdo estamos.

Comment: Yo opino que los dos tienen razón! en cierta forma. No es como que se quede cerrada la pregunta de por vida aunque podría pasar, ni que por tener una imagen nos sea imposible a la mayoría responder... yo la verdad lo veo como una oportunidad para los rep wh*r*s de que pasen el código de la imágen a texto y se lleven unos puntos. Y creo que debería cerrarse solo por el motivo de no ser inclusivo (por ejemplo no serviría a alguien con problemas de visión o con su fuente para evitar problemas de dislexia)

Comment: Es irreproducible si uno está desde el móvil, es cegatón, usa algo que le ayude a ver, usa 640x480 porque es albino y no ve bien... la pregunta estará entonces mal formulada y, si el OP no es tan amable de seguir los lineamientos y editarla, debe ser cerrada; no tiene interés en construir la respuesta junto con la comunidad.

Comment: @Alfabravo siguiendo con tu ejemplo, también debería cerrarse cualquier pregunta en la que `la explicación esté en código y por tanto la gente con problemas visuales no vea`, u otras. No creo que sea el caso.

Comment: Sí es el caso porque sigue siendo irreproducible. No se sabe qué es código y qué es enunciado/pregunta y uno no va a modificar el código suponiendo qué es qué. Igual, el OP siempre puede editar su pregunta, incluso cerrada y siempre puede convertirse en una pregunta bien formulada / "respondible". Me parece incluso peor para efectos de conservar nuevos usuarios, el votarla negativamente por ejemplo

Answer (score 2):

La respuesta de [anythingg](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5050/111983) me parece un poco extrema. El cerrar la pregunta solo por tener una imagen en lugar del código no me parece del todo justificado.

Él cita entre los motivos del cierre este motivo:

> Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.

Aunque es cierto que con una imagen no se puede copiar el código y verificarlo, a veces la imagen es el contexto necesario para ver el problema y responder al usuario. Y no me parece justificable cerrar la pregunta solo por que tenga ese código en formato imagen. De hecho, en la cola de revisiones de preguntas de baja calidad, cuando votas el cierre, el botón de cerrar dice claramente:

> Esta pregunta no puede corregirse y debería cerrarse.

Muchas veces la pregunta sí puede corregirse, y no siempre tiene por qué depender del OP el corregir la pregunta. Cuando se nos da el privilegio de votar cerrar preguntas, se nos da también la responsabilidad de corregirlas cuando podemos.

Yo creo, sinceramente, que con bastante asiduidad se vota por cerrar preguntas cuando son corregibles.

Solo por aclarar lo que intento decir: Los argumentos que dan [anythingg](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5050/111983) y [gbianchi](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5048/111983) me parecen argumentos válidos por los que una pregunta puede ser de baja calidad y puede llegar a la cola de cierre y jugarse el cierre. **Pero**, no me parecen razón suficiente para cerrar la pregunta, hay que valorar otros aspectos de la pregunta, sobretodo, como dice el botón, si la pregunta es "corregible". En caso de imágenes, a veces transcribirla hace gran parte del trabajo de corrección. Y creo que en ese caso deberíamos transcribirla nosotros con el botón de "Editar", o dejarle un comentario al OP, u omitir la pregunta y no sugerir el cierre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De nuevo, hay casos incorregibles. Pero tener una imagen no la califica automáticamente como tal.

Comment: Absolutamente de acuerdo con tu argumento. Intenté explicar lo mismo pero creo que lo expresaste de forma más clara: poner imágenes en lugar de código es malo, pero no debería ser condición suficiente para cerrar la pregunta. Puede, pero -como dijo Patricio Moracho por aquí- "depende".

Comment: Tu respuesta presenta argumentos válidos de igual forma, sin embargo, me parece que si es motivo de cierre; si una pregunta es cerrada por no contener un **ejemplo mínimo y verificable**, el OP puede seguir editándola y tras editarla se abre un proceso de reapertura para la pregunta; siempre hay que procurar instruir al usuario haciéndole saber que tiene que poner su código en formato de texto, el problema viene con preguntas que nunca pasaron el código a texto, me parece que ahí sí es motivo de cierre.

Comment: @anythingg haces un salto argumental que no sigo, pasando de lo recomendado a lo obligado. ¿Por qué no es verificable una pregunta que tiene el código en imágenes? Todos estamos de acuerdo en que es incómodo e indeseable, ¿pero tanto como motivo automático de cierre? Llevémoslo al extremo: si la imagen es de un código de apenas una línea, ¿no es verificable? Ese es el núcleo de la discusión en toda esta pregunta.