# Modificar el FAQ en español para incluir la recomendacion: "DO NOT use images of code"

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, imágenes

Esta es una propuesta basada en la pregunta:

- [¿Es adecuado sugerir el cierre de preguntas que poseen imágenes para compartir código?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5047)

**Contexto:**

En el sitio de ingles [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) del apartado [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Hay una regla especifica en la parte de "Complete" que dice:

> DO NOT use images of code. Copy the actual text from your code editor, paste it into the question, then [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). This helps others more easily read and test your code.

Que en español seria:

> NO use imágenes de código. Copie el texto real desde el editor de código, peguelo en la pregunta, y luego formateelo como código. Esto ayudara a que otros pueden fácilmente leer y probar su código.

Esto se incluiria en ese apartado: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Entonces, basados en la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5050/178674) de [anythingg](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/206458/anythingg), vemos que la comunidad dio 10 votos a favor, es por ello que sugiero implementarlo, para que todos los usuarios pongan **codigo como texto y no por imagenes**

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo. De hecho, los textos del Centro de Ayuda son traducciones de la versión en inglés, por lo que si no sale esto es simplemente porque no se ha mantenido actualizado.

Comment: En cuanto a la sugerencia de texto, por un lado para mantener la coherencia deberia ser algo como "NO use**s** imagenes de codigo...". Por otro, hay que tener cuidado y añadir ademas al enlace que apunta a la ayuda del markdown

Comment: yo lo pondria como voceo.. en todo el texto, se tutea a quien lee...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Añado una sugerencia de traducción del texto propuesto:

> NO uses imágenes de código. Copia el texto de tu código,
> pégalo en la pregunta, y después [aplícale formato de código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code). Esto ayuda a
> que todos podamos leer y probar tu código de una forma más sencilla.

Abierto por supuesto a cualquier sugerencia de modificación.

Comment: @JackNavaRow tienes razón que "formatealo" no suena bien. Que tal _y después dale formato de código_?

Comment: @JuanRivera en eso yo no estoy muy de acuerdo. En el original es presente y creo que está mejor asi. Pero a ver que opina mas gente

Comment: @JackNavaRow o quizá mejor aun: _después aplícale formato de código_

Comment: Ya que estamos, podrían mencionarse los Snippets, igual que se hace en la publicación de SO: _Use Stack Snippets to include runnable HTML, JavaScript, or CSS_, que enlaza a [una publicación](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/1983854) que bien podría traducirse.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' cierto. Esa pagina parece que la tenemos bastante desactualizada

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' por cierto, se podría enlazar a [esta pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3292/15301) que es basicamente lo mismo...

Comment: Muy de acuerdo. El tema de las actualizaciones del Centro de ayuda es complicado, pues en el sitio inglés van cambiándolo (como es normal) y desconozco si hay algún tipo de notificación para que las versiones internacionales lo actualicen.

Comment: Sugerencia de texto, que pongo aquí porque cambia bastantes cosas: _NO uses imágenes de código. En lugar de eso, copia el texto de tu código, pégalo en la pregunta y después aplícale formato de código. Esto ayuda a que todos podamos leer y probar tu código de una forma mas sencilla._

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' quizá es mejor que lo pongas en una nueva respuesta, para que se pueda votar

Comment: uy no no, tampoco quiero complicar las cosas

Comment: Yo diría "imagenes *con* código" (en lugar de "de código") y "Copia el texto real *de* tu editor de código" ¿no hay un término mejor para editor de código? Finalmente, "más sencilla" lleva tilde en "más". Me parece buena tu propuesta!

Comment: Aun sigo pensando que deberia ser "Esto ayudará" y no "Esto ayuda", ya que es algo que los usuarios harán

Comment: Pedimos para editar la pagina?

Comment: @gbianchi creo que si, ya tiene suficientes votos, aunque por mi comentario anterior lo sigo pensando...

Comment: @Pikoh entonces se podra implementar?

Comment: @JuanRivera voy a poner la etiqueta para que lo revisen los CM

Comment: @Pikoh ¿no solía hacerse un PR al github de g3rv4?

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' es posible. pero ahora mismo g3rv4 ya no es ni empleado de Stack Exchage, asi que tendrán que decirnos cual es la forma adecuada de gestionarlo

Comment: @Pikoh aaaah vale! Caramba

Comment: @Pikoh  hay que pedirle a Nicolas que ponga el documento para editar...