# La importancia del Ejemplo Mínimo Completo y Verificable

Tags: discusión, preguntas

**Nota** Pido disculpas por la forma en la que transmití las ideas. No la redacté bien. Si ofendí a alguien, no fue la intención.

Muchas veces, me encuentro con usuarios que no suben un Ejemplo mínimo Completo y Verificable. En su lugar, suben capturas, fragmentos o incluso su código entero.

Como usuario de aquí y por los comentarios que he visto de otros usuarios, me da la impresión de que aportar un emcv es importante para poder ayudar a un usuario.

¿Cómo podemos resaltarles a esos usuarios la importancia de un EMCV?

Mi pregunta, a diferencia de [un fragmento de código vale más que mil imagenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%C3%B3digo-vale-m%C3%A1s-que-mil-im%C3%A1genes-c%C3%B3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu) se centra en la importancia del emcv de una manera más amplia (por ejemplo, incluye el no usar fragmentos de código sin importar si están o no en imagenes) y centrada (no habla del uso de imagenes con texto, lo cual no implica necesariamente un emcv). Por lo cual, esta pregunta no es duplicado.

TLDR: La pregunta por la que se está considerando duplicada, no responde del todo a mi pregunta.

Esta NO es una discusión. El problema es que discusión es el tag más cercano de los 5 principales. Si a alguien se le ocurre uno mejor, el aporte es bienvenido.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imágenes... ¿cómo sensibilizar a los usuarios de ese principio?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2990/un-fragmento-de-c%c3%b3digo-vale-m%c3%a1s-que-mil-im%c3%a1genes-c%c3%b3mo-sensibilizar-a-los-usu)

Comment: creo que tu pregunta y respuesta vendria bien agregarla al thret existente sobre fragmento de codigo... con lo cual se contesta **¿Cómo podemos resaltarles a esos usuarios la importancia de un EMCV?**

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Mira la edición

Comment: Por cierto, que es un thret. A que te refieres?  Me pasas link por favor?

Comment: thread, post...

Comment: para mi sigiue siendo lo mismo ... el objetivo es sensibilizar el uso del EMCV

Comment: Ahhh, es que escribiste otra cosa. Además, son publicaciones, no posts. Ya expliqué por que esta pregunta no es duplicada de la que mencionas. Si viste una pregunta más que consideras que habla puntualmente de esto, pasamela y borro esta y pongo mi respuesta allá.

Comment: Es que, no es lo mismo. La que pasaste trata de sensibilizar a los usuarios de no usar imagenes con texto (lo cual no es necesariamente un emcv), la mia trata la importancia del emcv de una manera más centrada y amplia. Si pusiera esa respuesta allá, no encajaría del todo con la tematica de la pregunta.

Comment: sigo sin entender ... es como re-explicar lo que ya esta en la ayuda??? no seria mejor sugerir cambiar algo en la ayuda del sitio???

Comment: No reexpliqué, di profundidad a un aspecto que es poco explicado. El uso del emcv está explicado. Pero lo que no lo está con mucha profundidad es "¿Por que es relevante?" Además, sería mucha info para el centro de ayuda. Tendría que estar como link a una pregunta en meta. Y no veo la necesidad de colocar un link aquí en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: ha entonces es una opinion personal... yo consideraria más efectivo colocarlo en la ayuda aunque sea extenso ... para que quede que fue una desicion de la comunidad establecer o darle valor a los EMCV como indicas ... con una orientacion oficial y no un tema de discucion...

Comment: No hubiera usado ese tag, pero era el tag más cercano. No es discusión, yo plasme lo que aprendí aquí junto con algo de sentido comun.

Comment: Creo que el EMCV es vital para el sitio, la mayoría de las preguntas dependen de ello.  Me gustaría que existiera una publicación aquí en META para enlazar en los comentarios. Y que está publicación tuviera principalmente EJEMPLOS en varios leguajes. Además creo que **JS+HTML+CSS** merecen una especial atención, ya que la herramienta de snippet no es muy usada por usuarios nuevo,

Comment: no estoy de acuerdo entonces... lo ideal es como lo indica yussef; si hay error o falta informacion en el help center ... lo que se debe solicitar es corregir el help center y no crear hilos de discucion en meta que a la larga se pierden o se van no se adonde por culpa del mismo sistema de como funcionan las publicaciones en la red.... sin embargo una publicacion en META explicando con ejemplos y como se dene usar las herramienta de EMCV y que otras son aceptadas como http://sqlfiddle.com/ ... es lo que vendria de perlas a la comunidad.

Comment: para mi lo que no esta en el help center es una opinion personal (lo cabas de confirmar) ... y que 10 personas o 15 voten positivamente esa opinion, sigue sin representar lo mejor para la comunidad ... y cualquier otra persona nueva que llegue al sitio te dira... **"eso no es lo quer dice el help center"**

Comment: si vamos a cortar un problema que se esta dando en la comunidad es mejor cortarlo de raiz.

Comment: 1- Tenés razón en una cosa, y es que se está creando la ilusión de que es solo una opinion. Ya propuse que esto salga en el centro de ayuda. 2- El plan es que se use esta publicación para dejar links en los comentarios, no se va a perder. 3- NO demostré nada, no es opinion, es aprendisaje y sentido comun.

Comment: La publicación que enlasaste en el primer comentario, también es algo que debería estar en el centro de ayuda. Por que a ellos no les dices lo mismo? @ArcanisGK507

Comment: Iba a proponer la unificación de todo, pero el 90% del trabajo lo hace otra publicación (aunque lo hace un poco mal).

Comment: porque esa publicacion quedo en el pasado y no se hizo nada ... esta es nueva... :D

Comment: Nunca es tarde.

Comment: No entiendo quien volvió a votar por que sea duplicada. Por que hice una edición aclarando por que no es duplicada. Recomiendo que lean la pregunta entera antes de votar. Un fragmento de código vale más que mil imagenes no aclara al 100% las dudas presentadas aquí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Nota:** Esta publicación se enfoca en explicar la importancia de un emcv. Si querés saber qué es un emcv y cómo hacerlo, te recomiendo leer [el centro de ayuda](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

**Nota** Esto es lo que yo tengo entendido durante mis 3 años en la comunidad, escribiendo respuestas y usando algo de sentido común. Podría estar equivocado. Pero aun así, me siento seguro de mi experiencia, invito a votar a favor al que esté de acuerdo y en contra al que no. Si algo es incorrecto, invito también a señalarlo en un comentario.

---

El código publicado no tiene por qué ser, ni sirve que sea, el original que causa el error. Para hacer más fácil (o posible) a los usuarios que vean nuestra pregunta hallar la causa del error en nuestro código, está bueno que el código publicado cumpla con ciertos criterios.

### Los criterios

A continuación, enumeraré algunos de los criterios que he aprendido en mi estancia en el sitio y su importancia.

#### Mínimo

Conviene que el código sea lo más corto posible, quitando el código no relacionado con el error. Sin embargo, eso no significa que hubiese que sacrificar los otros dos criterios con tal de que sea mínimo.

Por qué conviene que sea mínimo:

- Si el código no es mínimo, se requiere que los usuarios dispuestos a responder lo revisen y modifiquen quitando dependencias y código no relevantes. Esto hará que los que no tienen tiempo, no puedan responder, y los que sí lo tienen, tarden mucho más en poder darte una respuesta.
- Se vuelve más difícil y pesado localizar el error.
- Los dos puntos anteriores, pueden hacer que algunos usuarios pierdan las ganas de responderte (créeme, yo mismo he perdido las ganas y he visto que otro usuario estubo de acuerdo). Recuerda que esto es un voluntariado, y nadie recibe una paga por responder preguntas, si no que lo hacemos por pasión. Ayúdanos a que nos guste responderte.

#### Completo

Si bien es importante que sea mínimo, no conviene tampoco irnos al otro lado y dar un código incompleto.

Por qué debería ser completo:

- Si el código publicado usa una dependencia y esta no aparece en el código, esto hará que los usuarios tengan que adivinar cuál es esa dependencia: "¿Qué significa `pd.DataFrame`?". Incluso pudiendo hacer imposible responder. Incluso estaría bueno que aclares en la pregunta y/o las etiquetas las dependencias necesarias para reproducir el error.
- Muchas veces, es útil hacer pruebas con el código y ver el error. Sin un código completo nuevamente se necesita dedicar un tiempo a completar las partes faltantes que, tal y como mencioné en el criterio anterior, requiere tiempo y voluntad que no todos tendrían.
- (creditos a [Benito-B](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/188830/benito-b)) Por qué debería ser completo? Porque si yo tengo que rellenar partes de tu código es posible que el error ya no exista, justo porque está en la parte que yo he escrito.

#### Verificable

Y por supuesto, el código de la pregunta debe producir el error mencionado. Esto es lo más importante.

Por qué debería ser verificable:

- Para poder ayudarte, necesitamos ver en primer lugar que error está ocurriendo.
- Si, además de que no es verificable, no es completo, podrían ocurrir errores no relacionados que no permitan ni siquiera ver el error que tenés por nosotros mismos.
- No todos están frente a una computadora con el lenguaje de programación que usas instalado. Si muestras el error, entonces podría que ni siquiera sea necesario ejecutar tu código y, por lo tanto, más gente podrá ayudarte.
- (creditos a [Benito-B](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/188830/benito-b)) El código aportado en un MRE considero que sea obligatorio que sea "ejecutable", es decir, que no provoque fallos de compilación/ejecución por falta de partes. Que pueda pegarlo en mi pc, darle al play y VER EL ERROR.

### Que NO parece buena idea de publicar como código

NO publiques:

- Tu código completo. Pues le falta ser mínimo.
- Un fragmento de código. A eso le falta ser completo. Y podría faltarle ser verificable.
- Una captura/foto de tu código. Además de ser un fragmento de código o un código completo, [existen motivos por lo que esto no es conveniente](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).
  Si el sistema no permite que publiques la pregunta sin usar capturas porque "es mucho código y poco texto", entonces probablemente sea porque no aplicaste/no lograste un equilibrio entre código y explicación. En lugar de hacer spam o usar capturas para evadir la restricción, intenta equilibrar un poco la cantidad de código y explicación. Lo único que lograrás evadiendo la restricción es que tu pregunta no sea bien recibida.
- Una descripción de tu código. Esto nos obliga a transcribir tus palabras (nuevamente requiriendo tiempo y voluntad) y, quizá, nuestra versión del código no tiene el error.

### Por último

Revisa que el código publicado no contenga tokens, contraseñas y otra información sensible. Porque aquí, como en cualquier otro lado de internet, hay gente que puede aprovechar eso para hacerte un mal. Si accidentalmente publicaste datos sensibles, NO solo edites la pregunta, ya que tenemos historial de edición. Regenera o restablece esos datos dentro de lo posible.

Agrego comentario de Padaleiana:

> Para el último caso que mencionás (datos sensibles), hay que reportar
> la pregunta, seleccionar el motivo *se necesita la intervención de un
> moderador* y escribir solicitando que se *redacte* la pregunta (los *mods*
> pueden eliminar info sensible del historial.)

Aunque, en mi opinión, hasta que se hace el reporte y un moderador interviene, lleva su tiempo, así que no viene mal regenerar los datos.

Comment: Para el último caso que mencionás (datos sensibles), hay que reportar la pregunta, seleccionar el motivo _se necesita la intervención de un moderador_ y escribir solicitando que se _redacte_ la pregunta (los mods pueden eliminar info sensible del historial.)

Comment: @padaleiana gracias por el aporte! Lo agregué a la respuesta!

Comment: Hay algo que me intriga acá: ¿a qué te referís con "regenerar los datos"?

Comment: Cambiar contraseñas, regerar tokens, etc

Comment: Ahhhh, ahora sí :D

Comment: Por qué debería ser completo? Porque si yo tengo que rellenar partes de tu código es posible que el error ya no exista, justo porque está en la parte que yo he escrito. El código aportado en un MRE considero que sea obligatorio que sea *"ejecutable"*, es decir, que no provoque fallos de compilación/ejecución por falta de partes. Que pueda pegarlo en mi pc, darle al play y *VER EL ERROR*.

Comment: Gracias por el aporte! Lo agregaré a la respuesta @Benito-B!