# ¿Es posible evitar votos en contra o confusiones en una publicacion?

Tags: discusión

Me explico resulta que me ha sucedido varias veces, y estoy seguro que a muchos también le ha sucedido lo mismo.

Resulta que cuando uno publica una pregunta, luego más tarde hay usuarios que publican comentarios diciendo que no entendieron el problema, cuando según mi percepción si fuera un usuario diferente que mira la misma pregunta (olvidando completamente que fue uno mismo quien la publicó) si leo **bien** la pregunta la logro comprender bien.

Por lo cual pienso que debería de haber alguna manera de evitar que un usuario pueda 'libremente' insertar un voto en contra por no entender la pregunta.

Ya que según mi opinión, lo cual me gustaría que me corrigieran si estoy equivocado, pienso que a muchos les hace falta tener mejor **comprensión lectora** para entender el problema, ya que aun así luego de explicar en comentarios una vez más el tema responden de la misma manera sin entender nada.

En lo personal no me molesta responder varias veces lo mismo, es más, actualizo siempre la publicación para que otros puedan entenderla bien. Pero a veces se vuelve un poco tedioso el tema, es por eso que pienso que falta comprensión lectora, y si estoy equivocado en algo me corrigen por favor.

Por ejemplo en la siguiente publicación que hice hace un tiempo atrás, la leí como un usuario normal olvidando completamente que fui yo mismo quien la publico y entendí el problema, que la persona quien publicaba buscaba que el mensaje que muestra en una vista (Laravel) cuente el numero de resultados obtenidos por una búsqueda.
[Pregunta sobre contar resultados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/229057/como-contar-los-registros-en-laravel-recibidos-por-request)

Comment: Yo he detectado mas problemas a la hora de explicar correctamente las preguntas que "problemas de comprensión lectora". Podrías poner algun ejemplo? De todas maneras, contestando a tu pregunta, no. Los votos son libres y cada usuario puede votar negativo por sus propias razones.

Comment: Está claro que hay gente que puede no entender. Está bien eso que dices que la editas varias veces para aclararlo. Pero es imposible evitar los votos negativos.

Comment: @Pikoh. Añadí un ejemplo para que se pueda comprender mejor.

Comment: Personalmente, no controlo la tecnología en la que se basa la pregunta que pones como ejemplo, asi que no puedo juzgar si está o no bien explicada. Pero debes tener en cuenta que tu sabes lo que necesitas, otros usuarios no. Aunque a ti te parezca que está correctamente explicada, si otros usuarios te dicen lo contrario, lo mejor es analizar y tratar de explicarse mejor. En cuanto al voto negativo, asumes que corresponde al comentario que te indica que no es una buena pregunta, cuando en realidad ha podido ser por cualquier otra razón.

Comment: Resumiendo: no os toméis nunca como un ataque personal cualquier voto negativo que recibáis. Se vota negativo a un post, no a una persona, y este voto es totalmente subjetivo. Lo que a un usuario le puede parecer una buena pregunta (y votarla o no positivamente), a otro le puede parecer lo contrario (y votar o no negativamente).

Comment: Comprendo, pero nunca me lo tomaba personal es solo que en varios casos sucede que no se sabe la razón del voto en contra, aunque ciertamente se asume que es por que no está explicada bien la pregunta, quizás debería por ultimo al dar el voto pedir la razón de por qué.

Comment: La razón de un voto en contra no se sabe nunca, a no ser que el que votó explícitamente quiera explicar la razón (ver https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/15301). En este caso concreto, veo que @shaz (el usuario con mas reputación en el sitio ayudando con preguntas de laravel) no comprende correctamente tu pregunta, como en algun caso anterior de preguntas tuyas. Como consejo personal, yo trataría de hacerle caso, ya que como digo si él no lo comprende, es difícil que nadie mas lo haga :)

Comment: la pregunta parece algo rebuscada, recuerda que la comprensión como tu mismo la mencionas debe ser un proceso simple a través de tu pregunta, Shaz es un usuario bastante activo y crítico de los aportes en Laravel(lo cual veo excelente), a mi criterio lo que veo mal es que das mucho mucho texto, demasiado código y muy poco o nada del error que se te presenta, hubiera sido distinto y no solo para el sino para mi también que indiques: ¿qué deseas obtener? ¿cómo lo estás intentando? (esto incluye el código y su explicación) y al final el error mostrado

Comment: Me pregunto como es posible leer tu propia pregunta como si fuese de otro. Está claro que tú vas a entender tu propia pregunta ya que la has hecho tú, escribiéndola con tu propia forma de expresarte y tus propios conocimientos. Aunque creas que puedes abstraerte totalmente y verla como los demás es prácticamente imposible, además cada persona tiene su propia percepción de las cosas, ¿cómo pretendes establecer el criterio correcto para interpretar un texto y basar en él quien puede votar o no? ¿y como podría resolverse eso técnicamente? No veo que esta propuesta tenga ningún sentido

Comment: Ya dí mi explicación del voto negativo en la respectiva pregunta, y sí, en mi opinión está muy mal planteada la pregunta y resulta muy confusa al leerla e intentar entender: 1. Lo que pretende hacer según la descripción y según el código. 2. El resultado actual. 3. Las palabras que emplea en algunas ocasiones (principalmente en preguntas anteriores). No es la primera vez que voto negativo a este usuario y he dejado algún mensaje en donde lo he hecho, con el fin que mejore sus publicaciones.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crear una buena pregunta a veces puede ser más complicado de lo que aparenta, tiene que ser breve pero explicativa y aunar ambas cosas es cuestión de práctica y saber centrarse en lo relevante.

La idea detrás del [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) es precisamente intentar ser preciso pero breve, intentando evitar ideas superfluas.

En tu pregunta das todo tipo de detalles (uso tal controlador, uso tal framework, se ve así en pantalla...) que (creo, mi conocimiento de PHP es nulo) son superfluos y ocupan la mayor parte de la pregunta.

La pregunta se podría resumir en: *Hago una consulta a base de datos y cuando quiero saber el número de resultados siempre me da 1, éste es mi código: ...*

Comment: Si comprendo pero la razón de lo extensa que pueden ser mis preguntas, es pensando de que manera la otra persona la puede entender mejor.

Comment: lo extenso es riesgoso, pues debes mantener una redacción clara y simple por que al menos en tu última pregunta, eres un tanto confuso y por eso es difícil entender tanto texto y código @M4uriXD