# ¿Por qué mi pregunta sobre CSS ha recibido tanto voto negativo?

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica, votos-negativos

Recientemente publiqué esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/263079/mejor-css-para-imagenes/) y al parecer hay varia gente que no le acaba de gustar. ¿Mal redactada? ¿Muy amplia?

Se que existe la publicación [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo) pero para mí no "cumple ninguna".

¿Alguna explicación?

Comment: En preguntas de CSS siempre va bien intentar insertar un ejemplo, un código que se pueda ejecutar, así como alguna imagen de cómo querrías que quedara.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No he sido yo el de los votos negativos, y no puedo hablar por la gente que haya votado porque no sé sus motivos, pero vi un par de cosas:

- **Alguna gente podría considerarla como basada en opiniones**: el título (antes de la edición que hice cuando ya tenía -2) invitaba a pensar que la pregunta era basada en opiniones ("*¿cuál es el mejor...?*") cuando realmente no lo era (o al menos a mí no me lo parece, pero yo soy yo).
- **Alguna gente podría considerar que le falta información clave**: añades el código de la etiqueta, pero no pones los estilos cuando la pregunta es sobre estilos en sí. Muchas veces, este tipo de preguntas acaban resueltas por el propio usuario con un "se me olvidó decir que también uso la librería XYZ que afectaba a los estilos y ese era el fallo".

Comment: Vi tu maravillosa edición. Muchas gracias por la aclaración. Intentaré mejorar para próximas preguntas. Un saludo.