# ¿Sería posible añadir al artículo "¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?" indicaciones sobre no añadir imágenes con errores, sino texto?

Tags: discusión, centro-de-ayuda

Hoy un usuario con cierta antigüedad (11 meses) hizo una pregunta. En un despiste, se *olvidó* de colocar el mensaje de error relacionado. Rápidamente la comunidad (negativos mediante) le *sugirió* que cabía la posibilidad de que dicho mensaje fuera importante ... y el usuario incrustó **una imagen** :-O

Un deseo incontrolable de votar negativo, votar para cerrar, y excomulgar al individuo en cuestión se apoderó de mi ... pero pude contenerme. Entré al centro de ayuda para copiar la URL e incrustarla en un comentario agradable y conforme a nuestro código de conducta ... y me di cuenta que, en la página

> #### [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

¡¿**No hay ninguna indicación** sobre el tema de las imágenes?! Con lo poco convenientes que resultan si lo que quieres es recibir una respuesta, amén de sus otras *cualidades*: no se pueden copiar/pegar, dificultan la lectura desde dispositivos con pantallas pequeñas, y la combinación de colores por defecto de muchos editores es bastante cuestionable.

¿ Sería posible editar la página y colocar una o varias indicaciones al respecto ?

Comment: Creo que es una buena idea. Si alguien se ofrece voluntario a escribir algún texto, podemos votarlo/pulirlo en las respuestas.

Comment: `Un deseo incontrolable de votar negativo, votar para cerrar, y excomulgar al individuo en cuestión se apoderó de mi ... pero pude contenerme` xD!!!!!!!!!!!! Top Comment.

Comment: Ya que lo has puesto, he entrado en ¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta? y me he encontrado esta frase: Pero si tu problema está en el código que **haz** escrito... ¿Estas faltas de ortografía en las ayudas dónde se avisan?

Comment: "*No se pueden copiar/pegar, dificultan la lectura desde dispositivos con pantallas pequeñas, y la combinación de colores por defecto de muchos editores es bastante cuestionable*" y añado que algunas personas con problemas de visión configuran los colores de su editor de texto para facilitar la lectura de código, es un esfuerzo que se va al garete en cuanto alguien pone una captura de pantalla de su IDE en lugar de poner su código.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

El artículo del Centro de ayuda de Stack Overflow en inglés [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ya lo tiene:

> - **DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Por tanto, simplemente sería cuestión de traducir este texto a algo así como:

> - **NO pongas imágenes con código, datos, mensajes de error, etc.** - copia o escribe el texto en la pregunta en sí. Utiliza imágenes solamente para diagramas o para mostrar bugs en acción, es decir, cosas que son imposibles de describir de forma precisa con texto.

... e incluirlo a través de una pull request en el [repositorio de textos del Centro de ayuda](https://github.com/g3rv4/help-pages), tal y como se documenta en [¿Cómo puedo sugerir un arreglo a una traducción en el centro de ayuda?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4466/83).

Comment: A ver si pillo un *huequecito* y me pongo con ello.

Comment: uy, veo que sigue sin estar

Answer (score 71):

Dato importante: Algunas preguntas donde comento que lean estas recomendaciones tienen potencial de mejora, no necesariamente cumplen lo descrito en la siguiente imagen, esta imagen representa parte de las preguntas mal estructuradas. ¿Las mejoramos por favor? Todos salimos ganando, quienes preguntan y quienes tendrán un escenario similar en algún futuro o cuando en algún futuro toque hacer mantenimiento de legacy code :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tomando la libertad del comentario del buen [@AlvaroMontoro](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/modificaci%C3%B3n-de-la-p%C3%A1gina-c%C3%B3mo-elaboro-una-buena-pregunta/4433?noredirect=1#comment18307_4432), una **buena pregunta** contiene los **siguientes ingredientes**:

1. **Bajo ningún motivo suena a ticket para el área de desarrollo**. Me he topado con una buena cantidad de preguntas del tipo: "Quiero hacer...", "necesito que...", "la idea es...", "tengo que...", "que debe tener...", "se espera que el usuario...", "que el sistema me permita...", "que se comunica con servicios externos...", "es urgente", si la pregunta contiene algo así, desde ya está basada en opiniones y/o demasiado amplia o simplemente irreproducible porque carece de código, intentos de solución y falta de investigación.
2. **Tiene código completo en texto (sin pantallazos del código)**. No simplemente un fragmento que depende de algo que está ausente en la pregunta, sino que, cualquier usuario puede hacer uso del código y tendrá el mismo error, esto es parte de "código mínimo verificable".
3. **Demuestra investigación**. Al margen del código en el que se ha estancado el usuario, se nota que ha investigado sobre librerías, intentó distintas formas de hacerlo funcionar sin éxito hasta el momento.
4. **Explica los pasos que realizó para que el error salte**. Como: "ingresé estos valores ABC y se generó un error en el módulo XYZ, sigo sin entender cómo funciona si ingreso los valores ABC1 y el módulo XYZ reporta correctamente".
5. **Muestra el mensaje del error en texto y en alguna imagen (opcional)**. Esto nos facilita hacer una búsqueda por la red sobre dicho mensaje en caso se desconozca.
6. **Está bien redactada, es decir, tanto en gramática como en ortografía**. Aunque suene utópico, hay una enorme diferencia entre decir "Vamos a comer niños" vs "Vamos a comer, niños", *canibalismo detected*. De la misma manera, consideren que escribir en mayúsculas equivale a gritar. Venga, que no en vano pasamos alrededor de 11 años en educación obligatoria, ¿o sí?. Todos podemos mejorar de algún modo.
7. **Siempre se percibe un mensaje amable, educado**. Hay usuarios que redactan con tanta buena onda que así uno desconozca la tecnología, nacen las ganas de ayudarlos.

**Actualización Marzo 31, 2021**

Hubo una conferencia en Madrid (OS Weekends!) donde tuve el privilegio de ser invitado y tener la oportunidad de mostrar el tema de "Curiosidades que pasan en la moderación de StackOverflow", les recomiendo ver el contenido: https://youtu.be/-IWbhU4csp8?t=660 les dará un mejor panorama de la situación en StackOverflow en Español, también les ayudará a entrenar su sentido de detective al momento de analizar bugs y dar con alguna pista que los lleve a la respuesta :D

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización Abril 14, 2021:**

Dato importante incluido antes del meme de arriba.

**Actualización Mayo 16, 2021:**

Si eres usuario nuevo, te doy la bienvenida a SOes :D
Revisa este enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour Te permitirá entender un poco más sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtendrás tu primera medalla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Actualización Julio 02, 2021:**

Si tu pregunta está recibiendo votos negativos, revisa este enlace [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2868/822) en todas las respuestas, hay puntos a tener en cuenta.

**Actualización Noviembre 15, 2021:**

Disculpa si te ha incomodado ver el meme y/o leer las recomendaciones, la intención con la que las redacté fue en buen plan con el fin de colaborar a que aumente la calidad de preguntas en el sitio. Quienes me conocen, saben que lo digo de corazón, y quienes no me conocen, podrían pensar cosas ajenas a la esencia de esta respuesta, así que mejor esta actualización para que todo quede claro. :D

**Actualización Noviembre 30, 2021:**

Incluida la imagen de la conferencia de la Open Source Weekend! y de la misma manera, se agregó la imagen del tour, si eres usuario nuevo, el tour te da la primera medalla :D

Comment: +1 ... y si pudiera, +1 extra por lo de la redacción y faltas de ortografía. Se ve alguna cosa ... ¡ Si los navegadores tienen corrector ortográfico ! ¡ Solo hay que revisar las palabras que están marcadas en rojo ! O_O

Comment: Lo bueno es que gracias a esa mala costumbre de redacción, ya pasé las 1000 ediciones :D

Comment: `+1` Excelente artículo. Lo considero una lectura recomendada.

Comment: el problema de los memes, es que suelen usarcé para burlarse de algo ...

Comment: Por eso mismo, la aclaración en 2 ocasiones en todo el texto, saludos estimado :)

Comment: Quiero manifestar mi oposición al uso que se está haciendo de esta publicación. La idea de Stack Overflow es construir conocimiento entre todos y eso incluye los documentos de ayuda. Es fácil sugerir modificaciones en el Centro de Ayuda, de la misma manera que se han creado banners específicos para ayudadr a los usuarios. Creo que sería mucho más útil sugerir cambios en el Centro de Ayuda que ir enlazando esta respuesta.

Comment: Esta publicación está en un lugar no estándar y es una contribución no oficial. En cuanto al contenido, está plagado de las cosas que hacen que una publicación no sea buena: actualizaciones constantes, enlaces (¡a vídeos de dos horas!) sin indicar la parte representativa, además de utilizar un meme que a mi parecer es ridiculizador. La parte inicial es útil, pero por el bien del sitio creo que sería mejor moverlo a un lugar más oficial.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Coincido contigo, ¿cómo le podemos hacer para moverlo al centro de ayuda? Por otro lado, del video de 2 horas, en realidad, la parte donde expongo sobre las cosas curiosas que pasan en la moderación dura 22 minutos aproximadamente; lo del meme, últimamente, siento que está jugando en contra, por ello tuve que mencionar en su tiempo lo inicial y luego agregar al final nuevamente la intención de tal imagen, en su momento fue gracioso, nunca hubo mala intención.

Comment: Entiendo la buena fe de la publicación y que seguro que ha ayudado a muchos. Yo creo que se podría mover buena parte a la publicación https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask que es la que se detalla al usar el magic link `[ask]` --> [ask]. De hecho, es lo que se preguntaba en esta pregunta jaja

Comment: Me gusta la respuesta y el meme, pero creo que si fuera alguien que fue redirigido a esta respuesta, no supiera nada del sitio, y lo primero que viera fuera el meme, me sentiría mal. No digo sacarlo, pero ponerlo más al final para que no sea la primera impresión que de esta respuesta.

Comment: Para lo de "está bien redactada", quiero recalcar que, IMHO, lo más importante es que se usen puntos y comas. Sin estos dos simbolitos, además de diferencias como la de comer niños, el texto se lee decorrido  y, por lo tanto, se vuelve más dificil entender el texto en cuestión.