# Cuando se consideran subjetivamente buenas o malas las preguntas

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos-negativos

Tomando en cuenta que existen diferencias sobre qué es lo que se considera buena o mala pregunta en **Stack Overflow**, me las he encontrado con votos negativos, positivos o simplemente no los tienen. Otras que se encuentran cerradas, pero que no deberían.

En este caso, voy a presentar dos (02) ejemplos concretos sobre una **pregunta cerrada** y otra con **votos negativos** para ilustrar un poco el escenario.

**Ejemplo 1:**

[image: No relacionado]

En la *vista previa* anterior se pudo observar [que la pregunta tuvo cuatro (04) votos negativos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327716/formar-un-triangulo-de-n%c3%bameros-pares-c/327752) y fue cerrada por considerarse [***Tema no relacionado***](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

**Cito el texto de la pregunta cerrada:**

> Es decir que si yo ingreso que la cantidad de filas del triangulo sean 5 se imprimira asi
>
> ```cpp
> 2
> 4 6 
> 8 10 12
> 14 16 18 20
> 22 24 26 28 30
> ```

En la cita anterior el usuario planteó [*un problema específico de programación*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Es decir, cómo formar un triángulo de pares numéricos en **C++** a partir de un número de filas introducidos.

**Tenemos su contraparte similar en Inglés (en el sentido de que no hay código):**

[image: imagen-pregunta-ingles-1]

Se pudo observar que tiene **2474 votos** y además es una *Wiki* de la comunidad. En ella se plantea sobre los números de versiones correctos de **C#**. [Pueden visitarla y revisarla.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247621/what-are-the-correct-version-numbers-for-c?rq=1)

**Ejemplo 2:**

[image]

[Dicho planteamiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/328511/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-mostrar-im%c3%a1genes-diferentes-pero-responsivas-para-todos-los-disposit) cuenta con dos (02) votos negativos y uno positivo (el mío).

En este caso, se desconocen las razones por la que se emitieron los votos negativos si la pregunta hace un planteamiento claro.

#### Estas son mis interrogantes

- En el ***Ejemplo 1*** de la publicación expuesta acá, con sus vistas previas y enlaces disponibles ¿Por qué se determinó que era un *tema no relacionado*?
- **En el segundo ejemplo**, ¿por qué se votó negativo si la pregunta es clara sobre la duda que plantea y además tiene una respuesta clara?
- **Y lo más importante,** ¿existe alguna posibilidad de implementar algún tipo de mecanismo que evite que se esté calificando a la ligera las publicaciones?

Sobretodo, si muchas de esas preguntas han obtenido respuestas que han sido concretas para las dudas que ellas plantean.

---

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/modificaci%c3%b3n-de-la-p%c3%a1gina-c%c3%b3mo-elaboro-una-buena-pregunta/4433#4433

Comment: En mi opinión, la primera pregunta debería de estar cerrada pero quizás el motivo de cierre no sea el correcto, no ha mostrado lo que ha intentando ni su código, es decir que le has hecho los deberes! Y respecto a la segunda pregunta planteada de SOes (la del snippet) puedes ver [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo). Hay muchos casos en los que la gente puede votar negativo, pero si de algo estoy seguro es que muchas veces se vota positivamente a preguntas que no lo merecen y viceversa

Comment: Lo recomendable es no responder hasta que el autor ponga su código y errores. De todos modos tu respuesta me pareció bastante completa y le voté positivo. Sin embargo me pareció bien haberla votado para cerrarla ya que el autor no aportó mucho, solo explicó un poco el enunciado. En la segunda pregunta no emití el voto aún, pero veo que se emitió un voto negativo antes de que yo la haya editado. El código se veía un espanto con líneas vacías por todos lados.

Comment: Haciendo click en el ícono de tiempo abajo del voto negativo y luego en **Mostrar resumen de votos**, se puede ver el sumario de votos de la pregunta, en este caso pondré el enlace del sumario de la segunda pregunta:  https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/328511/timeline?filter=WithVoteSummaries

Comment: Gracias @ArtEze y x3kagainstSEbehaviorpor la observación. De vez en cuando es bueno realizar estas reflexiones para mejorar la precisión de las votaciones.

Comment: Comento lo mismo que en la respuesta del triángulo. Me llamó la atención que a los números de dos cifras le agregas un cero a la izquierda. Al dos le dices 02, al tres, 03, tanto en tu respuesta del triángulo como aquí en meta... Pensé que esto venía de antes, me puse a mirar tus respuestas, y vi [una respuesta tuya hecha el 5 de enero](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/319815/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-escribir-un-car%c3%a1cter-m%c3%baltiples-veces-con-bash-y-dibujar-un-cuadrado/319842#319842), en donde comienza diciendo _Crearemos tres (03) funciones..._. Normalmente decimos 2 o 3, sin el cero.

Comment: Me pregunto si sería correcto dejarle el enlace de esta pregunta de _Meta_ en su pregunta para que el usuario sepa que estamos hablando de su pregunta, o si de lo contrario sería demasiado recursivo e innecesario.

Comment: @ArtEze, buena observación.

Comment: Hola David, se agradecen tus contribuciones al sitio, pero en varias ocasiones se ha hablado sobre este tema, te sugiero no comparar lo que se realizo en SO en inglès, revisa lo que dicta el [help], especìficamente [ask]. Regularmente este tipo de preguntas que no se realizan de acuerdo a [ask], provocan respuestas de baja calidad como https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/327742/95 saludos.

Comment: Hola David, sobre tu 2da pregunta de ejemplo, yo fui uno de los usuarios que la votó negativo y dejé un comentario al OP. Luego tú me comentaste compartiendo un enlace con el que caí en cuenta de que la pregunta era válida, motivo por el cual quité mi voto negativo y voté positivamente. Te agradezco por eso.

Comment: Hola @JheymanMejia. Me dejaste pensativo con lo que me escribiste. He aprendido algo nuevo con esta reflexión. Gracias Jheyman.

Comment: Y para los otros que me han escrito, me han dejado pensativo. Siempre se aprende cosas nuevas acá.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En el primer ejemplo que pones, con el último cambio que se ha hecho en el sistema de notificaciones de causas de cierre en el UI de StackExchange, dependiendo de tu reputación puedes ver más o menos información sobre la causa del cierre. En tu caso, solo ves que la causa es *Tema no relacionado*, pero dentro de esa categoría hay varias subcausas. En este caso, es la siguiente:

> Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.

Como puedes ver, dado que la pregunta no muestra ningún esfuerzo realizado para su resolución, esta causa parece mas que justificada para el cierre de la pregunta.

En muchas ocasiones se hacen comparaciones con StackOverflow, pero normalmente hay algo que no tenéis en cuenta: Cuando se hizo la pregunta.

El ejemplo que enlazas es una pregunta de nada menos 2008 (curiosamente hecha por Jon Skeet). En los primeros tiempos de StackOverflow, las normas eran más relajadas (incluso no existían) sobre que se podía preguntar y que no. Pero puedo asegurarte que una pregunta similar hoy en día acabaría cerrada en segundos (y creo que no exagero).

---

En cuanto al segundo ejemplo..sólo podemos especular. Los votos son secretos, y la razón para ellos solo la conoce el usuario que vota. Puede ser que se haya votado negativo porque cuando la pregunta se hizo estaba muy mal formateada (luego Arteze arregló eso). Puede que algún usuario considere que la pregunta no contiene toda la información necesaria para ser respondida...o simplemente puede que algún usuario tenía un mal día y quiso votar negativo.

Yo te recomiendo a ti y a todos los demás usuarios no preocuparse por los votos negativos. Si la publicación que has hecho es suficientemente buena, esos negativos es muy posible que queden revertidos con los positivos de otros usuarios. Y tratar de entender porque alguien vota negativo es simplemente especular a menos que dicho usuario comente el por que de su voto.

Comment: Sí, la segunda pregunta si recuerdo bien se había reportado como baja calidad, entonces desde la cola de revisiones la vi, se veía un poco mal y la corregí un poco, no recuerdo si la edité desde la cola de revisiones o por fuera.

Comment: Hola @Pikoh. Estuve leyendo las observaciones hechas en esta respuesta y me parece bien que cada quien escriba su punto de vista para mejorar la precisión de estas observaciones. De hecho, el planteamiento de la pregunta es una reflexión que busca incentivar el debate para que cada quien exponga su punto de vista, dado que el objetivo es aprender de ello.

Comment: Esperaré 48 horas para esperar más respuestas y observaciones antes de aceptar una respuesta. Conocer puntos de vistas y sugerencias de los que participamos acá. Es muy buena observación esta respuesta.

Comment: Añado después de un año, que la primera pregunta fue cerrada justificadamente, de hecho yo soy el autor de la primera pregunta, y acabo de caer en cuenta de esto, fue interesante darme cuenta de esto, supongo que el problema se origina de una mala percepción externa que se cree que SO esta destinado a resolver sus problemas, en mi caso si tenia código avanzado pero no creí que era necesario mi poco avance no funcional del código, por suerte hacer el recorrido de como preguntar me ha reformado, diciéndolo de forma graciosa, pero aun siento que falta connotar mas la importancia de como preguntar

Comment: Aún se ven preguntar muy mal formuladas, donde  incluso a veces se muestran como si fuera un obligación hacer el código que piden, el sistema guía, debería ser mas estricto para la primera que un usuario va a publicar