# ¡La nueva página para formular preguntas ha sido activada!

Tags: discusión, preguntas, anuncios

¡Hurra! La nueva página para formular preguntas ha sido activada para todos los usuarios de Stack Overflow en español.

[image]

> **TL;DR;**
>
> La nueva página para formular preguntas ha sido creada para ayudar a la gente a navegar el sitio y rápidamente guía a la persona en cómo mejorar su pregunta. Esta nueva página es una combinación de el Asistente de preguntas y la página Formular una pregunta.
>
> [Más sobre este proyecto se encuentra en el blog.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/09/26/research-update-improving-the-question-asking-experience/)

Por favor únanse conmigo para darles las gracias al equipo de desarrolladores y al increíble traductor [@Pikoh](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15301/pikoh) sin el cual no tendríamos esta página.

Estaremos felices de escuchar sus comentarios y feedback en las respuestas a esta pregunta. =)

Comment: Excelente!, esto será de ayuda para usuarios que en ocasiones desconocen el documento [ask] :-). Que bueno que se muestran los puntos que son imprescindibles: **2. Describe lo que has intentado y 3, Cuando sea apropiado, muestra algo de código.**. Es bueno que los usuarios sepan porque razón se realizan estas sugerencias : "**La comunidad está aquí para ayudarte** con problemas específicos de programación, algoritmos, o lenguaje".

Comment: ¡Excelente! Ahora, roguemos que sea innecesario estar enlazando: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 a cada pregunta mal redactada :')

Comment: Genial!!! Me agrada bastante la interfaz. Espero que los textos logren llamar la suficiente atención de nuevos usuarios y dejen de agregar adivinanzas o, en el mejor de los casos, poner pantallazos de código y ahí verá c/u qué entiende ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Excelente noticia. Espero que esto ayude a mejorar la calidad de las preguntas especialmente de los nuevos usuarios. Os pido a todos que si detectáis algún texto no traducido o cuya traducción pueda mejorarse lo notifiquéis aquí o directamente hagáis una sugerencia en [traducir.win](https://es.traducir.win/)

Comment: Esto funciona en el sitio principal pero no en Meta. Aquí sigue estando el formato antiguo. https://i.stack.imgur.com/7G5yc.png

Comment: @Pikoh estaba buscando lo de _Hurrah_ en traducir.win, para sustituirlo por _hurra_, pero no aparece. ¿Sabes si es modificable? ¡Gracias por el curro!

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' hurrah? donde sale eso?

Comment: @Pikoh en SOes, cuando aprietas en "NUEVO" https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SENl.png

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' supongo que eso no está en transifex. Se trata de un mensaje de aviso que muy posiblemente haya metido de forma manual Juan y que desaparecerá en un tiempo...tal vez g3rv4 nos lo pueda aclarar, pero tampoco le daría mucha importancia ya que acabará por desaparecer

Comment: Ha pasado 1 día y voy mandando a cerrar más de 5 preguntas por estar basada en opiniones T.T Sigo publicando el enlace de "Lectura obligatoria" https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 1):

Veo que se pueden hacer algunas correcciones en la gramática.

1. Antes:

   > Enseña lo que has intentado y dinos **que** has encontrado

   Luego:

   > Enseña lo que has intentado y dinos **qué** has encontrado
2. Al punto 3 le pondría un **punto al final** ya que en el punto 2 lo tiene. Antes:

   > problema (también llamado un ejemplo mínimo verificable)

   Luego:

   > problema (también llamado un ejemplo mínimo verificable)**.**
3. Antes:

   > Encuentra **mas** información sobre cómo hacer una buena pregunta aquí

   Luego:

   > Encuentra **más** información sobre cómo hacer una buena pregunta aquí

#### Sugerencias o ayuda de formato

4. Estilo, encabezados.

   1.1. Cambiar la **e minúscula** por **E mayúscula**, porque viene luego de un doble punto. Antes:

   - > Saltos de línea: **e**spacio doble

   1.2. Luego:

   - > Saltos de línea: **E**spacio doble

   2.1. Secciones con cabeceras. Antes:

   - > Subencabezado **Mas** Pequeño

   2.2. Luego:

   - > Subencabezado **Más** Pequeño

5.1. Los elementos en bloque de HTML tienen restricciones. Antes:

- > elementos en bloque **mas** externos no deben estar indentados

5.2. Luego:

- > elementos en bloque **más** externos no deben estar indentados

Nota: Además me suena inexacto **barra lateral**, yo lo cambiaría por **panel derecho**.

---

En la descripción al insertar un *snippet*, se puede ver lo siguiente:

> fragmento JavaScript/HTML/CSS Ctrl+M

Al insertar un *snippet* se puede ver que primero viene *JavaScript*, luego *CSS* y por último *HTML*, por lo que se puede cambiar de la siguiente manera:

> Fragmento JavaScript/CSS/HTML Ctrl+M

[image: Captura sobre snippet.]

Comment: Disculpen, había olvidado que estaban en https://es.traducir.win y ahora ya hice tales sugerencias... Debería existir algún cuadro opcional para explicar por qué se hacen tales sugerencias de traducciones.

Comment: Tengo dudas con el punto 1.2 de "Estilo, encabezados" ¿Por qué mayúscula después de los dos puntos?

Comment: Respecto al snippet el orden creo que es algo subjetivo. Tu te refieres al orden de como aparece en el código cuando yo veo más lógico el orden de los cuadros: `html > css > javascript > resultado`. Aún así creo que este último punto carece de importancia, estás nombrando lo que puedes usar en el snippet el orden no lo considero importante.

Comment: @ElChiniNet Es algo que se hace generalmente, además que las oraciones deben empezar en mayúscula, salvo algunas excepciones como cuando son productos de _Apple_, como _iPad ya no se usa._, _iPhone lidera en el mercado._

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior Bueno, aún así dice __fragmento__ con la inicial **f en minúscula**, cuando debería comenzar **en mayúscula**.

Comment: He aprobado parte de tus sugerencias. Segun [fundeu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/uso-de-minusculas-y-mayusculas-despues-de-dos-puntos-1532/)  _Después de dos puntos se escribe minúscula, salvo en casos excepcionales._ Por otro lado, en el punto 2 no hay un punto en la cadena original, así que soy partidario de dejarlo como está.

Comment: En cuanto al orden de JavaScript/CSS/HTML, éste es el orden en el texto original así que tambien preferiría dejarlo así a no ser que haya un consenso amplio sobre ese cambio

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias por el enlace, nunca había visto algo así, supongo que ese cambio hacia las minúsculas lo propusieron ellos mismos, los del fundeu... ok, entiendo, entonces se sigue la traducción original.

Comment: Hola @ArtEze, aquí puedes consultar las reglas relativas a los dos puntos (no es algo que hayan creado los de Fundeu): http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?id=2a3yRXFBiD6rvDOMtq

Comment: @Pikoh, acerca del punto 2, debería llevar punto final en inglés y en español, aunque si no lo tiene el texto original debería cambiarse primero allí antes de hacer el cambio aquí.

Comment: @ElChiniNet Bien, ya quité esa sugerencia en traducir.win