# ¿Se pueden hacer preguntas para resolver dudas en general?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, revisión-de-pregunta

Sucede que cuando tomo un curso sobre un lenguaje te enseñan algo pero no te dicen cuándo o por qué usarla.

Por ello, a veces tengo preguntas como:

- *¿Cuándo usar una función?*
- *¿Cuál es la ventaja de usar paquetes?*

¿Se pueden hacer este tipo de preguntas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si la pregunta es concreta y no esta basada en opiniones, si.

ventajas o desventajas de usar paquetes usualmente son basada en opiniones.. algo que para alguien es una ventaja, para otro es una desventaja y viceversa.

Cuando usar algo, si esta bien dirigida, puede llegar a ser respondido... Tene en cuenta que a veces no hay cuando usar algo. Se usa cuando se necesita, pero no habria una respuesta concreta a cuando, o los escenarios son infinitos.

Si tenes alguna pregunta asi, podes hacerla y vemos que pasa.

Comment: ok muchas gracias lo intentare

Comment: Quizás esta lectura te de algunas ideas: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822