# ¿Cómo debo estructurar pregunta sobre optimización para evitar que se considere basada en opiniones?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Tengo un tiempo trabajando en un script de autocompletado y quiero optimizarlo, pero no he querido crear una pregunta aún, principalmente, porque temo que sería cerrada por estar basada en opiniones y mejor consulto primero aquí.

Ya tengo lo básico para reducir la cantidad de peticiones AJAX con:

1. Mínimo de caracteres: Las peticiones se realizan solo si el usuario tecleó al menos 3 caracteres, sin incluir espacios en los extremos (trim).
2. Retraso de petición dentro de `setTimeout`: Evita realizar peticiones consecutivas si el usuario teclea muy rápido.

Mejoras u optimizaciones que me gustaría lograr:

1. Ocultar y recuperar últimos resultados: Cuando el usuario hace clic fuera de los resultados, se cierra la lista y no he logrado mostrarlos nuevamente cuando el *input* recibe el foco (focus) otra vez, aunque creo que estoy por resolverlo.
2. Peticiones sin resultados: Evitar que si un valor arrojo resultado vacío se sigan enviando peticiones al continuar escribiendo, por ejemplo: si *param* no devolvió resultados, que no se hagan más consultas si se sigue escribiendo *parametro*.
3. Recibir otras sugerencias de optimización.

Probable título para la pregunta: ¿Cómo reducir peticiones AJAX en script de autocompletado?

Si hago el planteamiento como lo describo aquí y con código adjunto, ¿sería una pregunta válida o terminaría cerrada por estar basada en opiniones?

Comment: Considera el contenido de esta lista: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Comment: Tiene una métrica clara: número de peticiones. Tiene una pregunta objetiva: cómo reducir la métrica. Valida diria yo.

Comment: Agradecemos te preocupes por realizar de forma correcta tu pregunta, en este caso preguntas como realizarlo pero expones lo que has realizado previamente lo cual es muy importante en las preguntas.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Lo principal... no tengas miedo a que tu pregunta termine cerrada. No hay nada malo en ello. Nadie te va a señalar ni mirar mal por eso. Todos tenemos preguntas cerradas, borradas o totalmente confusas... o hemos preguntado cosas obvias que al ver la respuesta nos dio ganas de enterrarnos...

Para sugerencias, hay uno de los sitios en inglés que es justamente para eso. ( estoy en el celu si alguien pone el link se agradece)

Yendo a tus preguntas, tu error en la 1 es válida... la 2 parecería  un problema de lógica válido ... la 3... no... eso es totalmente basado en opiniones....

Salvo que... digas claramente que es lo que queres optimizar.. que probaste en optimizaciones y que querias mejorar respecto a eso...

Asi que pregunta sin miedo, y trabajemos en ello...

Comment: complemento la respuesta de @gbianchi, la respuesta debe ser con los datos mas elementales posibles