# ¿Podríamos ser más abiertos con las preguntas de tipo "como hacer x cosa"?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, convenciones-sociales

Esta es mi primera publicación en Meta.

Hoy hice una pregunta en StackOveflow en español ([Como modificar la primera fila cuyo valor sea x sin tener primary keys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/434980/como-modificar-la-primera-fila-cuyo-valor-sea-x-sin-tener-primary-keys)), mi pregunta era de tipo "como puedo hacer x". Y uno o dos usuarios me pidieron que pusiera lo que intenté.
Sin embargo, hay veces (como esta) en la que simplemente casi no hubo intentos. Estoy seguro de que si no hubiera agregado nada por que no intente nada, mi pregunta hubiese sido ignorada.
Pero yo busqué en google como hacerlo y no encontré nada.

¿Que hubiera pasado si no intenté nada pero investigué sin exito? ¿Mi pregunta hubiera sido bien recibida?

El punto es que estaría genial que esta comunidad entendiera que algunas preguntas no tienen un "ejemplo minimo y verificable" por que no existe código intentado en primer lugar.

StackOverflow deberia ser un lugar para aprender, no solo un servicio técnico para programadores.

En conclusión, quisiera que fueran más abiertos con las preguntas de tipo "como hacer x cosa" y entendieran que no son preguntas "amplias o basadas en opiniones" o "carentes de ejemplos minimos y verificables" y que por eso sean mal recibidas.

Comment: No eres el primero, ni vas a ser el último que se encuentra en esa situación. De hecho nos ha pasado a todos. Pero, **hay espacios adecuados** para hacer esas preguntas. Por ejemplo el [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) donde el dialogo es abierto. Pero, el sitio, tiene unas normas orientadas a garantizar la pertinencia de lo publicado.

Comment: @quevedo Es decir, si tengo dudas del tipo "como hacer x cosa", debo ir al chat? Si es asi, no está tan mal. Aunque también estaria bueno ofrecer esa misma alternativa en el recorrido. Puede que haga otra publicación proponiendo eso! c:

Comment: En la sala de chat siempre la pasamos genial, ahí es la taberna del código y demás cosas. Hay un ritual de iniciación por cierto :D

Comment: Al principio respondía preguntas como la mencionada. Por lo general resultaba que no era lo que quería el OP: había detallitos que no había específicado y que invalidaban la respuesta. En suma, trabajo perdido. En tu caso, podrias haber publicado la estructura de la tabla, un juego de datos para probar, como quieres el resultado y el código que tienes escrito hasta el momento (algo tendrás escrito). Mientras más aportes, más fácil será responderte.

Comment: @fredyfx Gracias por la información y el ritual :D

Comment: Si! Es lo típico. Allí muchos hemos recibido ayuda o la hemos ofrecido para casos aún en borrador en los que no se tiene suficientemente claro el problema.

Comment: @CandidMoe tiene sentido. Di la estructura de la tabla y el juego de datos, además de explicar el resultado. El código era lo único faltante antes de los primeros comentarios. Mi intento es solo uno de los muchos que escribí y borre.

Comment: @quevedo Ya veo!

Comment: Gracias a todos por calmar mis ansias y hablarme del chat como un lugar para mi tipo de preguntas. La verdad muy amable de su parte nwn

Comment: Me tomo muy a pecho a veces como me pueden juzgar en estas paginas...

Comment: No diste la estructura ni los datos: sólo mostraste una foto. Tendrías que haber publicado el SQL para generar y poblar la tabla en cuestión, algo que fuera cortar-y-pegar.

Comment: @CandidMoe tienes razon! Tendria que haber puesto el sql para crear la tabla. No se por que no se me ocurrió...

Comment: No pasa nada, todo es aprendizaje constante, viendo preguntas, comentarios se aprende bastante, cosas a tener en cuenta, lugares a dónde preguntar y demás :D

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo contigo, pero la regla general que se cumple un 99% de la veces es que si el usuario no da detalles o no pone un ejemplo de lo que se quiere pues la pregunta no se entiende y por tanto no puede responderse, las reglas se hacen para la mayoría, no para una minoría,  aunque por supuesto toda regla tiene su excepción

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ¿Podríamos ser más abiertos con las preguntas de tipo “como hacer x cosa”?

Quizás algunos te respondan (incluyéndome si supiera cómo), de manera general, no amigo, no podemos o no deberíamos por una sencilla razón: hay muchas maneras de realizar algo. Preguntas basadas en opiniones, no tienen una respuesta exacta. Los lineamientos del sitio son claros: Preguntas específicas, respuestas específicas. Perdí la cuenta de las preguntas que dicen "me da *NULL*".

> ¿Que hubiera pasado si no intenté nada pero investigué sin exito? ¿Mi pregunta hubiera sido bien recibida?

Tampoco, por el motivo que no detallas cómo buscaste, cómo intentaste investigar o algo que nos diera a entender que hubo algún esfuerzo de tu parte. Considera que existen usuarios que solo quieren que les resuelvan los trabajos de la academia, instituto, universidad, trabajo y ya. Hasta exámenes han publicado...

> El punto es que estaría genial que esta comunidad entendiera que algunas preguntas no tienen un "ejemplo minimo y verificable" por que no existe código intentado en primer lugar.

Si al leer la pregunta, tiene un escenario de base de datos, donde no se muestra la estructura de las tablas, ni los datos que tiene, ni las relaciones con otras tablas, ¿cómo se puede reproducir el escenario?

Te dejo una lista de recomendaciones a considerar como ingredientes de una buena pregunta: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

> StackOverflow deberia ser un lugar para aprender, no solo un servicio técnico para programadores.

Pues, depende cómo veas el concepto de aprender. Hay gente que ha publicado parte de sus proyectos personales hasta que los han lanzado a producción. Hace años llegó un estudiante, ahora es ingeniero, su tesis fue completada con el apoyo de la comunidad. Efecto que el muchacho siguió las reglas, la forma de preguntar se alineaba a las reglas del sitio. Nunca pidió cosas generales y por ello sus preguntas se mantuvieron a flote.

> En conclusión, quisiera que fueran más abiertos con las preguntas de tipo "como hacer x cosa" y entendieran que no son preguntas "amplias o basadas en opiniones" o "carentes de ejemplos minimos y verificables" y que por eso sean mal recibidas.

Complicado, como dije al inicio, habrá gente que quiera responder porque tiene ideas y les da igual romper las reglas (a veces hago excepciones), y gente que te mandará a leer recomendaciones de cómo preguntar (me la paso publicando lecturas recomendadas"y el enlace mencionado líneas arriba), te lo dicen en buen plan por cierto.

Comment: Ingeniero de Sistemas es ese muchacho ;)

Answer (score 1):

Mira lo que pasa es que no estás siguiendo las normas del sitio.

1. la norma del sitio es clara:

- https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

2. la comunidad tiene la ultima decisión de como recibirá/tratara tu pregunta.

Comment: 1- Las normas del sitio no dicen nada sobre preguntas del tipo "como puedo hacer x". Por ejemplo, según el ultimo link, el ejemplo minimo y verificable solo se pone si el problema es causado por el código de OP. Si no va a haber cambios sobre esa política, entonces estaría genial que al menos aclaren que este tipo de preguntas no están permitidas en el sitio.

Comment: 2- Yo con mi queja le hablo a la comunidad precisamente. No solo hablo de mi pregunta, si no la de cualquiera.

Comment: entiendes que las preguntas del tipo: preguntas del tipo "como puedo hacer x" sin codigo son mal recividas?

Comment: Por lo que me dicen ustedes, lo entiendo, aunque no lo digan las normas, si no la comunidad. Pero existiendo el chat, ya no me preocupa c:

Comment: El apartado 2 es uno de los más determinantes IMHO.

Comment: @Mauricio Contreras Donde es eso? y que es IMHO?

Comment: @DanteS. IMHO == **I**n **M**y **H**umble **O**pinion, que traduce a *en mi humilde opinión*. Me refiero a que el punto 2 de la respuesta de Franciso Nuñez es quizás el más determinante a la hora de evaluar si una pregunta cumple o no con las normas del sitio (en mi humilde opinión).

Comment: Eso tiene sentido!