# ¿Cuál es el propósito del foro? O dicho de otra manera: ¿Cómo puedo mejorar mis preguntas?

Tags: soporte

Estoy en los dos foros, el de inglés y el de español, y estoy con un proyecto que puede que me genere algunas preguntas.

Me gustaría hacerme una idea de cuál es el propósito del foro en español para hacerme una idea de cómo he de postear las preguntas.

Me imagino que por un lado el foro en inglés tendrá el page rank más elevado y este lo alcanzará en el futuro y por eso es importante ir contestando las preguntas, obteniendo reputación y privilegios para organizar correctamente las cosas.

¿O los dos tienen el mismo peso para el buscador de Google ya?

Entiendo que no se trata solo de eso y que también está el hecho de ayudar a los programadores novatos que buscan información en español.

Luego no tengo claro, en cuanto a cosas un poco más avanzadas que resolver problemas en ejercicios que no están encaminados a generar proyectos, ¿se pretende crear una librería de información paralela a la del foro en inglés?

Si es así no tengo inconveniente en publicar mis preguntas en español. Es más, lo prefiero, para mí es más fácil y encuentro a los españoles y latinoamericanos más cercanos y más dispuestos a ayudar que lo que he encontrado alguna vez que he preguntado en inglés.

Por ejemplo esta pregunta que he formulado hoy:

[Acceder a una base de datos externa guardada en assets usando SQLiteAssetHelper](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/573207/acceder-a-una-base-de-datos-externa-guardada-en-assets-usando-sqliteassethelper?noredirect=1#comment1013759_573207).

Obtuvo un voto negativo, ninguno positivo y ninguna respuesta. Solo me aclararon en comentarios que cometía un error de novato (solo soy un geólogo que se apañó para publicar su contenido de geología y está modificando su [primera app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.geologyapplications.minerals) para hacer las cosas un poco mejor). Aclarar que en mi publicación cargaba la base de datos desde assets con SQLiteOpenHelper, pero a la hora de actualizar la base de datos tuve problemas, busque información en inglés y si no me equivoco para mi caso que es una base de datos preelaborada que el usuario no modifica se hace con SQLiteAssetHelper y luego se puede actualizar con el método setForcedUpgrade y por eso la pregunta.

He contactado por facebook al creador del tutorial en español que seguí a sugerirle que añada un ejemplo de conexión a la base de datos.

Si me responde, ¿sirve de algo que edite la pregunta o añada una respuesta? ¿Alguien que pretenda crear un proyecto Android con una base de datos de solo lectura encontrará esto a través de Google? ¿O eso siempre se busca en inglés?

Si siempre se busca en inglés entiendo que casi mejor pregunto en el foro en inglés. Si es mejor que lo publique aquí para nosotros, ¿qué debo de tener en cuenta para que la encuentre el buscador ante una búsqueda hispana?

Hice varias modificaciones a la pregunta comiéndome un poco la cabeza con esto. Si la pregunta tiene alguna utilidad, ¿cuál sería un buen título? ¿Se tienen en cuenta otras cosas como las etiquetas para aparecer ante determinadas palabras claves? ¿El código lo rastrea la araña de Google? (por ejemplo si el usuario teclea SQLiteAssetHelper).

Comment: ... Tu como el usuario eres el responsable de hacer preguntas de calidad con un titulo que de una clara idea de lo que deseas, eso no lo podemos hacer por ti.

Comment: Revise la publicación que mencionas. Me parece que Benito-B sigue una costumbre establecida: si basta con un comentario para desatorar al OP, no es necesaria una respuesta. Deberías estudiar con atención los comentarios, que son el fruto de años de experiencia en el cruel mundo real.

Comment: Si, pero eso resolvía parte de la pregunta inicial pero no mi problema, que el tutorial no incluye un ejemplo de como conectar a una base de datos, he probado a hacer lo mismo que tenía con SQLiteOpenHelper y no carga la base de datos. Sé que tendría que hacer un curso de bases de datos.....Para más adelante, por el momento tengo un acuerdo con una doctora en mineralogía para publicar como coatuores una mejora de mi app con 1000 usuarios.

Comment: Y me parece que Benito-B respondió muy rápido que el tutorial era malo aludiendo a la primera parte con SQLiteOpenHelper. Yo solo seguí lo del final, con SQLiteAssetHelper que debe ser muy sencillo conectar.

Comment: Bienvenido. **Ningún sitio de StackExchange es un foro.** La mecánica es diferente a la de un foro. En un foro hay tópicos donde puedes abrir hilos dentro de los cuales se pueden generar tanto preguntas como respuestas.

Comment: La mecánica de los sitios de StackExchange consiste en abrir preguntas, cada una con su propia página dedicada. Cada pregunta puede recibir respuestas o soluciones a la pregunta original (no son meras publicaciones usadas con fines banales como podrían ser saludar, hacer otra pregunta u hablar de otro tema). Tanto preguntas como respuestas pueden ser comentadas con el objetivo de señalar algo al autor, pedir o dar información.

Comment: Puedes hablar cualquier cosa en el [chat].

Comment: @Mateo Vale. Cuando me responda el autor del tutorial pregunto a ver como dejo mi pregunta en el chat.

Comment: En pocas palabras: Pregunta específica + detalles de cómo reproducir el error + intentos + lo que se haya investigado para dar con la solución. Más detalles: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Saludos y éxitos con el desarrollo. PD: me alegra mucho que seas geólogo y que andes programando cosas para gente de geología. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Varias cosas que resaltar...

Como te dijeron, esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Alguien pregunta, alguien responde (inclusive la misma persona, está muy bien visto). No charlamos, no conversamos, no hay repreguntas, es una pregunta con un problema puntual y una respuesta.

Este sitio es la versión en español del sitio StackOverflow... con lo cual, puedes publicar en todos los que quieras, y obtener respuestas en todos, inclusive respuestas que no sean iguales.

Esta en vos, cual quieras seguir y en que sitios quieras participar. Este sitio tiene muchos años ya, y está bien indexado por google. Inclusive, si el sitio en ingles detecta que tu navegador está en español, te recomienda ir al sitio en español.

En cuanto a tu pregunta, tengamos en cuenta que acceder a una base de datos, sea solo de consulta, o para guardar datos, es lo mismo... Por lo tanto, si tu pregunta no fue hecha (como por ejemplo, [acá](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/480213/324)) debería quedarse y ser respondida.

Lo que hace google, respecto a las preguntas, es lo que hace en todos los sitios. Mejor redactada la pregunta, más fácil de encontrar.

Y para terminar, no se pretende crear una librería de información paralela. Se pretende crear una base de conocimiento para problemas, en español, como así también existe en portugués, ruso y japones.

Comment: ¿Se puede preguntar la misma pregunta en el sitio en inglés que has publicado en este?

Comment: Por supuesto!!!! y en esos casos, se agradece que si obtenes una respuesta en algun sitio, te tomes el trabajo de traducirla al otro. Tenemos multiples ejemplos de eso.. Inclusive preguntas que no necesariamente fueron a parar a SO en ingles, si no a otros sitios de la red, pero eran bienvenidas en el nuestro

Comment: No me hizo falta preguntar. Ya solucioné y pude comentar. [Añadí la respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/574329/297358)