# Propuesta sobre votos negativo en nuevos usuarios

Tags: discusión, votos, usuarios-nuevos

He visto a usuarios nuevos hacer una pregunta:

> "Estoy haciendo esto, pero me da error de este tipo"- Un resumen corto de una pregunta que comunmente le cae muchos votos negativos

Pero uno le pone un comentario como:

> "Oye. Ok tu error, pero necesitamos el código para ayudarte"- A veces funciona, otras no.

Cuando funciona y el usuario pone los datos que se le pide por comentarios, ya la pregunta con 2 votos negativos. Yo me imagino que esto desanima a nuevos usuarios.

> > Usuario: Ya edité la pregunta y puse los detalles que me dijeron, ahora esperar respuesta. - Recibe otro voto negativo- Por favor, qué rayos tiene de malo la pregunta.

Me imagino que la situación anterior desanima al usuario de usar Stack Overflow.
Yo propongo que no se pueda votar en contra de una pregunta en un nuevo usuario por un tiempo(12 o 24horas), esto para darle tiempo al usuario de que pueda arreglar la pregunta sin que reciban tantos votos negativos.

Otra propuesta es limitar los votos negativos que puede recibir la primera pregunta de los nuevos usuarios.

Comment: A veces, no pocas veces, las publicaciones de usuarios nuevos son directamente enunciados de ejercicios, o incluso capturas de pantallas o fotos de la pantalla de un examen. Estas publicaciones, si bien deben ser votadas a cierre (lo cual requiere 3 votos de la comunidad o 1 voto de un moderador diamantado), también recibirán votos en contra, para indicar que la pregunta no es relevante al sitio. Propones que este tipo de preguntas, no reciban negativos, bien. ¿Pueden recibir positivos?

Comment: Si la pregunta en cuestión es publicada un fin de semana, cuando la moderación es baja o escasa, estaría esta pregunta visible (sin votos de cierre) al menos durante 12 o 24 horas? No dejaría el sitio con preguntas de pésima calidad?. Luego, estas preguntas, podrían ir quedando en la lista de preguntas y no ser visibles en las primeras páginas. Lo que no se ve, no se modera. Por último, no todos los usarios tienen privilegio de voto de cierre, por lo cual el único recurso de moderación que les queda es precisamente el voto negativo y tal vez los comentarios y reportes.

Comment: Yo estoy de acuerdo con tu propuesta, pero me hago estas interrogantes, porque en algún momento estuve en la situación mencionada en el comentario anterior, en la cual mi único recurso de moderación era el voto negativo. Es por ello que prefiero que esto no sea impuesto por el sistema, sino que se deje a criterio propio, como hasta ahora. Lamentablemente siempre habrá el usuario que vota negativo sin dar tiempo a nada más. ¿Podemos hacer algo al respecto? No. Pero podríamos hacer seguimiento a preguntas mal formuladas en las que el AP demuestre interés real, mediante la edición o mejora.

Comment: El voto negativo no es ni debe ser usado como sustituto de cierre

Comment: @Yussef, concuerdo, pero eso se lo puedes decir a un usuario que tiene más de 3000 puntos de reputación. ¿Qué debe hacer un usuario con menos puntuación? ¿Cómo modera aparte de dejar comentarios o reportar la pregunta (si fuese el caso)? Le costó llegar a 125 puntos adquirir el privilegio de voto negativo, y le dices que no lo use hasta que tenga 3000 puntos y pueda usar el voto de cierre. ¿Cuándo debe o puede usar el voto negativo entonces?

Comment: @MauricioContreras ese usuario puede reportar la pregunta. Cuando puede votar negativo? Según esta propuesta seria igual que siempre, exceptuando a usuarios nuevos pero solo dentro de las primeras 12 hrs, luego de eso puede dar el -1. Y si bien esta propuesta me parece imposible de implementar creo que es bastante razonable

Comment: Ahora bien, mi opinion es que los votos en las preguntas no deberian existir, no aportan nada, nadie viene buscando preguntas, los votos deberían ser solo para las respuestas. Si la pregunta no aplica al sitio se cierra

Comment: Vuelvo a preguntar. Si les bloqueas el negativo, ¿no se debería bloquear el positivo también? Si buscamos equilibrio y "justicia" para los nuevos usuarios (aunque opino que este sitio es de programación y no una ONG), tanto los votos negativos como los positivos deberían estar bloqueados. ¿Porqué? Por el simple hecho que si sólo se puede votar positivo, habrá quienes lo hagan en la publicación, siendo entendido que la publicación es relevante o buena. Eso fomentaría que el nuevo usuario crea o piense que su pregunta está bien formulada. Lo cual es justo lo contrario a lo que se desea.

Comment: Las preguntas con muchos votos son más visibles en las búsquedas del sitio, en las búsquedas de Google y cualquier otro buscador. Las respuestas encontradas a dichas preguntas son el resultado de la búsqueda de preguntas. Tú no buscas: _"para solucionar el problema debes hacer esto o lo otro..."_, tu buscas: _"¿Cómo solucionar el error ..."_ Entonces, sí que son relevantes los votos en las preguntas. Precisamente porque la gente llega aquí (navegando) formulando una *pregunta* en Google, no una *respuesta*.

Comment: Por otro lado, tal como expone @fredyfx en su respuesta. ¿Cuánto tiempo voy a considerar que un usuario es "nuevo"? ¿Qué pasa con los usuarios que abren un cuenta vinculada a Google o a Facebook y luego no formulan realmente su primera pregunta hasta pasado mucho tiempo después de la vinculación? Si esta pregunta es "mala" o de baja calidad, y el usuario tiene 3 meses o más desde haber vinculado o creado su cuenta, ¿cómo determinamos que es nuevo? ¿Aplicamos esta regla a los usuarios que formulen su primera pregunta independientemente de si es "nuevo usuario" o no?

Comment: Es un debate muy interesante. Entiendo que la idea es atraer a potenciales usuarios a que se sientan bienvenidos en el sitio y es una idea lógica y por mi parte bienvenida, pero tiene sus aristas y hay que analizarlas todas. No sé si esto es algo aplicable sólo en [es.so] o es algo que afecte a toda la red. Eso lo pueden aclarar los diamantados y en última instancia los CM o la misma empresa. Desconozco el tema. Pero vuelvo a repetir, esto es una propuesta que quiere cambiar cierto comportamiento hacia usuarios nuevos y que implica a su vez un cambio en el sistema de voto del sitio.

Comment: Alguien hizo una encuesta sobre el impacto psicologico en las personas de los votos negativos? yo no escuche quejarse a ninguno de esos "usuarios nuevos" al respecto.  Les molesta a los nuevos, o a los viejos que ven los votos en los nuevos? Y si, el sistema usa los votos negativos para prohibir que determinado usuario puede hacer cosas, por ejemplo, preguntar.  Si un usuario nuevo, hace su decima pregunta, y siguen siendo un desastre, pero no tiene negativos porque es nuevo, entonces lo va a seguir haciendo.. ojo con esos escenarios...

Comment: @gbianchi el problema, es que se le da abuso a eso

Comment: @DanteS. quien? porque todos los usuarios que se ganaron el derecho lo pueden usar... defini abuso?

Comment: @gbianchi abuso es usar negativos cuando alcanza con un voto de cierre. (Por ejemplo, preguntas que hablan de un error sin codigo). Sin embargo, tal vez el problema real es que el sistema bloquea demasiado pronto.

Comment: eso no es abuso. Si la pregunta merece ser cerrada, tal vez tambien merezca un negativo. una pregunta que es un error, sin mostrar el codigo ni el error, es una pregunta que no es util para el sitio.

Comment: No hay quejas sobre los bloqueos. Vos tenes estadisticas de usuarios bloqueados quejandose?

Comment: Ya determiné el verdadero problema: que te bloqueen luego de dos preguntas de baja calidad... Si no fuera por eso, el voto negativo está perfecto

Comment: @gbianchi acá tenés un usuario que estubo bloqueado quejandose

Comment: @MauricioContreras No se busca ni equilibrio ni justicia, solo paciencia. El sito tiene una curva de aprendizaje bastante alta. Los votos en las preguntas no representa ninguna ayuda al que viene buscando respuestas, se vota negativamente porque la pregunta carece de esfuerzo ¿y que le importa eso a un tercer usuario que viene por respuestas? Nada. Las preguntas que no cumplan las reglas se cierran y luego se eliminan ¿no basta con eso para mantener la calidad del sitio?

Comment: @DanteS. dudo que eso sea cierto..

Comment: @gbianchi Abuso es que existan usuarios que hayan emitido 2.427 negativos versus 464 positivos

Comment: y cual seria su abuso, si tienen la reputacion para hacerlo?

Comment: @gbianchi Te digo otro: 8 votos positivos 3.869 negativos

Comment: No entiendo tu pregunta, evidentemente tiene la reputación para hacerlo, de lo contrario no estaríamos hablando de ello. Una cosa es contar con el privilegio y otra distinta es abusar de él

Comment: @gbianchi cual sería el abuso de un presidente robando al pais, si lo votaron? Ese tipo de argumento estás usando

Comment: @gbianchi "dudo que eso sea cierto.." cree lo que quieras, yo lo viví. Quizá son 3 preguntas, dando beneficio de la duda. Igual, eso me pasó en el sitio en inglés

Comment: otra discucion sin sentido... 40 comentario para llegar a la mismo conclucion de siempre ... @Yussef podes entender que el sistema de votos _es lo que hay_ y no hay interes en cambiarlo _funciona bien para lo que fue hecho_ ... y es incluso mas facil crear otro sitio fuera de la red y comenzar desde 0 ... que bregar en buscar un cambio ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Aloha~ buenas :D me parece una situación interesante, vamos por partes:

**Preguntas**

En el sitio hay preguntas de todo tipo, desde ejercicios con enunciados y sin intentos de código, hasta preguntas muy bien elaboradas que merecen toda la atención necesaria para dar solución al caso (a modo de recompensa por tomarse el tiempo de formular una pregunta con todas las de la ley: código mínimo necesario + investigación realizada * cantidad de intentos que incluyen los errores).

**Usuarios**

Hay usuarios nuevos y relativamente nuevos que están sin `la medalla de informado`; para mi, es un indicador clave, puesto que si ya leyeron el recorrido (al menos eso quiero seguir creyendo), en teoría deberían saber que se solicita ciertos datos en la pregunta para que ésta tenga la calidad mínima necesaria. En estos 8 años que llevo en el sitio, puedo afirmar que curiosamente los nuevos que tienen dicha medalla, tienden a elaborar preguntas mejor estructuradas que los nuevos sin dicha medalla.

Un usuario nuevo, tal cual indica su nombre, tiene una cuenta recién creada, recién está aprendiendo el uso del sitio y pues, preguntar abiertamente en un foro y en sitios como SO, SOes, es todo un reto para algunos, para otros, les da igual, al final es una chance de obtener respuesta (o al menos interacción entre comentarios que podrían generar una nueva perspectiva y un efecto dominó), es un amplio rango de posibilidades. Todos hemos sido nuevos en algún lado, en algún momento y las experiencias han sido variadas.

**Opinión**

De manera personal, aparte de darles la bienvenida, los mando a realizar el recorrido, ver cómo preguntar y les sugiero las recomendaciones del link: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 (hasta el momento con 70+ votos a favor). Hay quienes agradecen, hay quienes les incomoda.

**Panorama**

Hago todo este preámbulo para dejar en claro que el escenario es amplio y por lo tanto, se tiene que evaluar todas las variables visibles y pensar en aquellas variables no-visibles que puedan impactar de alguna manera a las primeras experiencias de los nuevos.

**Vamos con los números:**

Al momento de la redacción de la presente publicación, en la sección de usuarios, existen 36 por página, hay 8490 páginas con 36 usuarios y la página 8491, 16 usuarios, haciendo la matemática del caso: (36*8490) + 16 = (305 640) + 16 = 305 656 usuarios.

De toda esta masa de usuarios, los que casi siempre estamos en META y en la sala de chat, somos casi los mismos, algunos tienen temporadas y algunos ya no regresaron. Solían decir "turno mañana" (España) y "turno tarde" (todo Latam), sumando ambos "turnos", creo que no llegamos ni a los 100 usuarios.

Siguiendo con las matemáticas y considerando hipotéticamente que somos 100 usuarios que estamos presentes, del total de 305 656, se traduce como un 0.0327% aproximadamente. La comunidad son los 305 656 usuarios, no solo 4 usuarios que andan en la sala de chat.

**Uno de los escenarios**

1. Usuario nuevo hace una pregunta mala y/o pésima.
2. La pregunta recibe un voto negativo, sin comentarios.
3. Aparece otro voto negativo, sin comentarios.
4. Llega un usuario y le deja un comentario diciendo que mejore la pregunta y le da los pasos a seguir.
5. El OP mejora la pregunta agrega el código mínimo verificable y demás detalles.

De este escenario, es indeterminado que los mismos usuarios que le dieron negativo a esa pregunta, regresen y retiren el voto negativo.

Si la pregunta ha sido votada para el cierre, se requieren 3 votos de usuarios comunes y silvestres, o 1 voto de un moderador para que la pregunta sea cerrada.

Existen los votos de reapertura.

**Lo que dices**

> Me imagino que la situación anterior desanima al usuario de usar Stack Overflow.

Es correcto, existen personas que se desaniman con votos en contra, algunos lloran, otros se incomodan. Aunque duela, es lo que hay, dudo mucho que la empresa vaya a cambiar toda la santa red de SE ese motor que tiene para medir qué aportes suman y qué aportes restan.

> Yo propongo que no se pueda votar en contra de una pregunta en un nuevo usuario por un tiempo(12 o 24horas), esto para darle tiempo al usuario de que pueda arreglar la pregunta sin que reciban tantos votos negativos.

Las preguntas que tengo aquí son:

1. ¿Por cuánto tiempo determinas que un usuario es nuevo?
2. ¿Esta propuesta involucra que se programe algo en el sitio?
3. ¿Te refieres a apelar al buen corazón de todos los demás usuarios?

Todavía mantengo la esperanza que habrá más gente con empatía y se tomará el tiempo de comentar para explicarle al usuario que edite su pregunta agregando los detalles mínimos necesarios.

> Otra propuesta es limitar los votos negativos que puede recibir la primera pregunta de los nuevos usuarios.

Aquí me parece que buscas que se programe algo a nivel de SOes, ¿verdad?

**Lo que sí podemos hacer**

Dejar comentarios para formar adecuadamente a los nuevos usuarios, invitándoles a leer el recorrido (https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) (y de paso obtengan su primera medalla), el cómo preguntar (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), evitar votar negativamente a las preguntas mal hechas de esos usuarios nuevos porque tienen "perdón de novato", sería algo como `Mercy`.

De manera personal, a veces, cuando veo alguna pregunta que le han dado negativos y es un usuario nuevo que no tiene ni la medalla de informado, aparte de mandarlo a leer los enlaces, le doy un +1 para que la pregunta se mantenga en 0. A veces dejo comentario pidiendo un poco de paciencia con los nuevos, en especial los que andan `desinformados`.

Comment: "es indeterminado que los mismos usuarios que le dieron negativo a esa pregunta, regresen y retiren el voto negativo." Sería bueno que haya un sistema que opcionalmente avise que la pregunta fue editada a estos usuarios.

Comment: no llegamos ni a 20 usuarios en META ... y en el chat si acaso rondamos el promedio de 8~9 usuarios...

Comment: @DanteS. según entiendo, hay un aviso: el de monitorear la pregunta. Pero es a voluntad.

Comment: dejare esto por aqui muy discretamente ... jajajajaja https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nca8F.jpg

Comment: Masbien, @FranciscoNuñezIALover disculpa si te ofendí con el comentario, no era mi intención.

Comment: ya esta roto el plato ... ahora tu eres el que tira null ...

Comment: Normal bro, ya te ofrecí las disculpas porque vi que realmente te incomodó en el chat, por otro lado, no podemos entendernos, se intentó y no pude, y si la situación va a seguir así, mejor evitemos interactuar entre nosotros con temas de moderación y ya~ cada quien sigue su camino en paz. Gracias por el entrenamiento, he aprendido nuevas ideas, buenas vibras y adiós.

Answer (score 3):

Hablando de manera general, la participación en *Stack Overflow en español* es bastante pobre, apenas se hacen preguntas en un día, por tanto debemos pensar maneras de atraer usuarios sin perder calidad en el sitio, cualquier medida que contribuya a aumentar la participación en el sitio debe ser analizada, no se puede ser como el avestruz y hacerse el que no pasa nada, que un usuario tenga reputación para emitir votos negativos no quiere decir que lo haga de la manera correcta, aquí hay personas que se les va la mano con los votos negativos, estoy casi seguro que muchos de esos usuarios que emiten votos negativos a preguntas y respuestas no retiran el voto después de que la publicacion fue editada, al usuario nuevo no hay que bombardearlo con votos negativos, se le puede reportar la publicación, emitir un voto de cierre o ante la duda simplemente no tomar partido. Es inconcebible que hayan usuarios que emitan más votos negativos que positivos, es como si estuvieran al acecho esperando el más mínimo error, porque también es verdad que aquí hay personas que emiten votos negativos hasta porque te faltó un espacio. Yo estoy de acuerdo en que se le de un margen de tiempo al usuario nuevo antes de que se le den votos negativos, y la métrica a usar sería 30 días como miembro de la comunidad, si lleva 3 años en el sitio y nunca ha entrado no es nuevo. Yo soy de la opinión de que el voto negativo si ahuyenta, de hecho no son pocos los que se quejan, pero estoy seguro de que todo va a seguir igual, solo espero que no cierren la comunidad por falta de actividad.

Comment: Hace varios años modificaron los requisitos para mantener un sitio de [se] abierto. Básicamente, para que un sitio continue abierto debe contar con moderadores activos. Puedes ver en la https://stackexchange.com/sites que hay muchos sitios con muy poca actividad que siguen abiertos. El caso más reciente de cierre de un sitio que tengo presente es el de Windows Phone, y este fue porque el sistema operativo dejó de estar disponible. Este sitio incluso fue "archivado". Más detalles en [The Windows Phone SE site has been archived](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/383855/289691)

Comment: @Rubén esperemos no modifiquen los requisitos teniendo en cuenta otros aspectos como la participación, porque de ser así...

Comment: En cualquier momento pueden cambiar los requisitos. Con "suerte" avisaran con anticipación. Lo mejor que podemos hacer como usuarios es prepararnos para "cualquier eventualidad".

Comment: @Rubén a mi más que nada lo que me preocupa es la poca participación, es como si hubiera sequía