# ¿Podríamos incluir un link a esta pregunta de meta en "¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?"?

Tags: discusión, característica-nueva, estado-completado

Estaba viendo preguntas en StackOverflow y me encontré con que alguien puso en comentario un link a esta pregunta en meta: [¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%C3%A9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo)

Considero que la pregunta tiene muy buenas y útiles respuestas y serviría de mucho a aquellos que buscan profundizar en como elaborar buenas preguntas y entender mejor que motivos hay detrás del que votó negativo la pregunta formulada por ellos.

Mi propuesta es agregar un link en "como elaboro una buena pregunta?" que diriga directamente a la pregunta en meta "por qué he recibido un voto negativo?". Que les parece mi idea???

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, hace tiempo ya lo habia sugerido @Muriano tambien

Comment: Personalmente no me parece una mala idea. El problema que tenemos es que para modificar esa parte debemos contactar con los CM, los moderadores no podemos. Creo que lo mejor es dejar esta sugerencia abierta durante un tiempo a ver que recibimiento tiene, y si la respuesta es favorable trataremos de escalarla para ver si es posible.

Comment: No había visto la de "¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?". Creo que a las respuestas que se dan ahí les voy a empezar a dar uso. Buena onda

Comment: @Pikoh entonces se podria agregar?

Comment: @Pikoh pedimos esto tambien?

Comment: Es una muy buena idea así muchos tendrán razones e información y podrán corregirse ellos mismos.

Comment: He añadido ese enlace y ya esta vivo en el centro de ayuda.

Comment: Genial! Yo creo que ayudará a mucha gente c: