# Una pregunta con una reacción extraña de la comunidad

Tags: discusión

Hace tiempo, se hizo una pregunta, la cual mantendré anonima por unos dias para ver como reacciona la comunidad (edit: El link de la pregunta está al final)

La pregunta pedía de manera directa que se realizara un script, diciendo "Quiero un script [...]". Motivo para cerrarla, y así fue. Eso fue un buen ejemplo de moderación perfecto. De hecho, el unico voto negativo es mio, y está perfecto. Incluso, debería retirar ese voto, pero no me quedó de otra que agregarlo.

Pero alguien le hizo el script a este usuario (también mantendré anonimo al que respondió). Lejos de comunicarle al usuario que no dé una respuesta a alguien que no demuestra el esfuerzo de responder su propia duda y pasarle el link a [Te he votado negativamente porque pides directamente que hagan tu trabajo/tarea escolar](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4320), se le dió hasta 3 votos positivos a la respuesta.

Ante esta emergencia en la moderación, decidí votar negativamente al usuario para compensar la situación y le dejé un comentario diciendo lo que hice.

Luego, recibí un comentario de otro usuario, que decía:

> me parece muy mal que castigues a quién ha escrito una buena respuesta
> y no te tomes la molestia de darle -1 a quién escribió tan mala
> pregunta. En mi opinión, debes aprender a separar las cosas. De hecho,
> hay medallas para quienes escriben excelentes respuestas a terribles
> preguntas (chaleco salvavidas, bote salvavidas). Si no te gusta,
> simplemente no votes la respuesta, pero no castigues a la persona
> incorrecta.

- Yo nunca usé el verbo castigar, ni lo hice con esa intención.
- Este comentario fue el que me motivó a poner -1 en la pregunta, pero en realidad, la pregunta tenía una forma diferente de ser tratada.
- Una buena respuesta no va a cambiar el hecho de que se promovió la holgazanería
- Las medallas probablemente están allí para una pregunta que resultó ser buena. No creo que el sitio promueva preguntas de baja calidad. Pero si es cierto, también algo no anda bien con la moderación.

Otra cosa que dijo este usuario fue

> El hecho de que otras personas castiguen otras respuestas no debiera ser razón suficiente para castigar una respuesta

Si la normativa de la comunidad es castigar respuestas que siguen ciertos criterios, entonces si es motivo suficiente.
Notese que el usuario recibió dos votos en este comentario (espero sea por el resto del contenido y no por este fragmento).

No hubo más respuesta relevante al caso del usuario desde este punto, debido a la politica de no extender demasiado los comentarios, y le doy la razón.

**Favor al autor de los comentarios y el que respondió, si es que reconoce el suceso, de no informar por el momento la pregunta ni el usuario que escribió la respuesta**

Casos similares a este han resultado en las respuestas votadas negativamente y comentarios del tipo "no fomentes la holgazanería y preguntas de baja calidad"

---

Este es el primer caso con el que me encuentro en persona. Sin embargo, he oido anegdotas de otros usuarios que hablaron de como la comunidad da "permitidos" y como el centro de ayuda da información desactualizada y/o no cierta sobre el sitio.

Hasta ahora, pensé que las publicaciones en meta eran 100% ciertas, pero si bien son bastante precisas, nadie ha hablado de estos permitidos.

Tal vez esta pregunta sea "una queja disfrazada", pero creo que, incluso si recibe negativos, sea relevante para varios usuarios.

Que habría que hacer con este caso? Esto es muy frecuente en el sitio? O son contandos los casos?

---

Respondo algunas inquietudes.

- Admito haber dado mal uso al voto negativo, sin embargo, no soy el unico que ha dado mal uso al voto negato. Escenarios similares han resultado en votos negativos sin importar que tan bien escrita estubiese la respuesta.
- En mi opinión, cuando la pregunta trata sobre problemas particulares, no importa que tan buena sea la respuesta, solo ayudará a una persona y no a lectores futuros. Considero que estaría bueno que el sitio no ayudara a personas que evidentemente no han puesto esfuerzo y hacen caso omiso a comentarios.
  **Sin embargo, es solo una opinión y no es el punto de esta publicación**. Lo que considero, es que estaría bueno estandarizar y escribir las normas de la comunidad. Tener normas claras ayudará a reducir preguntas de baja calidad desde mi punto de vista. No me importa si de repente dicen "respondemos todas las preguntas sin importar si demuestran esfuerzo", pero estaría bueno un estandar.
- No me convence mucho tomar fragmentos del centro de ayuda como referencia debido a que, al menos yo, percibo algunas diferencias con las normas reales y mencionadas en meta.

---

Edit: Habiendo pasado el tiempo, agregaré la pregunta en cuestión y la explicación de por que no mostré la pregunta antes:

[Eliminar archivos txt de una carpeta y dejar solo los 5 mas recientes](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/592558/eliminar-archivos-txt-de-una-carpeta-y-dejar-solo-los-5-mas-recientes)

La respuesta, fue hecha por un usuario de mucha reputación y que ha tenido una participación frecuente en la etiqueta. Por lo que quería evitar, al menos por un tiempo, ante la duda, la posibilidad de que apareciera algún favoritismo.

Comment: Recuerdo vagamente esa respuesta y ese comentario. No recuerdo el término para describir cuando algo se hace de por sí cuando el criterio por parte de la comunidad es hacerlo de esa manera (sin ser obligatorio), pero digamos que "ni está bien, ni está mal" lo que hiciste. No está bien porque se está penalizando la respuesta aun siendo buena, pero tampoco está mal porque estás penalizando que se responda a una pregunta pobre.

Comment: "*...se le dió hasta 3 votos positivos a la respuesta.*" definitivamente no fui yo el que contestó jeje xD. Bromas aparte, me parece apropiado el manejo. Una pregunta que pide directamente resolver una tarea, sea académica o no, debería ser cerrada. No se si sea el caso, pero es verdad que hay algunos usuarios *nuevos* que no se ciñen estrictamente a las reglas, por ejemplo, tenemos a los *revive preguntas*, a los *quién contesta primero*, y por qué no, a los *cosecha puntos*; así que es posible tener un confrontamiento de procedimientos con alguno.

Comment: Una pregunta: Tu ves alguna diferencia en la pregunta en cuestión versus la mas votada en los últimos 30 días: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/594795/ordenar-una-lista-alfab%c3%a9ticamente-en-espa%c3%b1ol-incluido-la-%c3%91-y-tildes

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down "¿Cuándo debo votar negativo?
Utiliza tu voto negativo cada vez que encuentres una pregunta o respuesta atrozmente descuidada, poco rigurosa, sin ningún esfuerzo empleado, o que es clara, pero quizás peligrosamente incorrecta.". Si la respuesta era buena, no estás usando el botón de voto negativo adecuadamente de acuerdo con las normas del sitio.

Comment: @Yussef no entiendo la pregunta.

Comment: @ordago Tenés razón, pero no soy el unico que le dió mal uso

Comment: @Yussef Ya entiendo. La pregunta que me presentas, a diferencia de la anterior, demuestra esfuerzo, mientras tanto, la que mencioné, incluye textualmente lo mencionado en la publicación

Comment: @aeportugal Este usuario no es nuevo, pero tenés razón. Esperaré un dia o dos y publicaré la pregunta.

Comment: @DanteS. El esfuerzo, es el **esfuerzo por resolver su propio problema**, NO es el esfuerzo que lleva acumulado antes del problema. Por eso, colocar un código no es sinónimo de esfuerzo. El caso que te planteo, es el mejor votado en los últimos 30 días, pero si tu analizas el código hay cero esfuerzo en resolver el tema particular, eso por eso que la discusión que está en mi respuesta, yo planteo que hay diferencia de criterios.

Comment: Perdón, le había hechado un vistaso demasiado rapido. Pero ahora que me lo planteas, tenés razón.

Comment: upsss no es nuevo

Comment: No entendí el comentario

Comment: Yussef, maestro, "hay cero esfuerzo en resolver..", estás seguro?, has estado sentado al lado del OP, verificando que hizo?, una de las pocas preguntas que hice, tenía atrás un mes de intentos de todo tipo, y no lo plasmé en la pregunta, ya que no tenía sentido (tampoco recuerdo todo lo que hago), hay que ser más "amplios" al juzgar una pregunta.

Comment: @MarcePuente Maestro!!! no puso la `@` antes de mi nombre y recién ahora veo su comentario. Obviamente no tengo como saber si existe un esfuerzo o no, idealmente ese esfuerzo debería verse reflejado en la pregunta, así se evitan estos problemas.

Comment: A modo personal, el asunto del esfuerzo siempre me ha parecido que sobra, no hay como medirlo; yo soy de la idea de que si todos pusieran suficiente esfuerzo no existirían preguntas en el sitio, ya que todos se auto resolverían sus preguntas. Es decir, bajo mi punto de vista absolutamente todas las preguntas del sitio (menos las auto respondidas) carecen de esfuerzo

Answer (score -5):

Te respondo los 2 puntos que encuentro estas equivocado

> Una buena respuesta no va a cambiar el hecho de que se promovió la
> holgazanería

La motivación del sitio es generar una base de conocimientos en formato preguntas/respuestas, no es desmotivar la holgazanería. Las preguntas son el medio para generar las respuestas, por lo que lo más importante son las respuestas.

Suponiendo que existe el problema de incentivar la holgazanería, debes preguntarte que es mas importante ¿No incentivarla? o poner en entredicho una respuesta correcta??? Porque finalmente eso representa el voto, es que hay alguien que está diciendo que es una mala respuesta. Lo ultimo, pienso que va contra todo propósito de mejorar la calidad del sitio y la confianza de los usuarios, porque finalmente los usuario no tienen porque comprender que tu voto es un castigo ajeno al merito propio de la respuesta.

Luego dices:

> Si la normativa de la comunidad es castigar respuestas que siguen
> ciertos criterios, entonces si es motivo suficiente.

No existe normativa que señale eso, existen opiniones (sobre todo aquí en meta) que han opinado de manera similar a la tuya, eso no las hace norma.

La [ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) señala que:

> Emitir un voto positivo a una pregunta o respuesta señala para resto
> de la comunidad que una publicación es interesante, el autor ha
> investigado, y es útil; emitir un voto negativo señala lo contrario:
> que la publicación contiene información errónea, no hay
> investigación previa, o no consigue comunicar información

---

Finalmente cada uno responde bajo su criterio, no con el criterio ajeno.

Comment: Las buenas preguntas son las que se tienen que responder, sino llenamos el sitio de preguntas basura que no sirven de nada, con lo cual, baja la calidad del contenido del sitio, y eso SI es contraproducente. Por otra parte, en el 2o punto que comentas, deberias leerte bien [Como escribo una buena respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) alli deja CLARISIMO "Contesta preguntas bien formadas".

Comment: @Marc "Buenas preguntas" eso es subjetivo y es el problema, hay una pregunta que a ti te parece mala y a mi buena...no debería responderla??  o sea debe pesar tu criterio por sobre el mío??.-- "Contesta preguntas bien formadas" Aquí nadie ha hablado de responder preguntas mal formadas, estamos hablando de que si demuestran esfuerzo en resolver su problema, lo que muchos llaman "El intento"

Comment: Ni mi criterio ni el tuyo, aqui [ask] te explican como elaborar una buena pregunta. Que a estas alturas sigas teniendo dudas de como hacerlo y sigas cuestionando las "normas" del sitio..

Comment: @Marc Evidentemente puedo estar equivocado, para aprender a que preguntas puedo responder fui a tu historial y tomé simplemente la ultima que tu has respondido, todo con el fin de aprender. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/590429/por-qu%C3%A9-encuentro-el-error-constructor-indefinido-en-clase-main/ y bueno.....ahí mejor no seguí buscando

Comment: Una cosa es hacer lo que te de la gana (mi caso), la otra es dar clases de moralidad o querer cambiar las normas del sitio en META (tu caso), no me vengas ahora con rodeos, en META se hablan las cosas como deben ser, no creo que encuentres a nadie en toda la red con un perfil impoluto, y no, no voy a caer tan bajo de ponerme a revisar tu perfil a revisar las preguntas que respondes, no me hace falta hacer eso para poder discutir una cuestion, cosa que no puedo decir de ti

Comment: Vamos que no seas tan cara dura que eras tu el que va dando clases de moralidad y luego resulta que respondes lo que se te da la gana. Aquí término la discusión contigo, no te responderé más porque ni vale la pena

Comment: Yo ya he dicho en varias ocasiones que hace tiempo estoy desconectado de la red pero si sé las normas que hay, eso no quiere decir que no pueda discutir sobre las normas del sitio con alguien que las quiere cambiar a su antojo, y demuestra repetidamente que no tiene la capacidad de entender algo tan simple como es el funcionamiento del sitio. Quizas deberias centrarte en aprender a comprender textos antes de meterte a discutir estos temas que ya hace mucho tiempo funcionan bien, y llegas tu a alterarlo todo, quizas el problema sea tuyo, pero bueno, es mi opinion, quizas..

Comment: @Yussef eso se llama falacia lógica. Te saliste del argumento para hablar de que otro usuario no tiene "autoridad moral" para sostener un argumento. Mal. Y no, cada uno no responde bajo su criterio. Responde siguiendo las normas del sitio.

Comment: @Alfabravo Por supuesto que se debe tener piso moral para opinar. Cuando digo responder bajo su criterio, lo digo dentro del marco de las normas y del espacio que deja a interpretación es a eso que me refiero. Hay casos en que se reabre una pregunta sin haber sido editada, es decir 3 usuarios la votaron para cerrar y otros 3 para reabrirlo, esto demuestra que existen criterios dispares. Entonces yo respondo bajo mi criterio (e insisto dentro del marco de las normas como las entiendo), porque simplemente no puedo preguntar a cada uno de uds si les parece o no que esa pregunta puede..

Comment: ser respondida. Ahora, si bajo el criterio de la mayoría esa pregunta es cerrada. Que culpa tiene el que responde, ni que fuera adivino para presagiar que sería cerrada. Cosa muy distinta a responder porque se te da la gana, eso es ir en contra de lar normas y el espíritu de ellas.

Comment: "La motivación del sitio es generar una base de conocimientos en formato preguntas/respuestas" No del todo, he visto preguntas "particulares" que solo ayudan al autor de la pregunta, como la que comenté. De hecho, este problema ya se ha hablado aquí. "No existe normativa que señale eso" exacto, no existe, pero aun así es aplicado. Sin embargo, admito haber usado mal el voto negativo. Lastima que los demás no lo admitan. De todas formas, no tomes el centro de ayuda de referencia, no refleja la normativa actual del sitio.

Comment: @Yussef Sigue siendo una falacia lógica. Que el argumento sea válido o no, nada tiene que ver con la autoridad moral de un sujeto. Si un ladrón confiesa, no deja de ser válida la confesión. Enfócate en el argumento de Marc, no en él ni en tu percepción de él. Mal. Y lo otro, no hay que ser adivino para no responder malas preguntas.

Comment: @Alfabravo No quiero entrar a discutir si es falacia lógica o no. Yo en mi vida las recomendaciones, criticas y sugerencias las tomo tanto por su merito como por quien la proporciona. Y sobre el fondo del asunto, es que hay un enredo. Yo estoy hablando sobre los votos y me salen con el link a como escribir una buena respuesta y empezamos a hablar de las respuesta, cuando el tema que estamos debatiendo son los votos

Comment: Es lo bonito de la forma en que funcionan los votos. A ti te parece "buena" la pregunta (como tal vez a otros) y a otros les parece "mala". Si todos votaran, cosa que jamás ocurrirá, se tendría un consenso único, pero como en todas las acciones de sufragio, no hace falta que todos voten, y se plasma la voluntad (o el criterio en este caso) de los usuarios que participaron. Si la pregunta termina con más votos en contra que a favor, significa que la comunidad ha expresado su criterio. Lo mismo sucede para las respuestas.

Comment: Ahora, votar en contra una respuesta porque la pregunta es mala, puede verse como "voto castigo", pero más allá de si es lógico o no, o si es debido o no, el problema con las respuestas buenas a preguntas malas (IMHO) es que, tal vez, la pregunta termine cerrada, y por lo tanto el aporte de la respuesta se pierde. Aunque siempre se puede votar a reapertura, no todos mirarán o considerarán la respuesta (o respuestas) como motivo suficiente para reabrir la pregunta. Entonces, ¿tiene sentido realmente responder malas preguntas con respuestas magistrales?

Comment: Perosnalmente no lo veo, y es algo que entendí con el pasar del tiempo, luego de ver como algunas de mis primeras respuestas simplemente se perdieron, a pesar del esfuerzo o dedicación que le puse. ¿Medallas? Si existe una medalla salvavidas, pero habla de revertir la percepción sobre la pregunta, no habla sólo de la respuesta, y usualmente, esto se consigue logrando que el OP edite su pregunta mejorando la misma. Eso, en mi opinión, es precisamente lo más difícil, ya que la gran mayoría de usuarios que reciben una respuesta a una mala pregunta, usan la respuesta y nunca más entran al sitio.

Comment: @MauricioContreras Yo respondo por ayudar, otras veces porque la pregunta me parece interesante, otras porque estoy aburrido y porque no decirlo hay veces que es por los puntos. Es que motivaciones hay tantas como los colores

Comment: Y si creo que hay un tema de lógica que importa.- Hay reglas para responder y hay reglas para votar. No tiene lógica incumplir la regla de votación para castigar a otro que incumple la regla de responder. Tampoco tiene lógica argumentar que este acto es por la calidad del sitio, cuando votar una buena respuesta empobrece el sitio. Yo entiendo que en el caso de @DanteS. es por desconocimiento, pero hay otros que tienen una doble moral

Comment: @Yussef válido que no quieras, pero usar una falacia lógica cierra el diálogo porque ya no importan los argumentos sino lo que tú quieres. Te quedas solo en tu torre de marfil moral, suerte con eso.

Comment: @Alfabravo Creo que no entiendes. Yo estoy en mi derecho de responder o no a los comentarios que me hacen, puedo pasar de ellos siempre que quiera, tengo el derecho a elegir con quien discuto. Yo solo di aviso que no seguiré mas la discusión con aquella persona y no le responderé más. Él está en todo su derecho a seguir comentándome tal como lo hizo. Ayer mismo tu me cerraste una discusión por tus motivos y yo lo respeté sin problemas